# Shortest code that raises a SIGSEGV

Tags: code-golf, error-message

Write the shortest code that raises a  [Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) in any programming language.

Comment: Wow. Possibly the shortest successful question.

Comment: @MatthewRoh Out of interest, I made [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/edit/1335239) SEDE query. It looks like there are a few with +10 or higher, but this is the first above +40

Answer (score 150, accepted):

## C, 5 characters

```
main;
```

It's a variable declaration - `int` type is implied (feature copied from B language) and `0` is default value. When executed this tries to execute a number (numbers aren't executable), and causes `SIGSEGV`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTPP@v9/AA)

Comment: Default value may not be 0, and this may give a BUS error rather than a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Macmade: Actually, it is `0`. `static` variables start as `0`, and `main;` is `static`, as I declared it outside function. http://c-faq.com/decl/initval.html

Comment: last time i played with this thing, i figured out that there's a different reason for the segfault. First of all by calling main you jump to the location of main, not the value, another thing is `main` is an int, it's located in `.bss`, usually functions are located in `.text`, when the kernel loads the elf program it creates an executable page for `.text` and non-executable for `.bss`, so by calling main, you jump to a non-executable page, and execution something on a such page is a protection fault.

Comment: Yep, segfaults in C are pretty much the default :P

Comment: `main __attribute__((section(".text#")))=0xc3;` FTFY (at least it seems to return without crashing on my x86).

Comment: @jozxyqk Or shorter, `const main=195;`. As interesting it is that it's working, the goal of this code golfing challenge was to make the code segfault, not work :).

Comment: `cont main=195;` doesn't work anymore, it gets in the `.rodata` section which is readable but not executable.

Answer (score 94):

### Bash, 11

```
kill -11 $$
```

Comment: Signal 11 in 11 characters. Seems legit.

Comment: @nyuszika7h I was going to upvote your comment, but you have 11 upvotes right now, so I'm going to leave it at that. :P

Comment: @AlexL. other people seem to have spoiled that :(

Comment: @theonlygusti Yeah... That's too bad. :( Oh well, then I can upvote it now.

Comment: Up to 42 upvotes, no touchee!

Comment: @JoeyAdams My shell script terminal just loaded for a long time, no segfault.

Comment: @theonlygusti it's okay, at least you can have 11! Until someone ruins that too.

Answer (score 52):

## Assembly (Linux, x86-64), 1 byte

```
RET
```

This code segfaults.

Comment: As an MSDOS .com file, it runs and terminates without error.

Comment: see this code [http://ideone.com/RMuLf](http://ideone.com/RMuLf)

Comment: My point being: just specifying “assembly” isn't enough to make it segfault.

Comment: 'ret' by itself should be a valid program; I suspect that is an error in the emulator.

Comment: @JB: On MS DOS, *no* program will *ever* produce a segmentation fault. That's because MS DOS runs in real mode where memory protection is nonexistent.

Comment: @celtschk IIRC NTVDM will eke out on nonexistent addresses, and those not allocated to MS-DOS.

Comment: @celtschk: You can segfault it anyway like so: mov bx, 1000h ; shr ebx, 4 ; mov eax, [ebx] -> CPU raises the underlying SEGV (AFAIK there's nobody to handle it though).

Comment: Whether `ret` by itself crashes depends on whether there's an outer environment to return to.  For instance, if this is used as the body of `main` in a typical C environment, it will _not_ crash (but it will exit with a garbage status), but if it's used as the sole contents of an ELF text segment, it typically _will_ crash because the initial stack frame created by the OS has a null pointer for the return address.

Comment: I have modified the answer to count bytes instead of characters.

Answer (score 36):

## Python 2, 13

```
exec'()'*7**6
```

Windows reports an error code of c00000fd (Stack Overflow) which I would assume is a subtype of segmentation fault.

Thanks to Alex A. and Mego, it is confirmed to cause segmentation faults on Mac and Linux systems as well. Python is the language of choice for portably crashing your programs.

Comment: `Segmentation fault: 11` on Mac

Comment: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` on Linux

Comment: Does this hang up first?

Comment: @MegaMan As in take a long time to finish? No, 7**6 is only about 100K so there's no perceptible delay.

Comment: Why does this work? It doesn't seem to on Python 3.6.8 on Mac OS.

Comment: @MaxGasner Try reading the programming language again :)

Comment: why does it work on py2?

Comment: @MaxGasner https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/B2B-SO/images/logo-so-PRINT-4.png

Comment: yes, obviously, but where? like is this a CPython implementation detail because the parser doesn't catch the syntax error early, etc.

Comment: "error code of c00000fd (Stack Overflow)" hey wait a minute i recognize that from somewhere

Comment: @MaxGasner: `print` and `exec` are no longer "statements" in Python 3, they MUST be used like functions: `exec('()'*7**6)` (15 bytes works on both Python 2 and 3)

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work on 3.8.9 (or at least my build of 3.8.9) on OS X. -- at least this version is clever enough to instead give you a`RecursionError`

Answer (score 29):

## pdfTeX (51)

```
\def~#1{\meaning}\write0{\expandafter~\string}\bye
```

This is actually probably [a bug](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/4841c950ab64b14f#), but it is not present in the original TeX, written by Knuth: compiling the code with `tex filename.tex` instead of `pdftex filename.tex` does not produce a segfault.

Answer (score 27):

## LOLCODE, 4 bytes

```
OBTW
```

Does not work online, only in the C interpreter.

Comment: LOL FANCY CODE M8 8/8 KTHXBYE

Answer (score 22):

### Python, 33 characters

```
>>> import ctypes;ctypes.string_at(0)
Segmentation fault
```

Source: http://bugs.python.org/issue1215#msg143236

### Python, 60 characters

```
>>> import sys;sys.setrecursionlimit(1<<30);f=lambda f:f(f);f(f)
Segmentation fault
```

Source: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/test/crashers/recursive_call.py?view=markup

This is the Python version I'm testing on:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
```

In general the Python interpreter is hard to crash, but the above is selective abusiveness...

Answer (score 22):

## W32 .com executable - 0 bytes

This will seem weird, but on 32 bit Windows systems, creating and executing an empty .com file *may* cause a segfault, depending on... something. DOS just accepts it (the 8086 having no memory management, there are no meaningful segments to fault), and 64 bit Windows refuses to run it (x86-64 having no v86 mode to run a .com file in).

Answer (score 20):

## Bash, 4 bytes

**Golfed**

```bash
. $0
```

Recursively include the script into itself.

**Explained**

Recursive "source" (.) operation causes a stack overflow eventually,
and as *Bash* does not integrate with [libsigsegv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/), this results in a SIGSEGV.

Note that this is not a bug, but an expected behavior, as discussed [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-08/msg00100.html).

**Test**

```bash
./bang 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

[Try It Online !](https://goo.gl/NSPme0)

Answer (score 19):

## Forth - 3 characters

```
0 @
```

(`@` is a fetch)

Comment: Shortest one so far that will work on modern systems.

Comment: Which Forth? Gforth just says "Invalid memory address"

Answer (score 18):

### brainfuck (2)

```
<.
```

Yes, this is implementation-dependent. SIGSEGV is the likely result from a good compiler.

Comment: How is a compiler that segfaults on that "good"? That `<` should either have no effect or wrap around.

Comment: Immediately producing a runtime error on bounds violation is best because it lets the programmer find and fix the bug as fast as possible. Letting the buggy program run for a while and corrupt memory haphazardly before crashing just makes the problem harder to diagnose. Preventing the crash entirely, as you suggest, is worst; the programmer may get the program "working" and then be publicly humiliated when it crashes on standard compilers and interpreters.

Comment: Conversely, catching bounds violations before runtime is not possible in general, nor especially useful in the cases where it is possible. Producing a more descriptive runtime error would be okay, but having the operating system catch it as a segfault is great because it doesn't have any speed cost. (In case it's not clear, the compiler itself doesn't segfault--it produces executables that segfault as soon as they try to access memory out of bounds.)

Comment: Can you provide an implementation that produces this behavior and was created before this challenge was posted? If not, this answer is invalid.

Comment: Bounds checks are implementation specific, so I'm sure there are some that would error on it. Would any SIGSEGV though? I doubt it. There are a large number of programs that depend on the array wrapping to the left though. It can be rather convenient having growable storage on both sides.

Comment: My compiler for Sun machines gave SIGSEGV, as of version 1.1 released in 2004. (http://web.archive.org/web/20040815081834/http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/dbc.c) Because it was pretty obviously the best thing to do. (Any counterarguments?) I haven't done a survey of other people's brainfuck compilers that generate machine-language executables. If I bother I'll report back here afterward. (Because having array space available to the left is nonstandard, careful brainfuck programmers won't use that space deliberately. So it's helpful to let them know ASAP when they use it accidentally.)

Comment: Some brainfuck implementations let you go out into the wild west, and allocate tape memory (and do memory magicks) for you if you do so. So yes, it is implementation defined.

Comment: Some do. Because many (if not most) do not, this "feature" is only used by those who don't care about making their programs portable or those who aren't thinking about it. For people who want to be careful, bounds checking is more useful.

Answer (score 17):

## Perl ( < 5.14 ), 9 chars

```
/(?{??})/
```

In 5.14 the regex engine was made reentrant so that it could not be crashed in this way, but 5.12 and earlier will segfault if you try this.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Perl 5.14 (Debian) and 5.18 (Arch Linux). http://sprunge.us/RKHT

Comment: Reproduced with Perl v5.20.2 (windows)

Comment: What about `/(?R)/` on older Perl versions?

Answer (score 16):

### C, 18

```
main(){raise(11);}
```

Comment: do you need to add #include <signal.h> in the code listing?

Comment: @FlorianCastellane: in C90 and lower, for any function call done without a visible declaration, the compiler implicitly declares it as `int func()`. i.e. a function returning `int`, taking unspecified parameters. In this case `raise` is a function returning int, taking an int argument, so this works out (even if the compiler complains).

Comment: @Hasturkun `main(){main();}`

Answer (score 14):

### Haskell, 31

```
foreign import ccall main::IO()
```

This produces a segfault when compiled with GHC and run.  No extension flags are needed, as the Foreign Function Interface is in the Haskell 2010 standard.

Comment: _Awwww._ I was gonna post `import Foreign;main=peek nullPtr::IO Int`, but that's 40.

Answer (score 11):

### C - <s>11(19)</s> <s>7(15)</s> <s>6(14)</s> 1 chars, AT&T x86 assembler - 8(24) chars

C version is:

```
*(int*)0=0;
```

The whole program (not quite ISO-compliant, let's assume it's K&R C) is 19 chars long:

```
main(){*(int*)0=0;}
```

Assembler variant:

```
orl $0,0
```

The whole program is 24 chars long (just for evaluation, since it's not actually assembler):

```
main(){asm("orl $0,0");}
```

**EDIT**:

A couple of C variants. The first one uses zero-initialization of global pointer variable:

```
*p;main(){*p=0;}
```

The second one uses infinite recursion:

```
main(){main();}
```

The last variant is <s>the shortest one -</s> 7(15) characters.

**EDIT 2**:

Invented one more variant which is shorter than any of above - 6(14) chars. It assumes that literal strings are put into a read-only segment.

```
main(){*""=0;}
```

**EDIT 3**:

And my last try - 1 character long:

```
P
```

Just compile it like that:

```
cc -o segv -DP="main(){main();}" segv.c
```

Comment: in C isn't       **main;**     only 5 charecters

Comment: @Arya: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: only  `main;`in file.c

Comment: :Linker doesn't check whether main is function or not .It just pass it to the loader and return **sigsegv**

Comment: @Arya: Now I got it. Yep, your kung fu is better.

Comment: @Alexander---smart programmer

Comment: @Arya That may run fine (if it happens that the bytes at `main` appear to form valid instructions) or raise an `SIGILL` instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl In this case `main` is a zero-initialized global int variable, so what we get is a result of trying to execute some zero bytes. In x86 it'd be something like `add %al,(%rax)` which is a perfectly valid instruction which tries to reach memory at address stored in `%rax`. Chances of having a good address there are minimal.

Comment: Of course the last entry can be used for everything, you just have to supply the right compiler arguments. Which should make it the automatic winner of any code golf contest. :-)

Comment: Usually compiler flags other than ones that choose the language version to use are counted towards the total.

Answer (score 11):

### Perl, 10 / 12 chars

A slightly cheatish solution is to shave one char off [Joey Adams' bash trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4403/3191):

```
kill 11,$$
```

However, to get a  real segfault in Perl, `unpack p` is the obvious solution:

```
unpack p,1x8
```

Technically, this isn't *guaranteed* to segfault, since the address 0x31313131 (or 0x3131313131313131 on 64-bit systems) just might point to valid address space by chance.  But the odds are against it.  Also, if perl is ever ported to platforms where pointers are longer than 64 bits, the `x8` will need to be increased.

Comment: What is this `1x8` thing?

Comment: @HannesKarppila It's a short way to write `"11111111".`

Comment: You can replace `1x8` with `$^`, it's long enough in both 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 11):

## Python 33

```
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(),11)
```

Sending signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in python.

Comment: Also 33 characters: `from os import*` and `kill(getpid(),11)`

Answer (score 10):

## F90 - 39 bytes

```
real,pointer::p(:)=>null()
p(1)=0.
end
```

Compilation:

```
gfortran segv.f90 -o segv
```

Execution:

```
./segv 

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FF85FCAE777
#1  0x7FF85FCAED7E
#2  0x7FF85F906D3F
#3  0x40068F in MAIN__ at segv.f90:?
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Materials:

```
gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
```

Comment: Nice first post.

Answer (score 9):

## dc - 7 chars

```
[dx0]dx
```

causes a stack overflow

Comment: Is works, but can you elaborate? Why does it behave that way?

Comment: `[dx0]` stores `dx0` on the stack, then `d` duplicates the top stack element, then `x` pops the top stack element (`dx0`) and executes it. Which duplicates the top stack element, and starts executing it... the `0` needs to be there to prevent this being a tail call, so they all build up.

Answer (score 9):

## PicoLisp - 4 characters

```
$ pil
: ('0)
Segmentation fault
```

This is intended behaviour. As described on their website:

> If some programming languages claim to be the "Swiss Army Knife of Programming", then PicoLisp may well be called the "Scalpel of Programming": Sharp, accurate, small and lightweight, but also dangerous in the hand of the inexperienced.

Answer (score 9):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>17 16 11 10</s> 9 bytes

```
⌠[]+⌡9!*.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9Rz4LoWO1HPQstFbX0/v8HAA)

If the above doesn't crash, try increasing the number (multi-digit numbers are specified in Actually with a leading colon)

Crashes the interpreter by exploiting [a bug in python](https://bugs.python.org/issue14010) involving deeply nested `itertools.chain` objects, which actually uses to implement the `+` operator.

Answer (score 8):

## OCaml, 13 bytes

```
Obj.magic 0 0
```

This uses the function `Obj.magic`, which unsafely coerces any two types. In this case, it coerces 0 (stored as the immediate value 1, due to the tag bit used by the GC) to a function type (stored as a pointer). Thus, it tries to dereference the address 1, and that will of course segfault.

Comment: `it coerces 0 (stored as the immediate value 1)` - why is 0 stored as 1?

Comment: @Skyler see edit

Comment: `Obj.magic()0` is one char shorter :)

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 3 characters

```
j1Z
```

This would be the part where I explain how I came up with this answer, except I legitimately have *no clue*. If anyone could explain this for me, I'd be grateful.

[Here it is in an online interpreter.](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=ajFa&debug=on%)

> ### [Explanation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-returns-sigsegv/104269#comment253355_104269)
>
> `j` squares the base and calls itself recursively until the base is at least as large as the number. Since the base is **0**, that never happens. With a sufficienly high recursion limit, you get a segfault.
>
> [- **Dennis ♦**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-returns-sigsegv/104269#comment253355_104269)

Comment: Figured something out! From browsing Pyth's source, I found that this code does `j` on `1` and `0`, which *tries* to convert `1` into base `0`. Why that segfaults, I have no idea...

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/macros.py#L748). `j` squares the base and calls itself recursively until the base is at least as large as the number. Since the base is **0**, that never happens. With a sufficienly high recursion limit, you get a segfault.

Comment: @Dennis [IDEone](http://ideone.com/wfPKb4)

Comment: @SeeRhino The Pyth interpreter sets the recursion limit to 100,000. At least on TIO, that's enough for a segfault.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3.8+, 47 bytes

```python
eval((lambda:0).__code__.replace(co_consts=()))
```

Not the shortest python entry by far, but this one works without any imports. And as a bonus, this bug is exploitable to get arbitrary code execution, if you're smart about it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, this is a pretty interesting answer!

Comment: It's honestly amazing that this language that has such a simple interface when seen from above gives you such incredibly deep access into the language's own runtime internals.

Answer (score 7):

### 19 characters in C

```
main(a){*(&a-1)=1;}
```

It corrupts return address value of main function, so it gets a SIGSEGV on return of `main`.

Comment: It depends on the stack frame layout, so in some architecture it can possibly not fail.

Comment: Why not simply `main;`, or `main(){*""=0;}`?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick `main;` is already given in another answer.

Comment: @saeedn Then why post it at all? This one isn't even the second to shortest!

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick At the time I was posting mine, `main;` wasn't posted and I didn't know it works. I was only pointing out that it is already given and no point in changing my answer. Furthermore, people here don't just post only for the shortest, sometimes a different way of solving the problem is also interesting.

Comment: @saeedn You're right; I can't blame you for posting an answer that was later surpassed. Regarding your second point, the title explicitly says the _shortest_ code.

Answer (score 7):

### C# - 62

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(IntPtr.Zero);
```

## C# /unsafe, 23 bytes

```
unsafe{int i=*(int*)0;}
```

For some reason I don't understand, `*(int*)0=0` just throws a NullReferenceException, while this version gives the proper access violation.

Comment: The `int i=*(int*)0;` returns a NullReferenceException for me.

Comment: You can try to access a negative location, like `*(int*)-1=0` and get an access violation.

Comment: The particular exception is just what the clr wraps it in, and is insignificant. The os itself actually gives the seg fault in all these cases.

Comment: The reason why `*(int*)0=0` throws an exception is likely due to optimization. Specifically, to avoid the cost of checking for `null`, the optimizer may remove null checks, but when a segfault occurs it may rethrow it as a proper `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 7):

### Cython, 14

This often comes in handy for debugging purposes.

```
a=(<int*>0)[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

### J (6)

```
memf 1
```

`memf` means free memory, `1` is interpreted as a pointer.

Comment: Why `1` rather than `0`? Is it legal to free a null pointer in J?

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab - Yes it is possible!

In a response to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16342688/983722) of mine, Amro came up with this quirk:

```
S = struct();
S = setfield(S, {}, 'g', {}, 0)
```

Comment: Please give Matlab version -- R2015B (and 2016B also) just throws an error: Error using setfield (line 56)
At least one index is required.

Comment: @FlorianCastellane Not able to try all versions now, but it has been confirmed to give a segfault in quite some versions, the latest being 2014b and the earliest 2012a.

Answer (score 6):

## C - 14 chars

Be sure to compile an empty file with `cc -nostartfiles c.c`

> #### Explanation:
>
> What went wrong is that we treated _start as if it were a C function, and tried to return from it. In reality, it's not a function at all. It's just a symbol in the object file which the linker uses to locate the program's entry point. When our program is invoked, it's invoked directly. If we were to look, we would see that the value on the top of the stack was the number 1, which is certainly very un-address-like. In fact, what is on the stack is our program's argc value. After this comes the elements of the argv array, including the terminating NULL element, followed by the elements of envp. And that's all. There is no return address on the stack.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to score with the additional args

Comment: You have to add 14 bytes for the special flag.

Comment: @ErikGolferエリックゴルファー -nostartfiles is actually 13 bytes long :)

Comment: @CharlesPaulet I think you have to count the space too.

Answer (score 6):

## Rust, 34 bytes

```
fn main(){unsafe{*(0 as*mut _)=3}}
```

Just a null pointer assignment, nothing special here.

---

As a bonus, <del>45</del> <del>44</del> 40 bytes solution not using `unsafe`. Arguably [a bug in a compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28179).

```
#![no_main]#[no_mangle]static main:i8=0;
```

Main is usually a function ;).

Answer (score 6):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), Interpreter Bug, 2 bytes

```
<?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P/fxv7/fwA)

This interpreter is so buggy it is beautiful. I can cause a bad `free()` with one byte of code in [two](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P@/9v9/AA) [ways](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P8/9v9/AA). But that, unfortunately, is a SIGABRT.

A quick check of the source code will tell you that the interpreter does not support wrapping. However, the bug isn't "lul I read backwards and it crashes", it is a little more in depth.

The Phooey code translates to these function calls:

```cpp
< tape.left(1) // move left one cell
? debug() // print debug info
```

So let's step through it:

First, we call `tape.left(1)`.

```cpp
    void left(int64_t amount) {
        right(-amount);
    }
```

This turns into `tape.right(-1)`:

```cpp
    void right(int64_t amount = -1) {
        pointer += -1;
```

Adding `-1` to `pointer` results it being `-1`, since the initial value was zero.

**However**, let's double check what type `pointer` is:

```cpp
    size_t pointer = 0;
    size_t furthest = 0;
```

`pointer` is a `size_t`, which is an *unsigned* type, meaning that this `-1` turns into a REALLY big number. Specifically, `SIZE_MAX`, the largest object size C++ is allowed to handle.

```cpp
        if(pointer > furthest)
            furthest = pointer;
```

We assign `pointer` to `furthest`, because `SIZE_MAX > 0`.

Now, we call `debug()`:

```cpp
void Phooey::debug() {
    std::cout << "Tape: " << tape << std::endl;
}
```

And this calls the operator overload function for `std::ostream << Tape`, and here is our bug:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Tape& tape) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i <= tape.furthest; i++) {
        stream << tape[i];
    }
}
```

Let's substitute `tape.furthest`, if the bug wasn't clear enough:

```cpp
    for(size_t i = 0; i <= SIZE_MAX; i++) {
        stream << tape[i];
    }
```

This loop will keep reading data from the `tape` pointer and printing it, until it segfaults. It is actually an infinite loop otherwise: Since `tape.furthest` is `SIZE_MAX`, it will always be true, as `SIZE_MAX + 1 == 0`.

How ironic that the bug occurs in the `debug()` function.

A simple way to fix this would be to add wrapping support, making sure that the pointer is always in range. As a matter of fact, almost every bug in this program can be fixed with range checks.

#### Bonus!

`debug()` is the buggiest function in this program. It segfaults even without putting any `?`s in your code!

```
<3-509
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P/fxljX1MDy/38A)

You may be saying, "How are you calling `debug()` without `?`?

And the answer is: [ROP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming).

Specifically, on this exact build of Phooey, the tape is stored on the stack, and `cells[-3]` contains the return address from `call Phooey::run()`, `0x403957`.

509 bytes before that is just after `Phooey::debug()` sets up its stack frame. (If I set the pointer to the start of the function, it crashes too early to be interesting since the stack is unaligned). That is why I subtract 509.

It segfaults because it is definitely NOT called how the code expects it to be, and `rdi` doesn't have the `this` pointer, so it crashes.

This is OBVIOUSLY going to be dependent on the system and binary itself.

Answer (score 5):

### Unix PDP-11 assembly, 18 bytes binary, 7 bytes source

(this is becoming a theme with me, maybe because it's the only language I sort of know that no-one else here does.)

```
inc(r0)
```

Increments the single byte addressed by the initial value of r0 [which happens to be 05162 according to the simh debugger] as of program start.

```
0000000 000407 000002 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
0000020 005210 000000
```

And, as always, the extraneous bytes at the end can be removed with strip.

I made a few attempts to get the source shorter, but always ended up getting either a syntax error or SIGBUS.

Answer (score 5):

## x86 and x86_64 machine language, 3 bytes

```
0:       50                      push   %eax
1:       eb fd                   jmp    0
```

This pushes the value of the EAX (or RAX in long mode) register to the stack in a loop until the stack overflows.

To [try this](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@cn1dcopCckVikkJuYmRcda6sUU2FqEFORmhRTkZaiZP3/PwA), compile and run the following C program.

```
const char main[]="\x50\xeb\xfd";
```

To try it on Windows, prepend the following to mark `main` as executable.

```
#pragma section("foo", execute)
__declspec(allocate("foo"))
```

Comment: Main is *not* loaded in at address 0. As such, that jmp alone is causing the segfault. (I'm pretty certain,at least)

Comment: @moonheart08 it isn't jumping to absolute address `0`, it's jumping to the `push %eax`. Jumping to absolute address `0` would require something like `xor %eax, %eax; jmp *%eax`

Comment: A long time later, i learned that the hard way (bugggssss!)
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Squire](https://github.com/sampersand/squire) commit `93d3bf1`, 6 bytes

```
" "*-1
```

A quite intriguing blunder.

My initial attempt was to allocateth \$\text{II}^\text{LXIV}-\text{I}\$ bytes of memory, but alas, Squire thwarteth me by limiting string lengths to \$\text{XXXII}\$-bit integers, and even my peasant computer with a mere \$\text{VIII}\$ gigabytes of RAM was impervious to said attacks, but lo! Even if `malloc` rewardeth `null`, Squire containeth a defense stronger than steel:

```c
void *xmalloc(size_t length) {
        void *ptr = malloc(length);

        if (ptr == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error allocating %zu bytes of memory\n", length);
                // Alas, thwarted again with SIGABRT!
                abort();
        }

        return ptr;
}
```

Instead, I ventured into `value.c` and spied this:

```c
        case SQ_TSTRING: {
                sq_number amnt = sq_value_to_number(rhs);

                struct sq_string *result = sq_string_alloc(AS_STRING(lhs)->length * amnt + 1);
                // ...
        }
```

As with most strings in C, Squire terminateth all strings with `\N`, so Sampersand addeth \$I\$ whilst calculating the length.

Intriguingly, \$\text{I} \times -{\text{I}} + \text{I} == \text{N}\$. Therefore, this rewardeth `&sq_string_empty`.

```c
struct sq_string *sq_string_alloc(unsigned length) {
        if (length == 0)
                return &sq_string_empty;
        // ...
}
```

To be more swift, Squire containeth some "static" strings for common values like `"false"` or `""`.

```c
struct sq_string {
        char *ptr;
        int refcount;
        unsigned length;
        bool borrowed;
};

struct sq_string sq_string_empty = {
    .ptr = "",
    .length = 0,
    .refcount = -1,
    .borrowed = false,
};
```

Curiously, we have a string literal treateth as `char *`, which, despite its mutable appearances, is actually a member of the evil `.rodata` clan. These sneaky impostors are indistinguishable from normal strings, unless one encanteth `-Wwrite-strings`.

Returning to `value.c`, the next line triggers the `.rodata` impostor:

```c
                // Lo! Sampersand hath summoned nasal demons!
                *result->ptr = '\0';
```

In order to make thine computer repent from nasal demons, thy great and powerful Linux exorcises Squire with a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: I thoroughly enjoyed reading this

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby 3.x, 10 bytes

```ruby
->x=(1in^x
```

Ruby doesn't like a circular pin reference in proc argument for some reason, this results in a null pointer dereference. Since this is a parser bug the program doesn't even have to be syntactically valid.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript Shell, 7 bytes

```
clear()
```

Clears absolutely everything, not just the current scope which obviously causes lots of borks which result in JS blowing up and segfaulting

Comment: According to MDN (document.clear), this should only do something in really old versions of Mozilla, and even then, what really segfaults in your experience?

Comment: @tomsmeding this is window.clear, FF directly doesn't reveal it, it's a spidermonkey built-in

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), <strike>311</strike> <strike>227</strike> 223 bytes

```java
import sun.misc.*;import java.lang.reflect.*;class M{public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{Constructor<Unsafe> c=Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();c.setAccessible(true);c.newInstance().getAddress(0);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#TYwxT8NADIV3fsWNdwwn9kClqGXowISYEIPruOmhiy@ynRSp6m9PL8DQyU/f@56XNIxFzOnEcUiK8bH5J98wQ8zAfRQ6ZkKrFWZQdW@Q@DJOh5zQqYHVM5fUuaFy/26SuP/8ciC9BmcnKWd1rz9Io6XCl21hNZnQijx/sMKRNg5f/lL8/R97sh3VKNTd2T40GJWsRSTVdMjka0MrZTrvqweM5MM6b7tOquSfQnO9PizLDQ)

Ungolfed:

```java
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class SegFault {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Constructor<Unsafe> unsafeConstructor = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        unsafeConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe = unsafeConstructor.newInstance();
        System.out.println(unsafe.getAddress(0));
    }
}
```

Saved 84 Bytes thanks to Mistah Figg

Comment: It does the same as the Dyvil Answer below

Comment: Ask the OP. After searching, I think Access Violation and SegFault are maybe two names for the same thing.

Comment: TIO throws a SIGSEGV on OpenJDK, so I think its Possible that Oracle and OpenJDK throws same things but under different names.

Comment: Why the long names and `import x.y.asdf;` instead of `import x.y.*;` ?

Comment: `args` -> `a` for a 3 byte savings

Comment: Remove the space before `throws` and the space before the declaration of `c` for a 2 byte savings

Comment: Using `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` instead of importing it saves 9 bytes

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#TY2xDsIwDER/JWPKELEXkCpgYGBCTIjBdU0JSp0qdikS4ttLgIXpTnfvdJPv@pjUyMCu84JuVmIAEbN/9kMdPBpR0Cz36BvTgWd70OS5PZ2h0GuKo5jtA6lXH/l5gzu4ANy6RJdAqG4dWTQNqDEtjixwoRUuf8Z9j1xLuqFsEzV/sC1KdEJaIZKIrwPZ3NAnZRp3mQNGssVnXjVNypCdF@XrNU1v "Java (OpenJDK 9) – TIO Nexus")

Comment: This can be shortened by using `var` "keyword" introduced in Java 10 to avoid typing the long type name of `getDeclaredConstructor` result.

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-98 (FBBI), 1 byte

```
=
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=PQ&input=) (expand the *Debug* section to view the segfault)

This only works in the [FBBI](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI) implementation of Befunge, exploiting a bug in its string handling code. Any attempt to read a string from an empty stack will result in a null pointer dereference. You can achieve the same result with the `i` (Input File) and `o` (Output File) instructions, which also expect a string on the stack.

Note that this error wouldn't occur if the stack was simply full of zeros, which in Befunge should be semantically equivalent to an empty stack. For it to crash the stack must be genuinely empty, as is the case on startup.

Answer (score 3):

## Tcl, 60 bytes

```
set a a;while {[incr i]<999999999} {set a [list $a]};puts $a
```

Not short, but crashes with a segfault.

This builds a deeply nested list (each with only one element), and when trying to serialize it, Tcl will crash with a stack overflow.

[I have reported this bug here](https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview?name=c31f72813b)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua (`luajit`), <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```lua
function f()c=coroutine;c.resume(c.create(f))end
```

An attempt to compete for the bounty that was recently set on an answer in Lua. This is a function submission (basically because I had to define a function anyway, so not including the code to run it saves bytes). Now with 4 bytes saved due to a suggestion by @ceilingcat to avoid repeating the word `coroutine`.

The program works by creating infinitely many coroutines, suspending each in turn to create and start the next. The most commonly used Lua interpreter, `lua`, thought of this case and starts causing coroutine creation to fail after a while. `luajit`, however, segfaults. (Valgrind reports the issue as a failure to grow the OS-defined stack; this is believable, seeing as one common coroutine implementation gives them each separate parts of the stack.)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua (LuaJIT), <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```
f=require"ffi"f.cdef"int puts()"f.C.puts()
```

Uses FFI in LuaJIT to call `puts()` with no (valid) argument.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 15 bytes

```
eval a='eval a'
```

Segfaults (Ruby 2.3 on Ubuntu xenial)

Answer (score 3):

## Lua 5.3.2 PUC-RIO (the "official") interpreter - 57 bytes

```
local t={}t.__newindex=t local y=setmetatable({},t)y[1]=1
```

Note: does not work on all machines, and was fixed in Lua 5.3.3.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>19</s> 12 bytes

```
Start=code{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3P7gksajENjk/JbW69v9/AA)

Every function always returns something in Clean, including `Start`. Because we haven't specified the type of `Start`, the compiler assumes (and it can only assume when you inline ABC) that it takes no arguments. Since it takes no arguments, there's nothing on either stack when the function resolves, and so the runtime tries to evaluate the first node in the spine of a graph with... Zero nodes.

Comment: Nice, but the explanation is not entirely correct. The compiler knows the arity by the number of arguments of `Start`; there is no way to write a function in ABC that takes a number of arguments other than the number of arguments of the Clean function. On startup, a `Start` node is created. When it is evaluated, it is overwritten by `_cycle_in_spine`. The ABC code is supposed to push a new node on the stack, with which the `_cycle_in_spine` is then filled. But because it doesn't, the `fill_a` instruction then attempts to fill an uninitialised node above `_cycle_in_spine`.

Comment: @Keelan I learn something new every time you comment :). I'll edit that in once I'm back at my computer.

Answer (score 3):

## NASM, 3 characters.

any of the following:

```
ret
nop
cbw
cwd
cdq
clc
cld
cli
cmc
aaa
aas
aad
aam
stc
std
sti
```

`ret` causes stack underflow. `cli` and `sti` trigger SIGSEGV because they are privileged instructions.  All the other opcodes trigger a SIGSEGV simply because there's no exit point.

Comment: Under Linux, `cli` and `sti` will segfault all by themselves, because they're privileged, not because of the lack of exit point.  You could add `hlt` to the list for the same reason.

Comment: @NateEldredge Isn't `hlt` the opcode for "halt"? `hlt` causes the program to segfault, and does not halt the processor, even though the NASM manual (http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html#section-A.74) says it does.

Comment: Yes, `hlt` will halt the processor **if** executed at privilege level 0, but if not then it raises a general protection fault.  See for instance https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/hlt.  Linux userspace programs are at privilege level 3, and the kernel handles the GPF by delivering SIGSEGV to the process.  `cli` and `sti` are in a similar boat, though the privilege requirements are more complicated.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ok, I've updated this answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 3046 bytes

Behold, an answer in Malbolge that you can embed inside an answer!

```
bP&A@?>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$T"!~}|;]yxwvutslUSRQ.yx+i)J9edFb4`_^]\yxwRQ)(TSRQ]m!G0KJIyxFvDa%_@?"=<5:98765.-2+*/.-,+*)('&%$#"!~}|utyrqvutsrqjonmPkjihgfedc\DDYAA\>>Y;;V886L5322G//D,,G))>&&A##!7~5:{y7xvuu,10/.-,+*)('&%$#"yb}|{zyxwvutmVqSohmOOjihafeHcEa`YAA\[ZYRW:U7SLKP3NMLK-I,GFED&%%@?>=6;|9y70/4u210/o-n+k)"!gg$#"!x}`{zyxZvYtsrqSoRmlkjLhKfedcEaD_^]\>Z=XWVU7S6QPON0LKDI,GFEDCBA#?"=};438y6543s1r/o-&%*k('&%e#d!~}|^z]xwvuWsVqponPlOjihgIeHcba`B^A\[ZY;W:UTSR4PI2MLKJ,,AFE(&B;:?"~<}{zz165v3s+*/pn,mk)jh&ge#db~a_{^\xwvoXsrqpRnmfkjMKg`_GG\aDB^A?[><X;9U86R53ONM0KJC,+FEDC&A@?!!6||3876w4-tr*/.-&+*)('&%$e"!~}|utyxwvutWlkponmlOjchg`edGba`_XW\?ZYRQVOT7RQPINML/JIHAFEDC&A@?>!<;{98yw5.-ss*/pn,+lj(!~ff{"ca}`^z][wZXtWUqTRnQOkNLhgfIdcFaZ_^A\[Z<XW:U8SRQPOHML/JIHG*ED=%%:?>=~;:{876w43210/(-,+*)('h%$d"ca}|_z\rqYYnsVTpoRPledLLafIGcbE`BXW??TY<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(DCB%@?"=<;|98765.3210p.-n+$)i'h%${"!~}|{zyxwvuXVlkpSQmlOjLbafIGcbE`BXW??TY<:V97S64P31M0.J-+G*(D'%A@?"=<}:98y6543,1r/.o,+*)j'&%eez!~a|^tsx[YutWUqjinQOkjMhJ`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;9U86R53O20LKJ-HG*ED'BA@?>7~;:{y7x5.3210q.-n+*)jh&%$#"c~}`{z]rwvutWrkpohmPkjihafI^cba`_^A\[>YXW:UTS5QP3NM0KJ-HGF?D'BA:?>=~;:z8765v32s0/.-nl$#(ig%fd"ca}|_]yrqvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgJHdGEa`_B]\?ZY<WVUTMR5PO20LK.IHA))>CB%#?87}}49zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*ki'hf$ec!~}`{^yxwvotsrUponQlkMihKIe^]EEZ_B@\?=Y<:V97S64P31M0.J-+GFE(C&A@?8=<;:{876w43s10qo-&%kk"'hf$ec!b`|_]y\ZvYWsVTpSQmlkNiLgf_dcba`C^]\?ZY;WV97SLK33HM0.J-+G*(D'%A$">!};|z8yw543t1r/(-,+*)(i&%fd"!~}|_t]xwvutslqTonmPkjLhKIedGEaZY^A?[Z=X:POT75QP31MFEJ-+**?DC&$@98=~|:{y7xv4us1rp.omll#('&g|#d!~a|{z\\qvuXsUkjoRPOOdihKfH^]bEC_B@\?=Y<:V97S6433HML/J,BAF)'&&;@?"=}549zxww.32s0p(',+*kj!&g$#d!~`|_]y\ZYYnsrUSohglOMihKfH^]bEC_B@\?=YX;V8NMR53O20L/-I,*FED'&A:#>=~;:z87xv4-,1rp.om+*ki'~}$ec!b`__tyx[vXnmrUSoRPlOMihgJIdcb[D_^A\[=Y<:V97SR5P2HGL/-IH+F(>=B%#?"~<}{9zx6wu3tr0/.on+*)('~g$#d!~`|{^y[qpuXVrqToQgfkNLhKIeHFbEC_B@\?=Y<:V97SRQ43NMLKJIHA*EDCBA#9>=<;{3z165.32+0q.-,+l)(h&ge#db~a_{^\x[YuXVrUSoRPlkjMLaJedGbaCBBW\[><XQPU86R53O20L/-I,*F)'C&$@#!=~|:98yx54-t10q.-m+lj(igff{"!b`|uty\ZvYWsVTpSQmPNjMKgJHdcbED_^]\U>YX;VU7S64PO2M/EDI,*F)'&&;@?"~<549zx6wu3tr0qo-nl*kihh}$#"cb}|{zyxqZutWrqSoRPlkNiKa`eHFbEC_^A\>TSX;9U86R53O20L/-I,*FED'&A@?>=<;:3z76543s+0/.-m%l#('&}${"c~}`{z\x[YuXVUUjonQlNdchKIedGEaZY^A?[><X;9U86R53O20//DIHG*)D=&A@#>=}||387x5u-,1rp.om+lj(igff{"!b}_uty\ZvYWsVTpSQmlkNMhgf_HcbE`_A]@>Z=;W:8T75Q42NM0.JCBG*(D'%A$">!};|zyy0543ts0/.-,%l)(i&%e#"c~`vuz][wZXtWUqTRnmPkMcbgJHdGEaDB^A?[ZY<;VUTSRQPI2MLKJI+AFEDC%;$9>=<5:38y65v32r0qonn%*)jh&}|#dbaav{z][wpotWUqTRnQOkjMKg`_dGEaDB^A?[><X;988MRQP32G0KJ-HG)ED'B$:9>!}||387x5u-,1rp.om+lj(ig%fd"ca}`^z][ZZotsrUTongPNNMhgf_dGbaD_^@\?=Y<:VU86RKJO20L/-,,AFE(C%;:?"~<;|9y105vt21rp.'&+*)ji&%${"c~}|{^yxZvYWsVTpoRPlediLJfIGcFD`CA]@>Z=;W:877LQPO21LKJIB+))(CBA@?8=~;:{87w5vt2sq/pn,+l)i!~%fd"!b}_uty\ZYYnsrUpRhglOMiLJfIGcFD`_^A@[ZYXWPU8SRQ4ONM//DIH+)E>=B%#?"~<}{9zx6wutt+0/pn,%$)jhgg|#"ca}vuz][ZZotsVTpihmPNMMbgfIGc\[`CA@@UZY<:VONSRQ4I2MLKJIH+dv'Ps$_"]~[|YzWxUvStQrOpMnKlIjGhEfCAAyxw`;zLxwpo#F!~joQmPNd<hKJr^GoEm~B@zzy,X;c(s&5QJmNGL.h-yTdEc=`;$LK=m|:FV7Cwe3craq_'J\H)jF&%B0/RQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZZXc@JYFITf918QBIhkTDBB5BxENDkJkUTOGcRfnz3nSozH3nnYZ1V1dX2nu6@W/KK/XgijX7/6BU0oGPD7vIzH7XJ@OOw267vlzWwyGvS0Tquh1GWl4ik@mM71cj4dD/tF5bNUNF8vhimddo@G8b69x3U7bfhaKtK6MnzsLBUJSyadul7ipyhPccGA0ud1SOpmk9Wg/1NdRdSPh@tui@q77Wy9Whbms@lEGI@Gg3Y02giF2n5/g2GqLtcH67BZrYm3t6jRmKBpv0YTUqkUzqfDc786L6fj0fjdu0p57YuP@03yvqxuP9eTZT4P6vx4lBzE@B6qt5qNUs1TcX6ymYItl2UzppQxEY9FNRSFZD6Yh/vqtLzZj0hmbVoZ5rRSIQjo/SL2UL15aqD3z3VpuZjP2EkGvcf4KJLxN331WhXUP4qFfM7CZqKSeiQcUgEZkbHbXFfkvn/fgbqG0s/R@0g1RDLdWwe91/bV7Wa9KizQu5AC732@F@4S7wx4B@72QsoK3tNGYyge02nCjCegfHrF@@32/uE42fbAfbMyLuf0bKIRQL3/5Ll7tw3q6zp435RWy/F8ls0IPS6RaPNRUA@0/N464664PkoOWz6XhatGjAb0jplRKD4eDxtc9Ww3HXZ4Vc2L@@h1VcK9tpiD9yV4H0yE3miYAO9cvdYOAPdiNV92loqFFHB/S6eSoZe6X@Fl7m7X9QyZ2e@Jd8NiplM8x@O7csCLPSDTOjfrh1plWy6tivl5joXMpIaDON/kCBlvHci4IJGFfFJST@hjUR9FeeCqT8ZzJ95J3nVyZiaUeojqD@7W3m0bjdW@Wt6sS4XFaMiy/DiVGPRjvXC9FgiUG15P1Q1XtRds71mLOW0yJPQ6uCpF8g6ZIXlH9Y0ZMqOmp6h@J2TkRNarQOaziGTY/v9R11Ihoi5Cm0hmjJAZ8xq9zzAzo5viyT@6h/2l1TgimdkUycyyk3SPGyZif7mqFRKZNhEy2jBydyIZaJPkfYve9ZgZbNPgiXnv7MhVd3DVidRV8N7FRBLu/kadJNJRxDZZiHo8gOoy9xuSOdmse@zqaqFW6aYCNZa5d3AJGjXkDmQKOUxkOonee1y4g5nxQpvK2ZKjQLybITOwBMBdFXA5RdHuvl0@zkfbYWfZQlcX@jlwH6tHAwV67yL3NXS1AoksLubZ6SSTGnU7sViTCwfbAd9fuEObSCJduJFyZvbvqK6h5nOlrN7vofd288v7Yp6bssKYGyKZSJd4Z2qozmZstuS3q6qVfoXIPG6Yd7vtAFeVEznVIBnMDHfoyAu8LUsbyaJ3JNNs4FVhZzwFaBNyf8/GY6Cu1wegTeqg2@V7PqSNtB9hZzbm9XKxUEFXhQfuDA@JbLdhgev7ynwGec/nh0BmnOx2@rHIDzLoHdpkDIfitFajYTCRogO5n89mvOpGpwXv85lCAxsJ6jIZbNOuAgssLPLZ/6jXYd9zWTmRb7DAelgCrSbkUb0yA95NRsm7Aa/6FCXuHAc70zrVV0tUh66iupCGJei3oiSRL@@QGWsygepJQ1zn92FmyEZ@ZQbatCJL8Hx5h8y0thvo6g64F4Ux7gxwT8Z/kikV7eT1wBXTS/vuxnf1bsMFBjIGbBOsGK37vsDQVVCXvENXWT5NNjISDtfa2NVi4aurEhlai1dVKfCqsAQXByww6eoSN3Iq4EZiImGB/0zk7zbBzpC3qeJH7hWS97w1@xaLSurSVZ9ex1/aNJmIuATyu7pt4hJsJe@5aYbvyWSAu7/8@W1n/riq/Mdhu5E/jr0Bl2BJkUSKsJHSzshkKpUZdjU3HHzP@/cVg38C3Hc66gN1yIxI3qaL4/g7M3@QEbkfZMB7Fl4PLokLzIU6QXi14V11YZvs1hx2NRL@0dXr1YJdJStmpBakqyPcyN7p@O1tgq5mB315xaQFhhUD7vi3JL/aKQN5@ShGjZlxeMg/AWwkcl@tKLLAInS1z/OnO6pv1l8vn/Rq/9h3lysL6jZrQlpgGvdd7XGD97@TkReYvKvNJtlI2BmhkJPIYCIhM6@8I/dMWrqq9McB3skfB/4tvVscp4MV1bX4TzADMtJVsU2XF3fpXZ2yaXz54tFe5Iu708nCq219RzJhA03rImGywNKrfUb1/Vb6J6CniifZyNdVpZ3ZlKSd@a0OiQwC93qtQP4J7PA/QzJjoGP/WYLDARIJ6pQauAuwkUiGXJWQAe9TePly2WxfQPV2C7wHg5UmksnnUF2@atIwPGkLezWn7Dxbj8atdqmcPg/FXX6TXWUWqVliEhtHQiF4lXrMjb3AVVVxxXO2xq4OvZNMetdNrGPLZzh4u12NdWag22scxfQyl2DNE9O1PIwNfD1GzWZ8y4cnXnVGziPbYMdvOW26naRncQ0VtryViv/8@vUv)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>38</s> 33 bytes

```rust
unsafe{*(std::ptr::null_mut())=0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvmflqeQm5iZp6FZ/b80rzgxLbVaS6O4JMXKqqCkyMoqrzQnJz63tERDU9PWoPZ/7X8A)

Full program is `fn main(){...}`. Segfaults as setting a null pointer to a type is undefined behavior (hence the unsafe block that is required).
Old version:

```rust
unsafe{std::ptr::null::<u8>().read();}
```

Comment: There is something slightly poetic about a segfault in Rust

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
ßß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/MPz//8HAA)

oh

Since `ß` isn't actually coded as a recursive function call in the underlying Python, it isn't affected by the recursion limit. I don't actually know how Jelly's quicks work under the hood, but this appears to just create a nested structure that grows until it can't anymore. Any atom or atom-like quick works after the first `ß`.

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), compiler crash, <s>36</s> 28 bytes

```cpp
class{operator*(...){*this*1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//8fSBUXV@cXpBYlluQXaWno6elpVmuVZGQWaxn@//8vOS0nMb34PwA)

Unlike the other compiler crash which I found on my own, [I totally didn't look this one up on bugs.llvm.org.](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36831).

## <s>[Assembly (as, x64, Linux)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html), <s>17</s> 10 bytes</s>

Unfortunately, this was not a segfault, but an assertion. Leaving it up with another compiler segfault as a bonus.

I wrote code that raises a SIGSEGV in assembler.

Literally.

Replace `\0` with a literal `0x00` byte.

```cpp
"\0.asciz "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywuTs1NyqnUTSz@/1@JQS@xODmzSkHp/38A)

Found this bug when golfing the assembly [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217236/94093)

Note that this bug seems to have been fixed as of v2.34.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```rust
fn main(){main()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DsxpC1f7/DwA)

Well... This just calls itself.
It may be the only way to do it without `unsafe`.

Comment: [It looks like Rust actually detects the stack overflow and aborts.](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/Py1PITcxM09DsxpC1f7/DwA). What version are you running? 

Comment: But, it also is doing segfault, before aborting... as I found with `strace`

Comment: [Oh, I guess you're right](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sys/unix/stack_overflow.rs.html#71). My bad. Good find, then!

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6, 22

```
shell "kill -11 $*PID"
```

Just shelling to whatever shell you have.

Comment: Why not do it directly in bash (11 chars): `kill -11 $$`...

Answer (score 2):

### [Dyvil](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil), 42 bytes

```
dyvil.reflect.ReflectUtils.UNSAFE.getInt 0
```

Explanation:

```
dyvil.reflect.ReflectUtils // qualified type name
     .UNSAFE               // accesses the static field UNSAFE in class
                           // dyvil.reflect.ReflectUtils, of type sun.misc.Unsafe
     .getInt 0             // calls the method sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt(long),
                           // which tries to read a 4-byte integer from 
                           // the memory address 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Whispers](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 5 bytes

```
>> 1!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSr@/9/OTsFQ8f9/AA)

### How it works

```
>> 1  - Call this line repeated
    ! - Prevent tail call
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86 .COM, 2 Bytes

```
66 61 POPAD
```

## x86 .COM, <s>5</s> 3 Bytes

```
A3 FF FF
```

Write to the segment border

Comment: Does that work? I thought that DOS runs in real mode and has no memory protection whatsoever.

Comment: @xfix in real mode segment limits are 0xFFFF

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 15 bytes

Causes a stackoverflow:

```hs
main=main>>main
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM88WRNjZgcj//wE)

Comment: You can use `m@main=m>>m`

Comment: I don't know about you, but I just get a SIGKILL.

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp (SBCL), 79 bytes.

SBCL captures pretty much every exception and signal, but we can cause an "Unhandled memory exception" which is the result of a SIGSEGV. We must tell SBCL to not consider type safety and just add a fixnum to a float, which ends up disastrous.

```
(defun f(x)(declare (optimize (safety 0))(fixnum x))(the fixnum (1+ x)))(f 0.0)
```

My SBCL image errors with:

```
Unhandled memory fault at #x14.
   [Condition of type SB-SYS:MEMORY-FAULT-ERROR]
```

Evaluating `(f '(1 5))` returned a garbage object, then `(gc)` threw Lisp into the low-level debugger after it tried to GC that object presumably. I don't see the difference in results since it is possible to jump back into Lisp from this state, and I imagine this is 100% platform dependent behavior.

Answer (score 2):

## [WebAssembly (WaWrapper)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/wawrapper), 12 bytes

```
(func $main)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K08szv3/XyOtNC9ZQSU3MTNP8/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

#### x86 machine code - 1 byte

```
08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:       5c                       pop    esp
```

This is change value of address `esp` into value `0x1`, and then raises a `SIGSEGV`.

```
(gdb) disassemble _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x08048060 : pop    esp
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) b *0x08048060
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048060
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/programming/assembly/pop 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048060 in _start ()
(gdb) i r $esp
esp            0xbfffed40   0xbfffed40
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048061 in ?? ()
(gdb) i r $esp
esp            0x1      0x1
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Zig, 26 bytes

```
pub fn main()void{main();}
```

Answer (score 2):

## F95, 27 bytes

```
program a;pointer p;p=0;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vyM/MK0ktUiiwLrA1sE7NS/n/HwA)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the language, and preferably a link to someone other users can run your code, such as [TryItOnline!](https://tio.run)?

Comment: It works with GFortran, here’s [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vyM/MK0ktUiiwLrA1sE7NS/n/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

### AArch64, 4 bytes

Raw machine code:

```
d65f03e0
```

Disassembly

```armasm
        .globl f
f:
        ret     xzr
```

Branches to the `xzr` register, which is always null. We can't do something like `str x0, [xzr]` because it would be treated as `sp`.

Answer (score 2):

## [pbrain](http://www.parkscomputing.com/applications/pbrain/), 1 byte

```
(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gqSszM@/9f4/9/AA)

This is due to an unchecked error in the [interpreter](https://www.parkscomputing.com/applications/pbrain/):

```cpp
// Interpret a container of instructions
template<typename It> void interpret(It ii, It eos)
{
   while (ii != eos) {
      switch (*ii) {
         // Snip
         case '(':
            ++ii;

            {
               SourceBlock sourceBlock;

               while (ii != eos && *ii != ')') {
                  sourceBlock.push_back(*ii);
                  ++ii;
               }

               // BUG: eos is not handled here, and when ii is incremented below,
               // it is GREATER than eos, not triggering the loop condition,
               // which is if ii is EQUAL to eos, and causing an out of bounds read.
               //
               // It should be this:
               //   if (ii == eos) {
               //       throw 5; // raise error in the interpreter
               //   }

               procedures.insert(std::make_pair(mem[mp], sourceBlock));
            }

            break;
     }
     // Snip
     ++ii;
   }
}
```

For a version which doesn't rely on an implementation bug, behold, the world's least interesting segfault: the stack overflow from recursing too much.

```
(:):
```

It does exactly as you might expect, it defines a function and then calls itself recursively.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 53 characters

```
class A:__lt__=lambda s,o:o.clear()or s
vars(A)>A()<0
```

This is a bit longer than some other solutions, but unlike some other solutions it

1. works in modern python versions (tested in 3.7.17, 3.8.17, 3.9.17, 3.10.12, 3.11.8 and 3.12.2)
2. doesn't look like it does anything dangerous/suspicious/illegal at first glance
3. showcases an actual interpreter crash rather than just explicitly dereferencing null/execing invalid code/etc

Btw, don't report this upstream, this issue is already known and closed as "wontfix" in CPython: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88004

#### Explanation:

The important part is essentially

```python
class A:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        other.clear()

AnyClass.__dict__ > A()
```

`AnyClass` can be any class (`A` in the short version) and `vars(A)` is a shorthand for `A.__dict__`.

The issue here is that the class `__dict__` property is supposed to be of type `mappingproxy` that is implemented as thin wrapper around regular `dict`s. This special type is supposed to make this dictionary immutable/read-only:

```python
AnyClass.__dict__["foo"] = 0 # TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment
del AnyClass.__dict__["foo"] # TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item deletion
AnyClass.__dict__.clear()    # AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

However, it's possible to circumvent this protection using [python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). Specifically, `mappingproxy` doesn't reimplement all of the required methods itself, but instead just delegates to the underlying `dict` implementation.

So, when we do `AnyClass.__dict__ > A()` the following happens:

0. `m = AnyClass.__dict__` is of type `mappingproxy`

   `a = A()` is of type `A`
1. we try to execute `m > a` or `m.__gt__(a)`

   `mappingproxy` doesn't implement `__gt__`, so it delegates this call to `dict`

   this essentially does something similar to

   ```python
   # except this isn't a real property so it isn't accessible from pure python
   d = m.__internal_reference_to_underlying_dict
   return d.__gt__(a)
   ```

   where `d` is the actual underlying storage of type `dict`, not the safe/immutable/read-only `mappingproxy` wrapper
2. we try to execute `d.__gt__(a)`

   `dict` does implement `__gt__`, but it doesn't know what to do with our custom type `A`, so it returns the special `NotImplemented` value

   python's data model says that when `x.__gt__(y)` (`x > y`) returns `NotImplemented`, you should try the swapped version `y.__lt__(x)` (`y < x`) before failing
3. we try to execute `a.__lt__(d)`

   our custom class `A` does have an implementation for `__lt__` that calls `clear()` on the "other" object, in this case - `d`

So with this, we were able to call `clear()` on the underlying storage for the class `__dict__` that was supposed to be made immutable by exposing it through a `mappingproxy`. This breaks some core assumptions that python heavily relies on. After that, it's pretty easy to cause a SEGFAULT by attempting to interact with an instance of `AnyClass` (or `A` in the minified version).

The use of `__lt__` and `>` here is not mandatory, this also works with any other paired binary operator (`eq`/`ne`, `add`/`radd`, `sub`/`rsub`, `mul`/`rmul`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

## Battlestar, 3 characters

```
ret
```

#### Test

```
 $ echo ret > main.bts
 $ bts main.bts
 (segfaults)
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 5 bytes

```
Archive A:A
```

Archives the variable `A` and then tries to get the value of `A`.
Throws the `ERR:ARCHIVED` error when used.

This is the closest thing you'd get to a segmentation fault in TI-BASIC, since archived data cannot be accessed directly.

In other words, [the software has attempted to access a restricted area of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

---

**Note:** TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does ***not*** equal byte count.

Comment: It's **not** a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick It most definitely is.  "A segmentation fault occurs when a program **attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access**, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed (for example, attempting to write to a read-only location, or to overwrite part of the operating system)." ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault))  **Archived data can't be accessed in TI-BASIC**, simple as that.  Do your research before commenting next time.

Comment: You seem to be saying "Fish can swim; I can swim, so I am a fish.". A segmentation fault is more specific than the definition you gave. It has to be the signal SIGSEGV, not just _any_ memory permission error. Suppose you try to use a bash command that you don't have permission to use. Is that a segmentation fault? Of course not.

Comment: Fair enough.  Though, you could've explained that in a way without trying to use a strawman like "Fish can swim; I can swim, so I am a fish."

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 25 bytes

Recursively executing the current file raises a segmentation fault. (You know, the system running Io obviously doesn't implement tail-call optimization.)

```
doFile(System args at(0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z8l3y0zJ1UjuLK4JDVXIbEovVghsUTDQFPz/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 19 bytes.

```
int main(){main();}
```

Not very interesting, just stack overflow. (pun not intended)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5, 29 characters:

```
func x(){y()}
let y={x()}
x()
```

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWaFCQ7O6UkOzlisntUSh0raCCyjw/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 29 characters

```
package x;func x(y*int){*y=4}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **x86 assembly (intel syntax), 12 chars**

```
lgdt [0x123]
```

## **How it works**

You force the cpu to load a GDT table at a random address(0x123 in this case) , and of course it'll segfault. And if that location is actually a valid gdt, you should still trigger a GPF. Also, this might triple fault if you use it on msdos.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```
cast[ptr int](4)[]=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f8/ObG4JLqgpEghM68kVsNEMzrW1uj/fwA)

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 20 bytes

```
proc x()=x();x()
x()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8vM/f@/oCg/WaFCQ9MWiK2BmAuI//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Braille](https://github.com/TryItOnline/braille) (reference interpreter bug), 9 bytes (3 UTF-8 chars)

```
⢽⢽⢹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzJSf3//9GivWC08/9/AA)

```
⢽ data_pointer += 32768
⢽ data_pointer += 32768
⢹ data_pointer[15] += shared_storage
```

The Braille interpreter does not correctly handle memory allocation.

Specifically, it will only allocate the power of two larger than the program size in Braille opcodes. This supposed data pointer does not have much to work with.

Specifically, this program would allocate 4 bytes of memory. *Technically*, just one opcode (`⢹`) is enough to write out of bounds (since it is writing 15 bytes past a buffer that is 2 bytes large), but that sadly isn't enough to create a segfault. At least not on TIO.

This code will advance the data pointer `65536` bytes forward, then write to 15 bytes past that.

Since this is outside a 64 KB page boundary, it segfaults.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bitwise](https://github.com/aaronryank/bitwise), interpreter bug, 2 bytes

```
SL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osKc8sTv3/P9jn/38A)

Hooray for input validation.

`SL` expects 3 arguments, but I give it zero.

```c
    for (line = 0; line < lines; line++) {
        char *t = strdup(s[line]);
        char *cmd = strtok(t," ");
        char *arg1 = strtok(NULL," ");
        char *arg2 = strtok(NULL," ");
        char *arg3 = strtok(NULL," ");

        //printf("%s %s %s %s\n",cmd,arg1,arg2,arg3);

        exec_cmd(cmd,arg1,arg2,arg3);

        free(t);
    }
```

`strtok` returns a null pointer since I don't supply the expected arguments, and when it dereferences it, it segfaults.

A rough fix:

```c
int _register(char *index)
{
    if (index == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // ...
```

Note: this also allows you to go past the tape bounds, but the state is a global variable so it isn't very useful for my ACE challenge.

Answer (score 1):

### Erlang 33

```erlang
os:cmd("kill -11 "++os:getpid()).
```

You can invoke like

```bash
erl -eval 'os:cmd("kill -11 "++os:getpid()).'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 54 bytes

```pascal
function _(x:int8):int8;begin _(0);end;begin _(0);end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/P600L7kkMz9PIV6jwiozr8RCE0xaJ6WmZ4IEDTStU/NS0Lh6//8DAA)

Comment: Free Pascal will not do any tail call optimize. So you may use `procedure` without parameter instead of a function: `procedure _;begin _ end;begin _ end.` would work the same.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 8 bytes (2 instrs)

```
00000000: e0fffef5 a5a4ff00                    ṭ”“ṫʠƥ”¡
```

```
sflt    SETH $255,#FEF5
        STW  $164,$255
```

Attempting to do anything with any data at a negative address causes a segfault unless you're the OS. I picked trying to store two bytes to a mem-mapped IO device so it'd look cool with `jxd`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight (C/golf)](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/blob/master/golf/knight.c), 0 bytes

*Not that I would call this interpreter golfed...*

A program that is empty (or all whitespace) segfaults.

If it is read from an empty file, `getdelim()` stores `NULL` into `stream`... ([line 236](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/blob/2e5bd8523a8f79a3b7c6fb87ebbe0fc9bea76e7a/golf/knight.c#L236))

```c
    else getdelim(&stream,&size,'\0',fopen(argv[2],"r"));
```

And when the program does an initial scan for non-whitespace... ([line 33](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/blob/2e5bd8523a8f79a3b7c6fb87ebbe0fc9bea76e7a/golf/knight.c#L33))

```c
    while(strspn(stream, "\t\n\f\r {}[]():#")) {
```

...it dereferences a `NULL` pointer.

Otherwise, it will increment the `stream` pointer ([line 54](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/blob/2e5bd8523a8f79a3b7c6fb87ebbe0fc9bea76e7a/golf/knight.c#L54))...

```c
    ++stream;
```

...recurse into `parse()` (([line 68](https://github.com/knight-lang/c/blob/2e5bd8523a8f79a3b7c6fb87ebbe0fc9bea76e7a/golf/knight.c#L68))

```c
    func[1] = parse();
```

and give that same `strspn()` an out of bounds pointer (it might take a few recursions to hit a page fault).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVltc9s2Ev4s/QpYGUukRCUU7ZvpSKI8SZpkPHWc1E7aD7YupinI5pSCWJKy6ybuX8/tLl4I6iW93DUzFkVgd/Hsg8XuQon7N3H89Uki4nQ14@OinCXLp7eTpj2SJte1obh8yPiaUJ6Im9pQmSykzIzPE8FZmrJ0KW7oo2lGP5x@fMsG1ev5hzMWVK@/PD9jh9Xr69OX7Ifq9ewjG1TCr0/OLdnTjyeW6MfTt8/Pf3IKlzn40WZ/Df7lmtnn57CsnIxvo5x13UrBlgKsxsRkwg6rudNXv@KkgEny6AvD7@PxmgwuQzLoJsikqYuCNZkX796dkBB@HJGTQ/TNAnL2RgqAvoX1LkpX3HUvxNRtNr@SI7AtF9Ow1Rp9bUrHYIBHCxbizKjZBP0sygvuuOxzs5GIkiWjZgNGyZbHuvOViGGElGN4LxeZV2TiIpiGn33PfwQbjQTMkTw8fRx49gzNJxm7v01KXmRRzJsN@J5yB8ZB3ZEwPNa6LC/F5fwyZ58fL6aOO3zScglKI5kzx6ANWedJx2XShB7dg9FLAcO9nhwBnA2eFtweeJRw4lse/8bmy5yJ1eKa54XCw5ykmCU3SamtwurozsAzHslnlw181mNdhbzXc1mfdfwOLIFIE5flvFzlgundl2oUAKN1DHdRnkTXKdcoAES6vOe5E8N6Ggj78oVpcDG9xUTEp46r6Em2uJ6EAw/2KDTDa@jwPKm4AxExW2UObilTnPYZvG0Clqe7kNYkjMtOp8LU6shNA2XwwIBiYASyAXwHZFlUlKy85WAsyksQVhvQ1YzihsYueqLBWodkJ1j4HLi00Y2KDIKPoVsmSwGwMWL9KUCLNSPFKsuQcFdHlR6x6bfjD2i3yEYbOpQzAXEMmQkjVyGXrHzomOMrB17jAGapIWYnhKmDjBKbdNVB3Ag1StNl7Bz63sBFB3HYOEEOilWaRvmD7Wi1P2fW9rzvGGS0oNJfiTVtWmKAS6iksM3TVy9eXv28d/LjO8tf2@p1stVssGl2r2b3zfH5Doslz8lkJGbs91WkX9Hsnb3EweYS0v83HUPF8RYqSPmwrlyXeaRMma8EbhCoyFxaLgtHp0qKf4jsMokZzV6v5hfB4VThkPvcpuxgABQZnKpy7oAo@L@fprOWTjtUXDw0sm4AzoQxIMuWXL8mN2aDg7qf6DyG4hFrlfmKtyAEzThGJIzPI0ggONHCwGpVJKCf6LuqL0THpxfLZQoz13UGdvpaufUth7rf75EN83oDZooYxT@KEYK2XKapY0P1mO9BgfgfIIsNyFiE3z5/f@phKZaBBq/HFwPf9yGcwBV41W9F8if/VDJ8jKwYtbxFBuDNw4@APg/Cga7omOCwqOODPgP5OACB18cnr7psDrlx1DChrdbDLBxHmZdyQQ2AxZVufyRncO52kbGuiKUJKxvWGyehVgJK8Zi4GEFNSXDS5I14ka3tAJGUTKsUgjQlU1ymuE/K@NbpAjMb3RJyFGN9gow51Kqqm8sh4zhu2/9jjv9wd6Xke5AEDBLjDS9TaMqcNnHZRoawQs0S4Y4se9RgljnWMHi4VGOltVfSmmzL8Kxhe4c5X2vjnqrMVGF4UaGV8mbmZTWDmvinLFYyVyCDXMPuhtky48KxFvZaeYvqMKAKF7IMwW6HgX/4A42ryu3Icj8H6DN0CvojCAgPmycQh8JMb7gGLK03z4FB1gupz8DzAJKuIhPs0FpEJFrohiywG4KKxsqTn8ET/gf0SHiWNvzcq@0pddZ7mCc2BE82Nh9WSeu8WOI/doaqCZNxFNosm7yi8nvrlHpOBzO8q1P8ZHLoVl3bRrLRqufUeTn7BSraAb9NGeiEvsJeF/KU26pE9QQmbx4JZXZXgVAVwd4BdXIVC@8qFjDs5a0CSZP7WaOOtdt0G@n3UXQqe8hL6mUbGtb@024BeBx4c5k@SLkFf1UWevdNTMhGSgLqGUCUhSAbYcLD0LK2R7aqjfpuy7sdSkNTzXQsBXLPsbmkwyA3gKRwGFNlqL0M3O2hGkelfqiWbtCraHL1d7TlQqvn0bNUOUL51d@ITivasQ@u45VK3Wp3trCwXvy28NDd4EHu6zYWFltc65JMaBshBcjwDpWZsHMJNygUGvX7ZE8RRQVpfaMlo2Xt9D/7JjHPthOz/02l/e1K/yY2aw7JvpzGAtvLkaJdsh6y/sCwTLJA/QDOWX8AZ2xgCwffKT2G9FiTDUMUpXWHesTXlBPRwcRXXAcuNQPdkPhvrh8ImiRXoAOnBIslBr5jQ37Lc94pmFhCh5qkZSLYffQAvLHZEi58Jb/hOehkS8FFmUTYo8NJXrJ7zm6jOw6CyhCKl2wRiRWEz8NTHEXvrpFxoIKYKFZpiTdyWtwkPC3St2X0kmuU2XpGZM082tst6e8GYsTGNSmfLr9RirXxAbwWs5TP2FUF@8pY@YzfZNtjLVI5M0Fj/b5@d0m8oUS7FvRHkwfHFKxrhQ@TXi0vhvWseMTswz@2jwGqDtWvVm0mBY5YrQ2jQY9Z2RBt@FJTl9xA1gGU3Quh2lhd0AQOJYbWcrYcsgVfxBmGmWCTq6P/15XJP@DKRLuyt8WXUPmiXDnazb5cdQtknD5iNYHASAS6gO5tw1m9GPd05rENGHjtKv2hL9tqw5GtqVKJ0f/y3@irHGSZMfqjztCWrrW567JhlXXr0999TdC9bXVPQLlG7a5gUiHJoMVpWNO20iRqoESvZ9Qk5F/BPfmTkt1o1rxjdu@i1I7rXTuKWvpHwfDAouWNvDKEVofVswvQ5r1DqIuHZ87CQa2hPZdErxkdrZe8YFvJO3BNHxAY7UMa/JuGCIHhE7ciNs2/aYfs3igAD3HV3gCbJGoQZPzLSXqQRE@dBFh9xucRJEnwTHeYiYDJZEY/0URxCWWqsx93sOfEEZftuCOiMVMDoRtU1/RFlAhsVlmU38QeGe124fudiz8G0e0R/xPE8QlN/Rr3@PU/)

Comment: Ok but that's kinda the point. It's only well defined for valid inputs and everything else is irrelevent ;p

Comment: Never said it wasn't. There are actually a lot of interpreters like this.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 17 (OpenJDK), <s>180</s> <s>177</s> 172 bytes

```
import sun.misc.*;interface A{static void main(String[]a)throws Throwable{var f=Unsafe.class.getDeclaredFields()[0];f.setAccessible(true);((Unsafe)f.get(null)).getInt(0);}}
```

This may be JVM dependent, but I think this is the most compact way to do it.

Some strategies used:

- An interface is used to get rid of the `public` modifier on the main function
- A space isn't necessary between the array brackets and the variable name `a`
- Throwable is more compact than the full name of the exception that could be thrown
- `var` is used (Java 10 and up) instead of Field, also gets rid of an import
- A direct array access to the declared fields is used (JVM dependent), for hotspot the main Unsafe instance is the first field in the class
- `getInt(0)` is used because I'm pretty sure it has the lowest profile of any method that could cause a segfault in Unsafe
- A wildcard import can be used rather than the explicit type name to cut down on text

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), interpreter bug, <s><sup>15</sup></s> 14 bytes

```
main:sb$0 f
f:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7IzP3/PzcxM8@qOEnFQCGNK83q/38A)

Here's a cute one I found by accident.

This attempts to store a byte to the address at label `f`. This is in the `.text` section.

SPIM is pretty clever in that writing out of bounds of a section will just grow the section. However, writing to `.text` is tricky.

SPIM stores instructions in a struct for easier parsing it and debugging, instead of just storing data directly.

`CPU/inst.h:57`:

```cpp
/* Representation of an instruction. Store the instruction fields in an
   overlapping manner similar to the real encoding (but not identical, to
   speed decoding in C code, as opposed to hardware).. */

typedef struct inst_s
{
  short opcode;

  union
    {
      // Snip
    } r_t;

  int32 encoding;
  imm_expr *expr;
  char *source_line;
} instruction;
```

Therefore, to store to `.text`, SPIM will give it a special treatment in `bad_mem_write()`.

`CPU/mem.cpp:395`:

```cpp
void
set_mem_byte(mem_addr addr, reg_word value)
{
  data_modified = true;
  // .data
  if ((addr >= DATA_BOT) && (addr < data_top))
    data_seg_b [addr - DATA_BOT] = (BYTE_TYPE) value;
  // .stack
  else if ((addr >= stack_bot) && (addr < STACK_TOP))
    stack_seg_b [addr - stack_bot] = (BYTE_TYPE) value;
  // .data
  else if ((addr >= K_DATA_BOT) && (addr < k_data_top))
    k_data_seg_b [addr - K_DATA_BOT] = (BYTE_TYPE) value;
  // .text or section out of bounds
  else
    bad_mem_write (addr, value, 0); // <--
}
```

In `bad_mem_write()`, SPIM will attempt to splice and recompile the instruction as if you modified the memory directly.
`CPU/mem.cpp:506`:

```cpp
static void
bad_mem_write (mem_addr addr, mem_word value, int mask)
{
  mem_word tmp;

  if ((addr & mask) != 0)
    /* Unaligned address fault */
    RAISE_EXCEPTION (ExcCode_AdES, CP0_BadVAddr = addr)
    else if (addr >= TEXT_BOT && addr < text_top)
  {
    // For halfword and byte writes, attempt to overwrite part of the instruction.
    switch (mask)
    {
    case 0x0:
      tmp = ENCODING (text_seg [(addr - TEXT_BOT) >> 2]);

#ifdef SPIM_BIGENDIAN
      tmp = ((tmp & ~(0xff << (8 * (3 - (addr & 0x3)))))
               | (value & 0xff) << (8 * (3 - (addr & 0x3))));
#else
      tmp = ((tmp & ~(0xff << (8 * (addr & 0x3))))
               | (value & 0xff) << (8 * (addr & 0x3)));
#endif
      break;
      // ...
    }

    // Free instruction if it isn't NULL
    if (text_seg [(addr - TEXT_BOT) >> 2] != NULL)
    {
      free_inst (text_seg[(addr - TEXT_BOT) >> 2]);
    }
    // create a new instruction with the encoding
    text_seg [(addr - TEXT_BOT) >> 2] = inst_decode (tmp);
```

But wait a second....

SPIM checks for NULL...
`CPU/mem.cpp:549`:

```c
if (text_seg [(addr - TEXT_BOT) >> 2] != NULL)
```

...after it already dereferenced it!

`CPU/mem.cpp:519` (after macro expansion)

```cpp
tmp = text_seg [(addr - TEXT_BOT) >> 2]->encoding;
```

And what would cause this instruction to be NULL? If it is not an instruction.
And what is at the label `f`? Nothing, so SPIM dereferences a NULL pointer.

- -1 byte: Parser abuse

I have submitted a patch fixing this but, but this works on at least 9.1.23 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/), UB, 1 byte

If you allow undefined behavior that happens to segfault on my machine (Windows 10 on x64), all of the following programs work:

- `+`
- `-`
- `*`
- `:`
- `%`
- `7`
- `>`
- `v`
- `L`
- `<`
- `^`
- `e`
- `(`
- `)`
- `j`
- `!`
- `o`
- `&`
- `r`
- `x`
- `~`
- `2`

All of these attempt to perform some operation on an empty stack. Interestingly, `,` (pop from stack) runs just fine (though it loops forever).

Answer (score 0):

## .mmo (MMIX executable), 28 bytes (7 tetras)

Doesn't cause emulator segfault, but the program itself does segfault.

Negative addresses are reserved for the OS, and a fault occurs if the protection bit in `rK` is the same as the high bit of the instruction pointer, which it will be when the OS tries to start this program at the address given to start.

```
00000000: 98090100 980a00ff 8fe6a7d6 9b16daee  Ƭµ¢¡Ƭ½¡”Ɓȧʂẹɓæḷŀ
00000010: 980b0000 00000000 980c0001           Ƭ¿¡¡¡¡¡¡Ƭ€¡¢
```

```
98090100 lop_pre 1,0                // version 1, 0 tetras
980A00FF lop_post 255               // and immediately jump to postamble
8FE6A7D6                            // almost arbitrary address to start at
9B16DAEE                            // must have high bit set
980B0000 lop_stab
00000000                            // no tetras in symtab
980C0001 lop_end
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 15 bytes

```c
main(){main();}
```

So this is why Python has a recursion limit…

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7MaQlnX/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## GFortran, compiler crash, 6 bytes

```c
#if'a'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzmxRMFOIS0zJ1XPzcCCKz0tv6ikKDEPLvL/v3JmmnqiOgA)

This answer is more appropriate for [Crash your favorite compiler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/crash-your-favorite-compiler),
but that one is closed unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 14 bytes

This *only* works on Python 3.8 :P. I found this while [scavenging](https://bugs.python.org/issue38525) bug reports.

```python
*reversed({}),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/X6sotSy1qDg1RaO6VlPn/38A)