# Shortest program that throws StackOverflow Error

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that throws a StackOverflow Error or the equivalent in the language used. For example, in *java*, the program should throw `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

**You are not allowed to define a function that calls itself** or a new class(except the one containing `main` in java). It should use the classes of the selected programming language.

And it should not throw the error explicitly.

Comment: I don't understand "use the classes of the selected programming language"

Comment: Is it ok to define a function that calls inner function like this `def s{def t=s;t}` ?

Comment: In most languages, classes are only a special kind of data structure, not the center of the universe. Many don't even _have_ such a thing.

Comment: The funny thing here is that languages that require tail recursion elimination (and implementations that support it when the languages does not require it)---which are in a very real sense better---are at a disadvantage on this. [TwiNight's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9360/78) links to the version of this that exists on Stack Overflow from the early days.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley, I wanted to say to use the structures/functions of the programming language, not to define something new; to avoid answers like define a function which calls itself.

Comment: I wonder if certain Math Errors in calculators could be called stackoverflows, if so then `99!` would be a very short one on my casio

Comment: Does a compile-time overflow violate the rules at all?

Comment: From the java doc: **Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

Comment: Is this even possible in JS?

Answer (score 90):

## Befunge, 1

I don't know Befunge, but...

```
1
```

<sub>[from Stack overflow code golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188/stack-overflow-code-golf)</sub>

Comment: Explanation: 1 is a numeric literal that gets pushed to the stack when encountered. In Befunge, control flow wraps around until it encounters an `@` to end the program.

Comment: I didn't know there was this question on StackOverflow. I searched only on this site before posting.

Comment: I'm mildly flattered to see my answer here.

Comment: This works in ><> too.

Answer (score 51):

#### Python (2.7.3), 35 characters

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1)
```

This operation itself succeeds, but both script and interactive will immediately throw `RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'` afterward as a consequence.

Inspired by elssar's answer.

Comment: I thought about putting that up as my solution instead, but wasn't sure if the error could be considered a stack overflow. Though, essentially, that is what it is, right?

Comment: @elssar: I guess there are two ways to overflow the stack: make the used part of the stack larger, or make the unused part of the stack smaller. If you imagine a bucket filling with water, you can overflow it by adding more water, but you can also overflow it by shrinking the bucket.

Answer (score 21):

### Coq

```
Compute 70000.
```

`70000` is just syntactic sugar for `S (S ( ... (S O) ...))` with 70000 `S`'s. I think it's the type checker that causes the stack overflow.

Here's a warning that is printed before the command is executed:

```
Warning: Stack overflow or segmentation fault happens when working with large
numbers in nat (observed threshold may vary from 5000 to 70000 depending on
your system limits and on the command executed).
```

Comment: That might let you think Coq is an incredibly dumb language... funny...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Actually not. The Nat type is a type level peano numeral that *must* act as if it is a linked list.

Comment: @FUZxxl: my comment was not not meant ironically at all. Decide for yourself if you want to include classical logic into that sentence, or prefer to stay constructive...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oops... sorry. I forgot that the markdown parser always eats those nice &lt;irony&gt;-tags.

Answer (score 20):

### Javascript 24 characters

Browser dependent answer (must have access to `apply`):

```
eval.apply(0,Array(999999))
```

- `eval` was the shortest global function name that I could find (anyone know of one that is shorter?)
- `apply` allows us to convert an array into function parameters, the first parameter being the context of the function (`this`)
- `Array(999999)` will create an array with the listed length. Not sure what the maximum number of arguments is, but it's less than this, and more than `99999`

IE9:

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space 
SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 20
```

Chrome 24:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

FireFox 18

```
RangeError: arguments array passed to Function.prototype.apply is too large
```

**Note** — Due to the single threaded nature of javascript, infinite loops end up locking the UI and never throwing an exception.

```
while(1);
for(;;);
```

Neither of these qualify.

**Update** — this shaves off three characters:

```
eval.apply(0,Array(1e7))
```

Comment: MDN says that `eval` is the shortest.

Comment: `eval.apply(0,Array(1e6))` saves 3 chars, you can even go with `9e9` at no cost

Comment: `apply` is a standard ECMAScript feature. There is nothing browser dependent. Unless you are talking about really old browsers, but this wouldn't work in hypothetical Netscape 2 with `apply` anyway, because `Array` class doesn't exist in Netscape 2.

Comment: new shortest in ES6: `eval(...Array(9e9))`

Comment: Probably non-standard, throws in Chrome from the console. `dir.apply(0,Array(1e7));`

Answer (score 20):

## Java - 35

```
class S{static{new S();}{new S();}}
```

Comment: Didn't OP say no new classes? I don't see a `public static void main` in there. Or am I just failing to understand Java?

Comment: @B1KMusic There are no new classes, there's only one class (S). The code uses a static initializer, it throws the SO before the jvm figures out there's no main method. Works with java 6.

Comment: I understand the static block. But what is the next block ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco That's an initializer block, it's executed when you construct a new instance.

Comment: Java8 & Eclipse: trying to run this program, no Exception is thrown, sorry...

Comment: @LuigiCortese I think it only works with java 6 or older

Answer (score 17):

## Python 2.7 (12 chars)

```
exec('{'*99)
```

results in a «s_push: parser stack overflow»

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: With `exec('{'*101)` I get `MemoryError`

Comment: In Python2, `exec` is a statement, so you can just use `exec'{'*999` (99 doesn't seem to be enough)

Comment: You need at least 100 to trigger a MemoryError. And that ≠ stack overflow

Answer (score 13):

## Mathematica, 4 chars

```
x=2x
```

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Comment: *"You may not define function that calls itself"*

Comment: That isn't a function, it's a variable (unless it isn't at all what it looks like).

Comment: You took my idea.

Answer (score 12):

**Clojure, 12 chars**

```
(#(%%)#(%%))
```

Running in the repl:

```
user=> (#(%%)#(%%))
StackOverflowError   user/eval404/fn--407 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

Comment: This reminds me of the lambda calculus expression `(\x.xx)(\x.xx)`, but I don't know clojure well enough to tell for sure if this is what's happening. I also don't see why the aforementioned expression would result in a stack overflow, so maybe you're doing some trickery with the Y-combinator? This answer interests me and an explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 12):

## Java - 113 chars

I think this stays within the spirit of the "no self-calling methods" rule. It doesn't do it explicitly, and it even goes through a Java language construct.

```
public class S {
    public String toString() {
        return ""+this;
    }
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        new S().toString();
    }
}
```

Condensed Version:

```
public class S{public String toString(){return ""+this;}public static void main(String[] a){new S().toString();}}
```

Comment: Well, `""+this` is actually `""+this.toString()`, so the method calls itself.

Comment: @TrueSoft Pretty sure java throws in a `StringBuilder` object there. `toString` will likely be called from within there.

Comment: By the time the compiler and optimizer are done, the `toString()` method ends up being `public java.lang.String toString() { return this.toString(); }`

Answer (score 12):

## C, 19 bytes

```
main(){int i[~0u];}
```

Comment: @Thomas Yes it *is* a stack overflow on any machine where local variables are allocated on the stack. Since the C language has no concept of a stack overflow indication (it's all undefined behavior; one of them manifests itself as a segfault), this does fit the original requirement.

Comment: OK, sorry, accepted.

Comment: it gives `main.c:1:16: error: size of array 'i' is negative` for me on gcc 4.8.1. The unsigned version `main(){int i[~0U];}` works.

Comment: Doesn't work for me after I manually configured a 4GB stack.

Comment: @FUZxxl Interesting; are your ints 32 bit? If so, `sizeof(i)` is 16GB. Does using an `ul` or `ull` suffix make a difference? Some systems over-commit memory and only crash if the memory is written to.

Comment: Nothing accesses the array, so it is not generated and no error. At least initializing or using it is necessary to error.

Comment: You can golf off 1byte by doing this `main(int i[~0u]){}`

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I don't think this works, because the argument declaration is equivalent to `int *i` and will neither allocate memory nor crash.

Answer (score 10):

### GolfScript (8 chars)

```
{]}333*`
```

Result:

```
$ golfscript.rb overflow.gs 
golfscript.rb:246:in `initialize': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `new'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `ginspect'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `ginspect'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `map'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `ginspect'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `ginspect'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `map'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:130:in `ginspect'
 ... 993 levels...
from (eval):4
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:293:in `call'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:293:in `go'
from /home/pjt33/bin/golfscript.rb:485
```

Basically this creates a heavily nested data structure and then overflows the stack when trying to turn it into a string.

Comment: For me, this doesn't throw an error, but outputs `[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[
[[[[[[[[[[[[[""]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]] (and so on, output too long for comments)`

Comment: @ProgramFOX, there will be some value which you can replace `333` with and it will break. `333` was the smallest value which broke for me, but if you have a different version of Ruby (or maybe the same version on a different OS, for all I know) it might handle a different number of stack frames before overflowing.

Comment: Breaks at 3192 on my machine, so `6.?` still works without adding characters.

Answer (score 10):

## x86 assembly, NASM syntax, 7 bytes

```
db"Pëý"
```

"Pëý" is 50 EB FD in hexadecimal, and

```
_loop:
push eax
jmp _loop
```

in x86 assembly.

Answer (score 8):

### **Ruby, 12**

```
eval"[]"*9e3
```

Gives

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Presumably system-dependent, but you can add orders of magnitude by bumping the last digit up (not recommended).

Edit for explanation: Similarly to some other examples, this creates a string of `[][][]`...repeated 9000 times, then evaluates it: the rightmost `[]` is parsed as a function call to the rest, and so on.  If it actually got to the beginning, it would throw an ArgumentError because `[]` is an object with a `[]` method that requires one argument, but my machine throws an error a little before the stack is over nine thousand.

Comment: hmm... crashed IRB :P

Comment: Which version? `ruby` 1.9.2 throws “ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)”.

Comment: Found an old `ruby` 1.8.7. There the posted code works as described.

Comment: Odd, it works on my 1.8.7, 1.9.2, and 1.9.3.

Comment: I would have said `def f;f;end;f`

Comment: That wouldn't fit the full problem description. And is longer.

Answer (score 8):

## Rebol (11 Chars)

```
do s:[do s]
```

Yields:

```
>> do(s:[do s])    
** Internal error: stack overflow
** Where: do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do 
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do 
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do do
do do do do do do do do do do do do...
```

Though Rebol has functions, closures, and objects...this doesn't define any of those.  It defines a data structure, which in the code-as-data paradigm can be treated as code using DO.

We can probe into the question of *"what is S"* with the REPL:

```
>> s: [do s]
== [do s]

>> type? s
== block!

>> length? s
== 2

>> type? first s
== word!

>> type? second s
== word!
```

DO never turns this into a function, it invokes the evaluator in the current environment on the structure.

Comment: +1 ... I hadn't noticed that my answer was defining a function and that was against the rules, but edited my answer to use DO...then noticed you'd already submitted that answer.  So I just deleted mine, but since I'd written up why this isn't defining an object/function/closure I thought I'd put the explanation into yours.  Also I think the do do do do is kind of funny and worth including.  :-)  Hope that's ok!

Answer (score 8):

## Casio Calculator, 11 keypresses

It's quite hard to count bytes/tokens in this "language" - I've given the number of keypresses required, excluding Shift, Alpha (the second shift key) and `=` at the end - this certainly fits into 1 byte per keypress.

Tested on the *fx-85GT PLUS* model, which is a standard, non-graphing, "non-programmable" scientific calculator. Other models will work.

Just stack up 11 cube roots:

<kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd>
<kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd>
<kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd> <kbd>3√</kbd>

It doesn't even give a syntax error about the missing number under the square root.

This doesn't seem to work with square roots.

Alternatively, repeat <kbd>cos(</kbd> 31 times.

### Output

```
Stack ERROR

[AC]  :Cancel
[<][>]:Goto
```

I believe that this qualifies as a stack overflow. The stack seems to be tiny...

Comment: I always thought it was called stack error because you "stacked up" too many roots :P

Comment: My Canon calculator gives a stack error with just about any operator (excluding at least +, -, * and /) if it is repeated 25 times or more. For instance, this causes stack error (without syntax error): `(((((((((((((((((((((((((`

Answer (score 7):

## C, 35 characters

```
main(){for(;;)*(int*)alloca(1)=0;}
```

Comment: Why store anything in the assigned space?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Because a segmentation fault is only generated when memory outside the available stack space is *accessed*. Just calling `alloca` only decrements the stack pointer.

Comment: In this case, it's impossible to solve this problem in C.

Comment: @dmckee, Not all segmentation faults are stack overflows, but I'd say this one is, since it's the result of exceeding the stack capacity.

Comment: The initial `int ` isn't needed, and you can call `alloca` within the `while()` (but assign 1).

Comment: @dmckee, [alloca](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca) allocates from the stack.

Comment: @Job: This needs an `#include<stdlib.h>`, though, I think... but you can use the implicit `int` return type and just `main(){*(int*)alloca(9999999)=0;}`.

Comment: Or maybe that's not guaranteed to do the trick, but `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)` saves the same number of characters.

Comment: I improved my answer a bit, thanks to everyone for the tips!

Comment: @ugoren: I don't really understand what you mean...

Comment: @minitech: That's not guaranteed to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @job - I see you did remove the `int`. My other suggestion is no longer needed (`while(*(int*)alloca(1)=1);` is the same length).

Comment: Thinking about this more: are you sure it's necessary to store something in the assigned address in order to access unavailable stack space? Unless `alloca` is inlined it seems to me that the stack frame used to call it should move one byte further each time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It probably depends on the implementation but in my case `alloca(1)` is basically translated to `sub $1, %esp` so the stack isn't touched.

Comment: `error: ‘alloca’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: FreeBSD allocates on the stack.  Linux allocates in the data area.  So it depends which OS you use.

Comment: Also, in some OS you have to assign the allocated space a value, because the OS won't actually allocate the space until it is needed.  But maybe that's just for malloc.

Comment: Interestingly enough, on my machine using the latest GCC, there is no stackoverflow. The code compiles down to `.L2: jmp .L2`, generating an infinite loop that never errors.

Comment: @BЈовић Compile with a C89 compiler.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith `alloca()` always allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 7):

## FORTH, 13 bytes

```
BEGIN 1 AGAIN
```

overflows the value stack

Comment: `: X X ; X` (9) must overflow return stack

Comment: won't work (X isn't defined while defining the call and that's a self reference/recursion

Comment: @ratchetfreak, those control words can only be used in a compile state, so they need to be wrapped in a `:`...`;` word definition. That adds at least 6 characters, plus at least 2 more for this to execute as a program.  You might be able to do it shorter, but here's an example: `: F BEGIN 1 AGAIN ; F`.  I suggest this because the question asks: "Write a program." Anyways, gave you an upvote for Forth, regardless of char count! :-)

Answer (score 7):

## Common Lisp, 7 characters

```
#1='#1#
```

Comment: Beautiful...I was planning to use `#1=(#1#)` for the terminal and `(print #1=(#1#))`, but your solution is so much better.

Comment: Actually that doesn't overflow at read time, only when you attempt to print it.  So aside from the 1 character difference, yours is no better.

Comment: You're right, just edited that out.  I'm not sure if there's a way to cause an overflow at read-time.

Comment: Actually, #.#1='#1# causes a read-time overflow :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Python - 11 chars

```
exec'('*999
```

---

```
>>> exec'('*999
s_push: parser stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Comment: Very clever solution.

Answer (score 6):

## Postscript, 7

```
{1}loop
```

Eg.

```
$ gsnd
GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (C) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GS>{1}loop
Error: /stackoverflow in 1
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1168/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 8
GS<1>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell (GHC, no optimization), 25

```
main=print$sum[1..999999]
```

[sum](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#sum) is lazy in the total.  This piles up a bunch of thunks, then tries to evaluate them all at the end, resulting in a stack overflow.

Comment: i always thought sum was implemented using foldl'. isn't it?

Comment: Alas, it isn't: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/src/Data-List.html#sum

Answer (score 5):

### PHP 5.4, 33 characters

```
for($n=1e5;$n--;)$a=(object)[$a];
```

This causes a stack overflow when the nested [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) objects are automatically destroyed:

```
$ gdb -q php
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/php...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) set pagination 0
(gdb) r -nr 'for($n=1e5;$n--;)$a=(object)[$a];'
Starting program: /usr/bin/php -nr 'for($n=1e5;$n--;)$a=(object)[$a];'
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000006debce in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000006debce in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex ()
#1  0x00000000006dee73 in zend_objects_store_del_ref ()
#2  0x00000000006a91ca in _zval_ptr_dtor ()
#3  0x00000000006c5f78 in zend_hash_destroy ()
#4  0x00000000006d909c in zend_object_std_dtor ()
#5  0x00000000006d9129 in zend_objects_free_object_storage ()
#6  0x00000000006dee53 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex ()
#7  0x00000000006dee73 in zend_objects_store_del_ref ()
#8  0x00000000006a91ca in _zval_ptr_dtor ()
#9  0x00000000006c5f78 in zend_hash_destroy ()
#10 0x00000000006d909c in zend_object_std_dtor ()
#11 0x00000000006d9129 in zend_objects_free_object_storage ()
[...]
#125694 0x00000000006dee53 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex ()
#125695 0x00000000006dee73 in zend_objects_store_del_ref ()
#125696 0x00000000006a91ca in _zval_ptr_dtor ()
#125697 0x00000000006c5f78 in zend_hash_destroy ()
#125698 0x00000000006d909c in zend_object_std_dtor ()
#125699 0x00000000006d9129 in zend_objects_free_object_storage ()
#125700 0x00000000006dee53 in zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex ()
#125701 0x00000000006dee73 in zend_objects_store_del_ref ()
#125702 0x00000000006a91ca in _zval_ptr_dtor ()
#125703 0x00000000006c4945 in ?? ()
#125704 0x00000000006c6481 in zend_hash_reverse_apply ()
#125705 0x00000000006a94e1 in ?? ()
#125706 0x00000000006b80e7 in ?? ()
#125707 0x0000000000657ae5 in php_request_shutdown ()
#125708 0x0000000000761a18 in ?? ()
#125709 0x000000000042c420 in ?? ()
#125710 0x00007ffff5b6976d in __libc_start_main (main=0x42bf50, argc=3, ubp_av=0x7fffffffe738, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe728) at libc-start.c:226
#125711 0x000000000042c4b5 in _start ()
```

Comment: +1 for what must be PHP's second appearance on CodeGolf!

Answer (score 5):

## Q/k (16 chars)

Not sure if this is in the spirit of the challenge but I *don't think* it breaks the rules:

```
s:{f`};f:{s`};f`
```

Comment: It's a shame C# requires so much typing, you inspired my answer!

Answer (score 5):

## C#: <strike>106</strike> <strike>86</strike> <strike>58</strike> <strike>46</strike> <strike>32</strike> 28

**32**: Getters can SO your machine easy in C#:

```
public int a{get{return a;}}
```

Comment: No need for setter `public int a {get{return a;}}`

Comment: This violates the rule "You are not allowed to define a function which calls itself". Admittedly it's hidden behind syntax sugar, but it's still missing the point of the challenge.

Comment: Adding the setter somewhat circumvents the rule, because you now have two functions calling each other.  But I wonder: does that still violate the OP's intentions behind this challenge?

Comment: The idea as I understand it is to find some excessively nested recursion in the interpreter or standard API of the language. This might not be too easy in C#.

Comment: Why "public string"?  "int" works just as well: `int a { get { return a; } }`

Comment: Fair point.  I was able to remove four characters because of a space before the first curly brace, too!

Answer (score 5):

A bunch in the same style:

### Python, 30

```
(lambda x:x(x))(lambda y:y(y))
```

### Javascript, 38

```
(function(x){x(x)})(function(y){y(y)})
```

### Lua, 44

```
(function(x) x(x) end)(function(y) y(y) end)
```

Comment: In Python `x=lambda y:y(y);x(x)` is shorter (20 chars). This function is not recursive. x calls any function passed to it as an argument.

Comment: Ruby 2.0 - `->x{x[x]}[->y{y[y]}]`

Comment: Mathematica `#@#&[#@#&]`

Comment: You're just using recursion, then why not do just that, for example in JS: (function x(){x()})() ?

Comment: @xem Requirements say no recursion, that is why.

Comment: In Lua, you can just remove all the whitespace. You don't need the spaces between the function and the "end" keyword.

Answer (score 5):

## LaTeX: 8 characters

```
\end\end
```

This is the same code used in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21114/weirdest-way-to-produce-a-stack-overflow/21322#21322). Essentially, the `\end` macro expands itself repeatedly, resulting in a stack overflow: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]`. A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124423/end-end-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded).

Answer (score 5):

## INTERCAL, 12 bytes

```
(1)DO(1)NEXT
```

### Explanation:

`NEXT` is INTERCAL's version of a subroutine call (or, at least, the closest you can get). It pushes the current position onto the `NEXT` stack and jumps to the given label.

However, if the `NEXT` stack length exceeds 80, you get what's pretty much the INTERCAL version of a stack overflow:

```
ICL123I PROGRAM HAS DISAPPEARED INTO THE BLACK LAGOON
    ON THE WAY TO 1
        CORRECT SOURCE AND RESUBNIT
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/6kyruD).

Comment: "HAS DISAPPEARED INTO THE BLACK LAGOON" what is this, ArnoldC?

Answer (score 5):

## Mornington Crescent, <s>139</s> 133

```
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Angel
```

Answer (score 4):

## X86 assembly (AT&T), 33 characters

Note that although I'm using the label `main` as a jump target, this is *not* a recursive function.

```
.globl main
main:push $0;jmp main
```

Comment: Nice idea: this is a sort of recursion-without-recursion!

Comment: using a86: `dd 0fdeb60` 10 characters!

Answer (score 4):

## Python (17):

```
c='exec c';exec c
```

Comment: hm, I get `KeyError: 'unknown symbol table entry'`

Answer (score 3):

### C -- 34 characters, no libraries

Though competative with [Job's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9377/78),

```
o(){O();}
O(){o();o();}
main(){o();}
```

violates the spirt of the challenge by showing how to evade the restriction on constructing a simple recursion. You can save 4 character by removing one call from `O`, but gcc is smart enough to recongnise that if you use `-O3`.<sup>1</sup>

The trick is quite general and can be done in fortran 77, too (142 characters):

```
      program o
      i=j()
      stop
      end
      function j()
      j=k()
      end
      function k()
      k=j()
      k=j()
      end
```

Again, gcc can optimize away a single call in each.

---

<sup>1</sup> I suppose it inlines one of them and then applys tail recursion elimination. How cool is that!?!.

Comment: `O(){o(o());}` saves a character. Replacing `O` with recursive `main` call saves more.

Comment: ‘You are not allowed to define a function that calls itself.’ I think we both agree that using an intermediary doesn't excuse it, so why post it as a ‘solution’?

Comment: Because poking your nose through loopholes in the question description is a prestigious line of work with a long and glorious tradition on [codegolf.se]?

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy (27 chars)

```
a=[:];b=[a:a];a.b=b;print b
```

And so it goes:

```
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, real stack overflow: 38

```
a=[];eval("[x "+"for x in a "*800+"]")
```

Error message:

```
s_push: parser stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Explanation:

```
[x for x in a for x in a]
```

is the same as

```
y = []
for x in a:
    for x in a:
        y.append(x)
```

so the above eval produces 800 nested for loops :)

Comment: Ah just noticed that someone else already exploited the parser in a similar, more elegant way: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9370/6491

Answer (score 3):

### Tcl, 15 chars

```
interp r {} 1;a
```

gives

> too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)

the `interp r` stands for `interp recursionlimit` (you can abbreviate subcommands). `a` calls (because not known) `unknown`, which calls a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 3 chars

```
$:1
```

This does call itself. But it does not define a function that calls itself. Rather $: keeps invoking the largest verb it is enclosed in.

```
$:1
|stack error
|       $:1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, ES6 21

```
eval('{'.repeat(1e7))
```

Due to the nature of javascript, nesting a bunch of blocks causes a stackoverflow.

For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306367/why-does-nesting-a-bunch-of-blocks-causes-a-stack-overflow-in-javascript

```
eval('('.repeat(1e7))

eval('['.repeat(1e7))
```

Other similar cases

```
eval('+'.repeat(1e7))

eval('-'.repeat(1e7))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vitsy, 1 byte

Obviously non-competing due to language creation date.

This feature of my language was entirely unintended. Because of how loops work in my language, they can be finicky if you don't match braces. So, for a one-byte solution, I give you this:

```
[
```

Posted on my [Showcase your language one vote at a time!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61937/44713) answer...

> The shortest stack overflow error you'll ever see.
>
> Basically, in Vitsy, the `[` represents "start while loop". While in a while loop, the program will wrap around the line - which means it starts another while loop, which wraps around the line and starts another while...
>
> You get it.

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=Ww&input=&debug=on)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
$G~l
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=JEd-bA&input=&args=Wg&debug=on)

#### Explanation

`$G` is `1,000,000,000`. `$G~l` is thus: *“Create a list of length 1,000,000,000”*, which does not fit the stack.

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, 5 bytes

```
run()
```

Example execution:

```
$ groovy -e "run()"
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line)
    at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line:1)
    at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line:1)
    ...
```

works as a command line script (groovy -e), standalone groovy script, and in the groovy shell.

We are not defining a new function here so not breaking the rules as far as I can understand.

This works because the groovy compiler adds an implicit run method behind the scenes and calling this method ourselves causes a StackOverflowException.

Essentially the above run() call gets translated to something like the below code by the groovy compiler before its handed off for execution by the jvm:

```
// class generated by groovy compiler
class ScriptName { 
  def args 

  def main(args) {
    new ScriptName(args: args).run()
  }

  def run() {
    // user code start
    run() // our call
    // user code end
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### VBScript, 101 characters

Not the smallest script, but created as a proof of concept

```
i=2
s="sub[2](b):i=i+1:d=replace(b,i-1,i):execute d:call getref("""&i&""")(d):end sub"
execute s
[2]s
```

This code creates new named functions on the fly by executing a string that creates a function and giving the new function this string as a parameter. The function creates a new function and calls it. Results in a `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Out of stack space: 'execute'` error.

Answer (score 2):

Scheme:

```
((lambda (x) (x x)) (lambda (x) (x x))
```

Comment: Citing the question: *"you are not allowed to define function that calls itself"*

Comment: These functions aren't written to call themselves. Instead, `(lambda (x) (x x)` is a function with one parameter that `x`, that calls `x` as a function, passing `x` as a argument.

Comment: In Racket: `((λ (x) (x x)) (λ (x) (x x)))`

Answer (score 2):

**Burlesque, 5 characters**

```
1R@p^
```

Range from one to infinity, push all elements to stack -> StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

## PERL, 19 chars

```
sub c{sub d{c()}d}c
```

Originally I posted this solution (11 chars), but I overlook that rule *"You are not allowed to define a function that calls itself"*:

```
sub c{c()}c
```

It's a pitty that PERL doesn't allow this `sub c{c}c` - would look really cute :-)

Comment: You can get down to **18** characters with `sub c{sub d{&c}d}c`. I also tried `sub c{&{$_[0]}}c\&c`, but that one is also 19 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## LI, 1 byte

```
R
```

`R`eruns the program with the given input.  Every time this is done, another two functions are added to the interpreter's stack (one interpreting the program string and another interpreting the function `R`), eventually overflowing the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua

```
function b()b()end b() --stack overflow
```

Alternatively,

```
a={}setmetatable(a,{__index=function()return a.a end})a(a.a) --C stack overflow
```

Comment: "You are not allowed to define a function that calls itself". That aside, what language is this?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: These are two separate  [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) programs.

Comment: The first one is syntactically broken. Try `a=function(b)b(b)end;a(a)` for 25 characters. It defines a function that calls its parameter, passing itself as the parameter. Certainly evades the tail recursion optimization, and skirts the spirit of not writing a directly recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 7 chars

```
[ddx]dx
```

You may watch how it consumes memory :-)

```
dc -e'[ddx]dx' & watch -n 1 "ps l|grep $!|grep -v grep"
```

Comment: When run in OpenBSD dc(1), this program overflows the *data* stack, not the *call* stack. The question never said which stack to overflow! Running `dc -e '[dx ]dx` overflows the call stack, because OpenBSD won't optimize tail recursion if there is space in `x ]`.

Comment: @kernigh what is "data stack"? There is only one stack present, and this is a call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Java + SnakeYaml and a quirk over jva.awt.point :P; length=104

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().dump(new java.awt.Point());}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## *C#*

### (59)

With a `Main` method:

```
static void Main(){unsafe{int* p=stackalloc int[1000000];}}
```

### (39)

Just the code that causes the exception:

```
unsafe{int* p=stackalloc int[1000000];}
```

Answer (score 1):

**x86_64 ASM - 7 bytes**

```
48 81 EC 00 00 60 09
```

Here is a mnemonic version.

```
SUB RSP, 0x9600000
```

This instruction by setting the stack pointer to above the maximum size, (at least on Unix) Since the stack grows downwards we use subtraction instead of addition.

You could probably also exchange RSP with RBP top set the base pointer of stack to overflow. This would require you to change EC to ED in the hex representation.

Although this doesn't throw an error, the stack is overflowed as we set the size that the stack is filled to a number above the maximum stack size.

You could improve this answer to 4 bytes if you are using an operating system with a stack size to less than one byte.

```
48 81 EC FF
```

Answer (score 1):

## [TECO](http://almy.us/teco.html), 4 bytes

I was thinking about what tasks would be best to do in TECO, and realized that infinite loops and stack overflows are among its greatest talents.

```
<[a>
```

Pushes the contents of register `a` to the stack in an infinite loop.

Result of running code:

```
*<[a>$$
?PDO   Push-down list overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/Neoscript-lang/neoscript), 22 bytes

```
try 1/0;catch e retry;
```

The division by 0 crash and execute the catch block, which call the try..catch block again, the division by 0 crash and excute the catch block again, etc...

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 63 bytes

```
PRGEDIT 1FOR I=0TO 16384PRGSET"GOSUB"+(@_+HEX$(I))*2NEXT
EXEC 1
```

Error: `Stack overflow in 1:16385`

This generates code like:

```
GOSUB @_0@_0
GOSUB @_1@_1
...
```

No recursion is used, just 16385 `GOSUB`s, enough to fill the call stack.

#### And a boring and possibly cheating answer in 10 bytes:

```
@A
GOSUB@A
```

Error: `Stack overflow in 0:2`

Comment: ‘You are not allowed to define a function that calls itself.’

Comment: It's not a function though. Functions in SB are created using `DEF`, for example: `a:DEF a:a:END` would trigger a stack overflow.

Comment: Semantics. Gosub is used to call a subprogram, and it overflows because you're pushing the same return point on the stack. So this overflows the stack for the same reason, in the same manner, as calling a recursive function in some other programming language. This solution is against the rules.

Comment: At that point you might as well ban anything that involves any type of stack, then, which would make this impossible.

Comment: How does that follow? Just read the rules. Recursively calling the same function is prohibited, but e.g. calling loads of different non-recursive functions isn't. How is that so hard to understand?

Comment: And, as an afterthought, not only is the rule and the spirit behind it easy to understand, but the reason the rule is there is pretty obvious too: anyone can overflow the stack with a recursive function. There's no trick to it and programs overflowing the stack through a recursive function call are utterly uninteresting. Just look at your own submission.

Comment: Look at “dofile’a’” in Lua. It’s just a program which recursively calls itself, just like you would define a function that calls itself. The only difference is the name (just like mine).

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 12 bytes - Fills the stack

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/whitespace#@8@loABEClxcQPT/PwA)

### Explanation

```
nssn ; Declare label ''
sssn ; Push 0
nsnn ; Jump to label ''
```

Cloned from [Shortest program that continually allocates memory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101709/shortest-program-that-continuously-allocates-memory/123310#123310). Whitespace is actually somewhat competitive for this question, I'm surprised we hadn't already had an answer.

This program loops and continuously pushes the value 0 to the stack, causing the stack to grow until the interpreter crashes (with the equivalent of a stack overflow error in whatever language the interpreter uses).

Answer (score 1):

## Braingolf, 5 bytes

```
1[l>]
```

Pushes a 1, then repeatedly pushes the length of the stack and moves it to the beginning of the stack. The loop will only exit if the first item in the stack is 0, so this loop will continually increase the length of the stack until eventually it reaches python3's deque limit.

Answer (score 1):

## GW-Basic, 18 bytes

In GW-Basic there's no separate stack overflow error as such; when the stack overflows you get error 7, ‘Out of memory’. The trick is to make sure you got this because you've ran out of stack space and not for some other reason. Enter:

```
CLEAR,,241:?SIN(0)
```

This will immediately result in:

```
Out of memory
Ok
```

The number `241` is important. Firstly, it cannot be `0` because that will yield error 5 ‘Illegal function call’. But it also cannot be `240` or less, because although you will get the out of memory error above, `CLEAR` won't actually have adjusted the stack space. So in that case the error isn't a real stack overflow, but it acts more like an illegal argument error of sorts. ‘This is too small for us to work with at all, no can do, sorry.’ You can easily check this:

```
CLEAR,,999
Ok 
CLEAR,,1
Out of memory
Ok 
?SIN(0)
 0
Ok 
CLEAR,,240
Out of memory
Ok 
?SIN(0)
 0
Ok 
CLEAR,,241
Ok 
?SIN(0)
Out of memory
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#: 62 (full program)

(full program, not excerpt like other one, although it's based on it)

```
class A{static int a{get{return a;}} static void Main(){a=a;}}
```

Comment: I think someone else already posted that.

Answer (score 0):

### R - 5 (plus 18 for the command line switch)

Using a ridiculously small memory allocation (`--max-mem-size=32M`), you can do this easily:

```
1:1e9
```

I tried this without setting the memory limit, and that caused my computer to hang. I don't know if it would have overflowed or not. If not, a score of 6 (`1:1e99`) would surely do it.

Comment: Exhausted memory is *not* a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

## fish shell (14 characters)

In my opinion, this doesn't count as declaring a function that calls itself. Could be shorter if [this pull request](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/1204) would be applied (by one character), but considering it wasn't yet (and I'm not going to do this just to make my code shorter), this has to work.

```
alias ls ll;ls
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java : 131 characters

```
public class HelloWorld{public HelloWorld(){main(new String[]{"3","4"});}public static void main(String []args){new HelloWorld();}}
```

Comment: The question is a code-golf question, so remove all unnecessary whitespace, 'golf' your code and add the character count.

Comment: Violates the you may not define a function that calls itself rule. main() transitively calls itself

Answer (score 0):

### Batch (7 chars)

It requires CALL or the execution of the calling batch ends right after starting itself again.

```
CALL %0
```

I'm not defining a function which calls itself, hence Batch doesn't even have functions. Also I did not create any classes. So this is valid.

Answer (score 0):

## Node.js REPL (15)

```
eval(RegExp.$1)
```

Sample session:

```
> eval(RegExp.$1)
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (repl:1:12), <anonymous>:1:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, 24 characters (no cheating)

```
x(){main();}main(){x();}
```

Compile with default `cc` settings and ignore warnings.

### C, 10 characters (with cheat)

```
X{Y;}Y{X;}
```

compile with:

```
cc -DX='x()' -DY='main()'
```

Comment: Violates the *you may not define a function that calls itself* rule. `main()` transitively calls itself.

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript/Javascript - Only in Chrome (24 chars)

Sorry for waking up an old post

This only works in Google Chrome (tested in Firefox and Chrome):

```
JSON.stringify a:5,->a:5
```

http://coffeescript.org/#try:JSON.stringify%20a%3A5%2C-%3Ea%3A5

This is not converting a circular structure to JSON. Actually, it uses the replacer function: the replacer function returns another object so the object ends up stringifying that object whose replacer also returns an object.

It gets compiled to the following JavaScript:

```
JSON.stringify({
  a: 5
}, function() {
  return {
    a: 5
  };
});
```

Tested on Chrome 39.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 29 bytes

This one causes a stack overflow by generating a new function every call and calling it.

```
l=loadstring s='l(s)()'l(s)()
```

Here are some other creative answers:

### 9 bytes:

```
dofile'a'
```

This causes a C-stack overflow.  Requires you put it in a file named `a`.

### 39 bytes:

```
package.loaded.a=z require'a'
```

This causes a C-stack overflow.  Requires to be put in a file named `a` and requires `LUA_PATH=a`.

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby - Proc fun - 18

```
a=->(b){b[b]};a[a]
```

Basic recursive solution. In `irb` ends up with:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Answer (score 0):

## ANTLR4 / Java, 103 Bytes

```
grammar P;
r:(C|N)+;
C:(('p'|'i')P);
P:(N|S)*;
N:[0-9]+;
S:[A-Za-z0-9_]*;
WS:[ \r\n]+ -> skip;
```

**To use**:
Better create a new directory to put the file in, I used the common aliases shown on the antlr4 site.

```
antlr4 P.g4 && javac P*.java && echo 'Press Ctrl-D in 5 secs.' && grun P r -gui
```

Don't have **any** idea why this works, and I think it can be golfed much.

Answer (score 0):

### Rust, 29 bytes

```rs
fn main(){let a=[0;9000000];}
```

I hadn't thought it would be that easy. It actually gives segmentation fault, but given that it's rust, I'm pretty sure it's the stack that throws in the towel.

I wonder if the compiler ought to give a warning about stuff like this?

Answer (score -1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 70 bytes

```java
public class Main{public static void main(String[] args){main(args);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#@19QmpSTmayQnJNYXKzgm5iZVw0VKS5JLAFSZfmZKQq5QHGN4JKizLz06FiFxKL0Ys1qsBiYaV1b@/8/AA)

Comment: You are not allowed to define a function that calls itself. The exception for main was meant for creating a new class, not for recursion.

Comment: That is quite the same as the Groovy Solution.

Comment: Also, is it even necessary to pass main args?

Comment: I do, I pass args, the String[] which the main method receives. could name it shorter as I see it