# Weirdest way to produce a stack overflow

Tags: popularity-contest, stack

As a programmer you certainly know the error of a stack overflow due to an obvious recursion.
But there are certainly many weird and unusual ways to get your favourite language to spit that error out.

Objectives:

1. Must cause a stack overflow which is clearly visible on the error output.
2. Not allowed to use an obvious recursion.

Examples of invalid programs:

```
// Invalid, direct obvious recursion.
methodA(){ methodA(); }
```

```
// Invalid, indirect, but obvious recursion.
methodA(){ methodB(); }
methodB(){ methodA(); }
```

The most creative ways are the best as this a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). I.e, avoid boring obvious answers like this:

```
throw new StackOverflowError(); // Valid, but very boring and downvote-deserving.
```

Even though I accepted an answer now, adding more answers is still okay :)

Comment: I tend to produce by navigating to stackoverflow.com, though I have been known to query 'stack overflow' on my search engine of choice.

Comment: It's too bad http://mailinator.blogspot.no/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html is just an infinite loop.

Comment: There are many good (and short!) answers here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/shortest-program-that-throws-stackoverflow-error. I hope nobody will copy those answers.

Comment: @JasonC You don't need to advertise your posts on this question with a comment. The OP owner will get a notification, and anyone who would upvote or such will find the answer without needing to read your comment.

Comment: @Quincunx Sure; sorry.

Comment: Use Internet Explorer. A sure way to catch one :)

Comment: @asgoth explain plz

Comment: @masterX244 I mean, IE can produce javascript errors (e.g. `stackoverflow at line 0`), while the code runs fine in other browsers. My comment was meant to be sarcastic. Sorry if it failed.

Comment: didnt knew that one thats why i asked @asgoth 
avoiding Internet Exploder since multiple years so the bugs didnt fgound a way into my memory

Comment: Hey does it have to compile? I have given an example of one that would overflow, but compilers will refuse to compile it because the behavior is never intended, not because it is semantically wrong. (C++ - constructor to construct temporary to pass to constructor causes infinite loop at runtime)

Comment: post cause some compilers could accept it; (like the TeX example which relies on certain versions

Comment: The weirdest way to produce a stack overflow is to post a popularity-contest on codegolf.stackexchange.com asking for people to post the weirdest way to produce a stack overflow. The responders, in testing their solutions to the question, will produce a stack overflow. I haven't tested it though, so I can't be sure it works (which is why I didn't post it as an answer).

Comment: I'm partial to this method: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html

Comment: #[Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)# This is only an idea (one specific implementation in Java can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617792/programs-that-reproduces-itself)).
A quine is a program that produces it's own code. If you take it a step further, you can make the code be saved to file and compiled during run time, then executed. This will not cause a classic StackOverFlow error, but a (much more risky...) disk memory overflow.

Comment: @TimSeguine - that sure sound like recursion to me!

Comment: I'm presuming that the goal is to cause an actual stack overflow, rather than to simply throw a StackOverflowError or whatever your language calls it.

Comment: [Drive a Toyota](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/14/02/21/2349204/stack-overflow-could-explain-toyota-vehicles-unintended-acceleration) (Hey, wait a minute, my car **is** a Toyota...)

Comment: I used to have a program bug that called a super-method of an overridden method by accident, causing a stack-overflow by the `EventDispatcher` thread, but I can't remember where nor reproduce it.

Comment: Here is the weirdest way to produce a StackOverflow. Get a time machine. Go back to 2008. Create a vote-based, community-run question-and-answer site about programming questions, where users can post their problems and get reliable results. Come back to your current time. Edit this post with the URL of your Q&A site. This should generate a StackOverflow. EDIT: I did it, here is my site: http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 224, accepted):

### Python

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1)
```

This will cause the interpreter to fail immediately:

```
$ cat test.py
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1)
$ python test.py
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' in <function _remove at 0x10e947b18> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' in <function _remove at 0x10e8f6050> ignored
$
```

Instead of using recursion, it just shrinks the stack so it will overflow immediately.

Comment: I do love that :D

Comment: .......... cute

Comment: Cute, but not quite what the original question was aiming for in my opinion.

Comment: @Nit I don't see the problem.  What about this solution is unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Nit its not the usualy way of spamming stack :)

Comment: @masterX244 Yes, the whole point of the question is "don't do it the usual way".

Comment: @Plutor do you usually set up a StackOverFlow on purpose ?

Comment: This was only mildly clever the [first time it was posted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9368).

Comment: @primo 185 upvotes disagree with you. :)

Comment: @JeffGohlke As a matter of etiquette, answers which are not original to the poster, or have been posted elsewhere on this site _verbatim_, should be marked as community wiki. Also, this question was posted just after a surge of activity from ~600 visits per day, to over 4000 per day, which I believe thoroughly explains the low quality of the highest voted answers.

Comment: We've heard the old joke, the optimist sees a glass half-full, the pessimist sees a glass half-empty, and the programmer shrinks the glass so it gives off a glass overflow error.

Comment: When this code is executed in an interactive Python prompt, the interpreter is unable to even give an explanation for the error. It just gives `RuntimeError` no matter what you enter, even a blank line. If the recursion limit is set to 2, all statements still fail (including blank lines), but it'll give `RuntimeError: maximum recursion limit exceeded`. If the recursion limit is set to 3, anything that indirectly calls a function will fail but a traceback is generated (and blank lines no longer generate errors).

Answer (score 189):

## Python

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: Fantastic. Nice and elegant.

Comment: Much literal. Very answer.

Comment: I don't see the recursion

Comment: @copy Recursion ain't needed. Ya just need ta make a stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, this *shows* a Stack Overflow, but to *produce* one, this only works if it's Jeff Atwood or Joel Spolsky executing it.

Comment: @TimSeguine Wow.

Comment: Not an answer as it's not in the error output.

Comment: My face when I saw this answer. I was actually thinking the same thing when I clicked it from Hot Network Questions.

Comment: @TimSeguine I up-votted your comment then accidentally clicked again and it undid my up vote and apparently if you undo an up vote it won't let you re-upvote after (even after waiting the 5 seconds)... I would go complain on META but I'm too lazy... you should be able to #Meta in comments and it auto-generates a post on META :D

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail **produce**: Show or provide (something) for consideration, inspection, or use. E.g., "he _produced_ a sheet of paper from his pocket". Synonyms: _present_, _offer_, _provide_, _furnish_, _advance_, _put forward_, _bring forward_, _come up with_. Have I sufficiently swayed you to accept even the technical/pedantic correctness of this answer, or should I _produce_ more evidence?

Comment: I'm voting this up because I didn't know about the `webbrowser` module, it's awesome.

Comment: I don't want to see your production code, if this is supposed to be the **weirdest** way to produce a stackoverflow

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I believe you can recast your upvote if somebody edits the answer.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Maybe you should write a Meta post about using #Meta to auto generate a Meta post. But, I guess you're too lazy until they implement this feature. At which time you requesting it would be moot

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw And you clicked OK to the JavaScript dialog that warns you that you will not be able to upvote it again?

Comment: @Tortoise Did not exist at the time. But even if it did, as with most dialogues, 90% of people will click okay without reading it. For this very reason, dialogue consequences should never be permanent.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Oh wow, that was a three-month-old post. I dug too deep.

Answer (score 131):

### C / Linux 32bit

```c
void g(void *p){
        void *a[1];
        a[2]=p-5;
}
void f(){
        void *a[1];
        g(a[2]);
}
main(){
        f();
        return 0;
}
```

Works by overwriting the return address, So `g` returns to the point in `main` before calling `f`. Will work for any platform where return addresses are on the stack, but may require tweaks.

Of course, writing outside of an array is **undefined behavior**, and you have no guarantee that it will cause a stack overflow rather than, say, paint your mustache blue. Details of platform, compiler and compilation flags may make a big difference.

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a segfault?

Comment: +1 for the weird stack manipulation and absolutely no recursion!

Comment: @11684, It's undefined behavior, so in general it could crash. On 32bit Linux (that I tested on), it writes outside the array, overwriting the return address, and doesn't crash until the stack overflows.

Comment: I get a `segmentation fault` (@11684) when i try to run this. (gcc 4.7.3, Xubuntu 13.10)

Comment: @klingt.net, A stack overflow causes a segmentation fault. But it might fail if you use 64bit.

Comment: Note that `gcc` would optimize it away at `-O2` and higher.

Comment: @devnull, I guess I need to emphasize "undefined behavior" in the post.

Comment: @ugoren Fair enough.  Neither have I downvoted your answer, nor did I say that it's wrong.  I simply stated that it (or as you'd prefer, the _undefined behavior_) wouldn't work with `-O2` or higher.

Comment: "Paint your moustache blue" -> That line had me.

Comment: @ugoren, [you are right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Stack_overflow), my fault.

Comment: Wow. This is fantastically obfuscated.

Comment: @11684 It will cause a seg fault due to stack overflow but not necessarily a seg fault due to a direct access violation, as long as a[2] still points into the address space of the process (which, in a working case of this program, it does).

Comment: I think changing into this will work on x64 Linux: http://pastebin.com/p4KEqSmS

Comment: @AneeshDogra Heck, it could kill your family!

Answer (score 107):

### JavaScript / DOM

```
with (document.body) {
    addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
        appendChild(firstChild);
    }, false);

    title = 'Kill me!';
}
```

If you want to kill your browser try that out in the console.

Comment: I'm sure you deserve more +1 votes, but sadly people tried this before voting.... lol

Comment: Well, that was effective. I couldn't even get my task manager open to kill it.

Comment: Use Chrome, close tab. Problem solved.

Comment: `with (document.body) {
    addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
        appendChild(firstChild);
    }, false);

    title = 'Kill me!';
}
15:43:43.642 TypeError: can't convert undefined to object`

Comment: Damn My Firefox was hanged

Comment: My Firefox wokrs fine with this code, just shown box saying "The script works long, continue?"

Comment: Isn't this recursion though? It'll just keep on repeating the same function.

Answer (score 91):

## Java

Saw something like this somewhere around here:

**Edit:** Found where I saw it: [Joe K's answer to *Shortest program that throws StackOverflow Error*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10449/9498)

```java
public class A {
    String val;
    public String toString() {
        return val + this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new A());
    }
}
```

That can confuse some Java beginners. It simply hides the recursive call. `val + this` becomes `val + this.toString()` because `val` is a String.

See it run here: http://ideone.com/Z0sXiD

Comment: Actually, it does `new StringBuilder().append(val).append("").append(this).toString()`, and the last append calls String.valueOf(...), which in turn calls toString. This makes your Stack trace a bit varied (three methods in there).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yeah, that is correct. However, it is much easier to say that it becomes `"" + this.toString()`.

Comment: I think the `+ "" +` might tip people off, as it looks useless at first glance. `String val;` and `return val + this;` might be marginally sneakier

Comment: @Cruncher not at all. If you are a Java coder, you would know that the easy way of concatenating an int to a string during `""`-String construction is with the `+ ""`

Comment: @quincunx actually in java int+string works. The purpose in this case is because int + Object is undefined. To get the implicit toString call you need to concat object with a string.

Comment: In a real world application I would prefer val+this.toString(); explicit is always better

Comment: In a real world application I would prefer to avoid infinite recursion and stack overflow errors

Answer (score 77):

## C

Quite easy:

```
int main()
{
    int large[10000000] = {0};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for non obvious! Despite it is very system dependent (an `ulimit -s unlimited` in the shell solves this in linux)

Comment: @RSFalcon7, thanks for the +1, but to me this was actually the most obvious!!

Comment: Is this just 0ing the stack? How does that result in recursion?

Comment: @Cruncher: It doesn't result in recursion. The problem given was to blow the stack. On many operating systems the stack is of fixed size, and far smaller than ten million ints, so this blows the stack.

Comment: Do we get the requested "stack overflow" error message for this one? Or rather some out-of-memory when trying to allocate the array?

Comment: @HannoBinder, In Linux where I tested, you don't get a stack overflow error. You get a segmentation fault, since overflowing the stack results in access to unowned segments. I'm not sure if stack overflow error even exists in Linux, since an infinite recursive function call also gives out a segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can reduce that code by replacing `10000000` with `9e9`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, no, because `9e9` is of type `double`. Although `(int)9e9` would work.

Comment: Then it's not worth to change it in the answer. It would be sweet if you could do `9e9` like in PHP.

Comment: `9**9` is pretty large number too

Comment: But `9**9` isn't C.

Comment: `~0u` is a pretty large number in C.

Comment: @Vortico, yes that could also be used. Although it's not necessarily a pretty large number in C, but rather on 32-bit or 64-bit architectures.

Answer (score 63):

## Non-recursive stack overflow in C

Calling convention mismatch.

```
typedef void __stdcall (* ptr) (int);

void __cdecl hello (int x) { }

void main () {
  ptr goodbye = (ptr)&hello;
  while (1) 
    goodbye(0);
}
```

Compile with `gcc -O0`.

`__cdecl` functions expect the caller to clean up the stack, and `__stdcall` expects the callee to do it, so by calling through the typecast function pointer, the cleanup is never done -- `main` pushes the parameter onto the stack for each call but nothing pops it and ultimately the stack fills.

Comment: nice way of spamming the stack :P

Answer (score 62):

I was frustrated by the fact that java 7 and java 8 are immune to my evil code in [my previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21121/3755). So I decided that a patch for that was necessary.

Success! I made `printStackTrace()` throw a `StackOverflowError`. `printStackTrace()` is commonly used for debugging and logging and no one reasonably suspects that it could be dangerous. It is not hard to see that this code could be abused to create some serious security issues:

```java
public class StillMoreEvilThanMyPreviousOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            evilMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void evilMethod() throws Exception {
        throw new EvilException();
    }

    public static class EvilException extends Exception {
        @Override
        public Throwable getCause() {
            return new EvilException();
        }
    }
}
```

Some people may think that this is an obvious recursion. It is not. The `EvilException` constructor does not calls the `getCause()` method, so that exception can actually be thrown safely after all. Calling the `getCause()` method will not result in a `StackOverflowError` either. The recursion is inside JDK's normally-unsuspected `printStackTrace()` behaviour and whatever 3rd party library for debugging and logging that are used to inspect the exception. Further, it is likely that the place where the exception is thrown is very far from the place where it is handled.

Anyway, here is a code that does throw a `StackOverflowError` and contains no recursive method calls after all. The `StackOverflowError` happens outside the `main` method, in JDK's `UncaughtExceptionHandler`:

```java
public class StillMoreEvilThanMyPreviousOneVersion2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        evilMethod();
    }

    private static void evilMethod() {
        throw new EvilException();
    }

    public static class EvilException extends RuntimeException {
        @Override
        public Throwable getCause() {
            return new EvilException();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Comment: :D and now with a cross java version stackoverflow compliant method. Evil bastard !
 :D

Comment: I am inclined to consider the recursion in this case obvious.

Comment: @Taemyr See my edit

Comment: @Victor Looks the same to me…`EvilException`s make new `EvilException`s when you call `getCause()`.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Calling the `getCause()` method does not results in `StackOverflowError`. It is relying in the fact that there is a JDK's code which is recursively calling the `getCause()` method.

Comment: And people who thinks that there is an obvious recursion. Can you show me, in my second code, which lines do an obvious recursion?

Comment: @Victor Why would `getCause()` ever return a new instance of the exception class that's being defined? It doesn't seem useful at all, unlike, say, [overriding `stdout` and `stderr`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21130/13547) or [printing a stack trace on exception](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21121/13547).

Comment: @BlacklightShining I didn't say that it is useful. I just said that it is no recursion. If the constructor actually called `getCause()` it would be recursion, but it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think the edit makes the recursion any less obvious.  The fact that you make a valid program cause an error in the JDK outside of your code is cool.  The fact that people are expecting getCause to be the thing that is recursing is perhaps a strong argument that the recursion is nonobvious.

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't seem to overflow when using a checked exception and printing the stacktrace. Perhaps the error stems from the JDK being less rigorous with unchecked exceptions?

Comment: @Cruncher I tested this using `java 1.8.0-b109` (early access, a bit old but just a bit) and got the `StackOverflowError` regardless of if I made `EvilException` to extends `Exception`, `RuntimeException`, `Error` or even directly from `Throwable` in both forms posted in this answer. Which JDK/JRE version are you using?

Comment: @Victor 7. Nevermind though. It never printed something like `Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"` at the end, but it still throws a stackoverflow with a long stack trace.

Comment: I thought you could simplify this by changing the body of `getCause` to just `return this;` but apparently Java is too clever for that. It notices that it is a "`CIRCULAR REFERENCE`".

Comment: I did not get a `StackOverflowError` because the OpenBSD 5.5 package of jdk-1.7.0.21p2v0 has a bug. It doesn't throw `StackOverflowError`. It hits `SIGSEGV` and dumps core.

Answer (score 61):

### JavaScript

```
window.toString = String.toLocaleString;
+this;
```

Comment: This one is underappreciated.

Comment: What does `+this` do?

Comment: Unary + invokes the ToNumber abstract operation. That uses the ToPrimitive operation with a hint type of number. ToPrimitive on an Object uses the [[DefaultValue]] internal method, which when passed a number hint, first checks to see if the valueOf() method exists and returns a primitive. window.valueOf() returns an object, so instead [[DefaultValue]] returns the result of calling toString(). The first thing window.toString does (now that it's toLocaleString) is invoke toString on 'this'. Repeat.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore (Firefox 25 returns `NaN`, Chrome throws error - "Too much recursion").

Comment: If Chrome throws an error, 'Too much recursion', then it does work on Chrome, right? The stack overflows, and that's how Chrome delivers a stack overflow exception.

Comment: You should use `+{toString:"".toLocaleString}` :-)

Answer (score 57):

## Linux x86 NASM Assembly

```
section .data
    helloStr:     db 'Hello world!',10 ; Define our string
    helloStrLen:  equ $-helloStr       ; Define the length of our string

section .text
    global _start

    doExit:
        mov eax,1 ; Exit is syscall 1
        mov ebx,0 ; Exit status for success
        int 80h   ; Execute syscall

    printHello:
        mov eax,4           ; Write syscall is No. 4
        mov ebx,1           ; File descriptor 1, stdout
        mov ecx,helloStr    ; Our hello string
        mov edx,helloStrLen ; The length of our hello string
        int 80h             ; execute the syscall

    _start:
        call printHello ; Print "Hello World!" once
        call doExit     ; Exit afterwards
```

Spoiler:

> Forgetting to return from printHello, so we jump right into _start again.

Comment: In assembly, nothing is obvious.

Comment: @11684: I find the opposite to be true: in assembly, *everything* is obvious because nobody can use abstractions to hide what their code is really doing.

Comment: This is brilliant for its simplicity and elegance.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: I prefer to say that everything is **visible** instead of obvious... For a nice way to see the difference between visible and obvious, I love to refer to http://underhanded.xcott.com

Comment: @11684 I don't know, it's pretty obvious that this is classic recursion; the explanation of "if you forget to ..." is a bit sleight-of-hand.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I see your "nobody can use abstractions to hide what their code is really doing" and raise you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code. Back before anti-virus software was so prevalent and comprehensive; self-modifying assembler programs (and the study of them) were all the rage.

Comment: I remember my frequent mistakes of forgetting `ret`

Answer (score 48):

## C++ at compile time

```
template <unsigned N>
struct S : S<N-1> {};

template <>
struct S<0> {};

template
struct S<-1>;
```

```
$ g++ -c test.cc -ftemplate-depth=40000
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See  for instructions.
```

There is no recursion this source file, not one of the classes has itself as a base class, not even indirectly. (In C++, in a template class like this, `S<1>` and `S<2>` are completely distinct classes.) The segmentation fault is due to stack overflow after recursion in the compiler.

Comment: I confess I would have called this an obvious recursion in your metaprogram.

Comment: GCC detects recursion and stops gracefully this side (4.8 and above seem to be fine)

Comment: @AlecTeal It detects an excessively large template instantiation depth. It doesn't call it recursion, because it isn't, other than in GCC's own source code. :) But you have a larger stack than I did on the system I tested this on. If you use a larger maximum (try 200000, or perhaps even 2000000), you'll get the same segmentation fault.

Comment: `template <typename T> auto foo(T t) -> decltype(foo(t)); decltype(foo(0)) x;` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @Casey Nice idea! I'm surprised that that fails, though. In the trailing return type, the function being declared isn't available yet, unless later found by ADL, but `int` has no associated namespace. If I try it with a `struct S`, I do expect it to fail, and unlike the version with `int` it also causes a segfault in clang.

Comment: @hvd It seems to be exploiting a bug in GCC. [clang catches the erroneous usage](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7869d946c4a14949) - which I assume you are already aware of - but it makes my GCC spew almost 2 megabytes of error messages.

Comment: +1 for stackoverflow @compiler; btw java can be stackoverflown in compiler, too :P

Comment: +1 for [meta stack overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) :p

Comment: Still crashes the compiler as of GCC 4.9.1 (MinGW-w64): "cc1plus.exe has stopped working". Visual C++ gives `main.cpp(2): fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex`.

Answer (score 45):

## Bash (Danger Alert)

```
while true
do 
  mkdir x
  cd x
done
```

Strictly speaking, that will not directly stack overflow, but generates what may be labelled as "*a persistent stack-over-flow generating situation*": when you run this until your disk is full, and want to remove the mess with "rm -rf x", that one is hit.

It does not happen on all systems, though. Some are more robust than others.

#### Big danger WARNING:

some systems handle this **very** badly and you may have a very hard time cleaning up (because "rm -rf" itself will run into a recusion problem). You may have to write a similar script to cleanup.

#### Better try this in a scratch VM if not sure.

PS: the same applies, of course, if programmed or done in a batch script.

PPS: it may be interresting to get a comment from you, how your particular system behaves...

Comment: as I wrote: on many systems, rm -rf tries to go down and is hit by one (maybe no longer, these days, with 64bit address space - but on smaller machines with a smaller stack, it may). Of course, there may also be "rm"-implementations around, which do it differently...

Comment: Seems to me something like `while cd x; do :; done; cd ..; while rmdir x; cd ..; done;` should take care of this.

Comment: You are absolutely right (that's what I meant with "similar script for cleanup"). However, once your disk (or quota) is full, you may even have a hard time logging in afterwards, as some systems used to deal with that situation badly. You'll have to get in as root and do the script (which is easy on those PCs of today, but was often hard in ancient times, when computers where used by more than one user).

Comment: funny, this gets more votes than the Smalltalk magic below (never thought that!)

Comment: someone tried this on Windows?

Comment: On Windows paths can only be so long (~256 characters).

Comment: Typically this will run until there are no iNodes left, not until the disk is full.

Comment: This is harmless. I just tried (feb. 2014) with Linux 3.10.17 / bash 4.2.45 / ext4 (ext2fs 1.42.7) / coreutils 8.21 -- *they are not that fragile*

Comment: Does not work with `sh` in OpenBSD 5.5-current. I used `sh` because `bash` was not installed. It soon went into an infinite loop printing  `mkdir: x: File exists` and `attack.sh[5]: cd /tmp/x/x/x/.../x - File name too long`. I did `rm -rf x` and tried again with `perl -e 'for(;;){mkdir"x";chdir"x"}'`. After several minutes, this became an infinite loop printing `/tmp: create/symlink failed, no inodes free`. Command `rm -rf x` succeeded after about an hour. **No stack overflow.**

Answer (score 43):

## Java

A nice one from [Java Puzzlers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032133678X). What does it print?

```java
public class Reluctant {
    private Reluctant internalInstance = new Reluctant();

    public Reluctant() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("I'm not coming out");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Reluctant b = new Reluctant();
            System.out.println("Surprise!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("I told you so");
        }
    }
}
```

It actually fails with a StackOverflowError.

The exception in the constructor is just a red herring. This is what the book has to say about it:

> When you invoke a constructor, the **instance variable initializers run
>   before the body of the constructor**. In this case, the
>   initializer for the variable `internalInstance` invokes the constructor
>   recursively. That constructor, in turn, initializes its own
>   `internalInstance` field by invoking the Reluctant constructor again and
>   so on, ad infinitum. These recursive invocations cause a
>   `StackOverflowError` before the constructor body ever gets a chance to
>   execute. Because `StackOverflowError` is a subtype of `Error` rather than
>   `Exception`, the catch clause in `main` doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 41):

## LaTeX

```
\end\end
```

The input stack overflows because `\end` repeatedly expands itself in an infinite loop, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124423/end-end-causes-tex-capacity-exceeded).

TeX fails with a `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]` or similar.

Comment: I was waiting for a TeX/LaTeX issue. Those things are more jarring than most - usually, I've forgotten that what I'm doing counts as programming when suddenly I've managed to write something that is infinitely recursive.

Comment: See also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/shortest-program-that-throws-stackoverflow-error/22610#22610

Comment: _"TeX capacity exceeded, sorry"_ TeX is so polite when it fails.

Answer (score 39):

## BF

Will eventually overflow the stack, just depends how long the interpreter makes the stack...

```
+[>+]
```

Comment: That code reminds me of game of life.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no stack in brainfuck.

Comment: @fejesjoco Tape, if you wish.

Answer (score 32):

**On the Internet**  (used by billion people/day)

```
Redirects, HTTP status code: 301
```

For example, on the Dell support website (no offense, sorry Dell):

If you remove the support TAG from the URL then it goes into  ***infinite redirects***. In the following URL, ###### is any support TAG.

http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukdhs1/ServiceTag/######?s=BSD&~ck=mn

I believe it's equivalent to a stack overflow.

Comment: nice way :) firefox tells that it redirects so the request cannot be resolved which is the stackoverflow rquivalent :)

Comment: Note that the redirects are *not* infinite -- if you hit "Try Again" it adds a few more `/Errors/`'s to the URL and then stops after receiving HTTP 400 Bad Request. But this arguably makes for a better stack overflow than an infinite redirect does.

Comment: @nandhp, I agree, but if you think a third world browser(not modern, IE etc..), They haven't got clue of this situation.

Comment: Here's how Wget responds here: http://pastebin.com/pPRktM1m

Comment: `http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/uk/en/ukdhs1/ServiceTag/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/Errors/...`

Comment: That awkward moment when the internet breaks itself.

Answer (score 32):

### C#, at compile time

There are a number of ways to cause the Microsoft C# compiler to blow its stack; any time you see an "expression is too complex to compile" error from the C# compiler that is almost certainly because the stack has blown.

The parser is recursive descent, so any sufficiently deeply nested language structures will blow the stack:

```
 class C { class C { class C { ....
```

The expression parser is pretty smart about eliminating recursions on the side that is commonly recursed on.  Usually:

```
x = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + .... + 1;
```

which builds an enormously deep parse tree, will not blow the stack. But if you force the recursion to happen on the other side:

```
x = 1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + ....+ (1 + 1))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))...;
```

then the stack can be blown.

These have the inelegant property that the program is very large. It is also possible to make the semantic analyzer go into unbounded recursions with a small program because it is not smart enough to remove certain odd cycles in the type system. (Roslyn might improve this.)

```
public interface IN<in U> {}
public interface IC<X> : IN<IN<IC<IC<X>>>> {}
...
IC<double> bar = whatever;
IN<IC<string>> foo = bar;  // Is this assignment legal?
```

I describe why this analysis goes into an infinite recursion here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/07/covariance-and-contravariance-part-twelve-to-infinity-but-not-beyond.aspx

and for many more interesting examples you should read this paper:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/FOOL2007.pdf

Comment: The exact error message is `fatal error CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile near (code)`. The documentation for this error message is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92855ayd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and it's exactly as you say: "There was a stack overflow in the compiler processing your code."

Answer (score 31):

### PHP

A stackoverflow done with looping elements only.

```
$a = array(&$a);
while (1) {
    foreach ($a as &$tmp) {
        $tmp = array($tmp, &$a);
    }
}
```

Explanation (hover to see the spoiler):

> The program will segfault when the interpreter tries to garbage collect the `$tmp` array away (when reassigning `$tmp` here). Just because the array is too deep (self referencing) and then the garbage collector ends up in a recursion.

Comment: PHP's GC can't detect self-referential structures? Really?! Ouch. That _is_ evil.

Comment: Yes, but it's not perfect. There's some reason why `while (1) { $a = array(&$a); }` or something similar just hits the memory limit…

Comment: yup, I think it's the same reason why PHP is not working properly regarding Object Oriented development either; (abstraction, inheritance etc.)

Comment: @pythonian29033 care to elaborate?

Answer (score 30):

## Java

I did the exact opposite – a program that should obviously throw a stack overflow error, but doesn't.

```java
public class Evil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recurse();
    }

    private static void recurse() {
        try {
            recurse();
        } finally {
            recurse();
        }
    }
}
```

Hint: the program runs in O(2<sup>*n*</sup>) time, and *n* is the size of the stack (usually 1024).

From [Java Puzzlers](http://javapuzzlers.com) #45:

> Let's assume that our machine can execute 10<sup>10</sup> calls per
>   second and generate 10<sup>10</sup> exceptions per second, which is
>   quite generous by current standards. Under these assumptions, the
>   program will terminate in about 1.7 × 10<sup>291</sup> years. To put
>   this in perspective, the lifetime of our sun is estimated at
>   10<sup>10</sup> years, so it is a safe bet that none of us will be
>   around to see this program terminate. Although it isn't an infinite
>   loop, it might as well be.

Comment: Obvious recursion ... not very interesting.

Comment: @Kami Have you tried it? Did you actually get a StackOverflowError? It seems obvious, but it's not.

Comment: Just because an exception gets caught doesn't mean it was never thrown. This program throws a stack overflow exception after time O(n)

Comment: @CodesInChaos Okay, so I double-checked this, and the correct version uses `finally` rather than `catch`, and the running time is O(2^n). Answer updated.

Comment: @ntorkrnl nice one +1'd ; btw got the compiler to stackoverflow already (compiler runs inside the VM, too fyi)

Comment: For those of us who don't know much about Java internals, can you explain why this terminates?

Comment: @JustinMorgan It terminates because it's not an infinite loop. If you think of the program as a 1024-bit binary counter where a stack frame in the `try` block is a 0 and `finally` is a 1, then the program steps through all possible states of the counter, throwing a stack overflow error every time. A similar program should work in C# as well.

Comment: I checked c# version, It did take less than second to blow UP (stackoverflow).   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            recurse();
        }

        private static void recurse()
        {
            try
            {
                recurse();
            }
            finally
            {
                recurse();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @Dipak Seems that I was wrong about C#. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx), you cannot catch a stack overflow in modern versions of .NET.

Comment: The Ruby equivalent is `ruby -e 'def r; r; ensure; r; end; r`. It would not stop until I sent SIGKILL.

Comment: I may have misunderstood; by 'terminates,' do you mean it eventually errors out? That would make sense.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Yes, in theory it will eventually error out with a stack overflow. In practice, that won't happen in the lifetime of the universe.

Answer (score 30):

## C#

First post, so please go easy on me.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

This simply creates a stack trace, grabs the top frame (which will be our last call to `Main()`), gets the method, and invokes it.

Comment: nice way of selfinvoke which isnt that obvious without explain; +1'd

Comment: You should comment that code with " what could possibly go wrong ? " :P

Answer (score 26):

## Java

- In Java 5, `printStackTrace()` enters an infinite loop.
- In Java 6, `printStackTrace()` throws `StackOverflowError`.
- In Java 7 and 8, it was fixed.

The crazy thing is that in Java 5 and 6, it does not comes from user code, it happens in JDK's code. No one reasonable suspects that `printStackTrace()` can be dangerous to execute.

```java
public class Bad {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            evilMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void evilMethod() throws Exception {
        Exception a = new Exception();
        Exception b = new Exception(a);
        a.initCause(b);
        throw a;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah; stackoverflows out of nothing are the best friend for codetrolling and a serious headache on hunting em

Comment: If anyone wonders, equivalent code in C# causes an infinite loop. But `InnerException` property is read-only and is set in constructor, so reflection is necessary to cause this.

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript: Non-recursive, iterative function mutation

```js
var f = function() {
    console.log(arguments.length);
};

while (true) {
    f = f.bind(null, 1);
    f();
}
```

There's no recursion here at all. `f` will be repeatedly curried with more and more arguments until it can overflow the stack **in a single function call.** The `console.log` part is optional in case you want to see how many arguments it takes to do it. It also ensures that clever JS engines won't optimize this away.

Code-golf version in CoffeeScript, 28 chars:

```coffee
f=->
do f=f.bind f,1 while 1
```

Answer (score 14):

## C# with an epic fail

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot]
public class P
{
    public P X { get { return new P(); } set { } }
    static void Main()
    {
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(P)).Serialize(System.Console.Out, new P());
    }
}
```

The way it fails is epic, it blew my mind completely:

[image]

It is just one frame of a seemingly infinite tripping series of strange images.

This has got to be the weirdest thing ever. Can anybody explain? Apparently, the ever increasing amount of spaces used for indentation cause those white blocks to appear. It happens on a Win7 Enterprise x64 with .NET 4.5.

I haven't actually seen the end of it yet. If you replace `System.Console.Out` with `System.IO.Stream.Null`, it dies pretty fast.

The explanation is pretty simple. I make a class which has a single property, and it always returns a new instance of its containing type. So it's an infinitely deep object hierarchy. Now we need something which tries to read through that. That's where I use the `XmlSerializer`, which does just that. And apparently, it uses recursion.

Comment: yeah; serializing ftw :P; but more funny is it when ythe quirk is completely outside of your code like how snakeyaml gets the attributes and one class returns itself in a way that endlesly recurses

Comment: Well, the overflow does happen outside of my code, but the real reason I posted this is because of the unexpected side effect in the console :-)

Comment: I think the white bits must be to either to do with .Net 4.5 or how your environment is set up, because using .Net 4 (even when run through cmd) I only get spaces, no white blocks. My guess is that either the Win7 Enterprise version of cmd or the .Net 4.5 console emulator treat a certain character combination as 'change the console colour background'.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with .NET 4.5 on Win7 x64 Professional with Aero turned on

Comment: Can't reproduce, either. .NET 4.5, Windows 8.1 Pro.

Answer (score 13):

### bash

```
_(){ _;};_
```

While many might recognize that the recursion is *obvious*, but it seems pretty.  No?

Upon execution, you are guaranteed to see:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: this one is prettier and worse: `_(){_|_;};_`

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Forkbomb alert! (Also, doesn't it need a space after the `{` to be syntactically correct?)

Comment: Yes! and yes! Forkbomb are beautiful :)  Sorry about the space

Comment: Try this as well `:(){:|:;}:`

Comment: Just a small note. On zsh for example the space is not required.

Comment: Looks like a creepy, mutant emoticon.

Comment: Bash emoticons: eater of faces, killer of stacks.

Answer (score 12):

### Haskell

(sad but true until at least `ghc-7.6`, though with `O1` or more it'll optimise the problem away)

```
main = print $ sum [1 .. 100000000]
```

Comment: shouldn't it do a tail call optimization automatically (in sum)?

Comment: @blabla999: tail-calls aren't that relevant in Haskell, it's mostly thunk buildup due to covert lazyness that's causing such problems. In this case, the issue is that `sum` is implemented in terms of `foldl`, which does use tail calls, but because it doesn't evaluate the accumulator strictly merely produces a pile of thunks as large as the original list. The problem disappears when switching to `foldl' (+)`, that evaluates strictly and thus returns a WHN in its tail call. Or, as I said, if you switch on GHC's optimisations!

Comment: aah - interesting, so if no one would wait for the thunk (i.e. leaving out the print), the garbage collector would collect them away (from front to back)?

Comment: @blabla999: well, leaving out the `print` would simply mean `foldl` never even starts to do anything: there would be just a single thunk representing the entire `sum (_)` expression, and that would then be GC'ed in one go. But, yeah, the GC _can_ in more interesting cases collect thunks as-you-go, that's where lazyness becomes really interesting (e.g. allowing you to process infinite lists).

Comment: BTW, none of this is really specified by the Haskell standard: it's merely required that evaluation is _non-strict_, i.e. a nonterminating computation won't block _forever_ if the result is not fully required. How long it really blocks is up to the implementation, in standard lazy GHC it doesn't block at all until you request the result.

Comment: haskell is cool.

Answer (score 12):

## Smalltalk

This creates a new method on the fly, which
  creates a new method on the fly, which
    creates a new method on the fly, which
      ...
    ...
  ..
and then transfers to it.

An extra little spice comes from stressing stack memory AND heap memory at the same time, by creating both a longer and longer method name, and a huge number as receiver, as we fall down the hole... (but the recursion hits us first).

compile in Integer:

```smalltalk
downTheRabbitHole
    |name deeperName nextLevel|

    nextLevel := self * 2.
    name := thisContext selector.
    deeperName := (name , '_') asSymbol.
    Class withoutUpdatingChangesDo:[
        nextLevel class 
            compile:deeperName , (thisContext method source copyFrom:name size+1).
    ].
    Transcript show:self; showCR:' - and down the rabbit hole...'.
    "/ self halt. "/ enable for debugging
    nextLevel perform:deeperName.
```

then jump, by evaluating `"2 downTheRabbitHole"`...

...after a while, you'll end up in a debugger, showing a RecursionException.

Then you have to cleanup all the mess (both SmallInteger and LargeInteger now have a lot of wonderland code):

```smalltalk
{SmallInteger . LargeInteger } do:[:eachInfectedClass |
    (eachInfectedClass methodDictionary keys 
        select:[:nm| nm startsWith:'downTheRabbitHole_'])
            do:[:each| eachInfectedClass removeSelector:each]
```

or else spend some time in the browser, removing alice's wonderland.

Here is some from the head of the trace:

```
2 - and down the rabbit hole...
4 - and down the rabbit hole...
8 - and down the rabbit hole...
16 - and down the rabbit hole...
[...]
576460752303423488 - and down the rabbit hole...
1152921504606846976 - and down the rabbit hole...
2305843009213693952 - and down the rabbit hole...
[...]
1267650600228229401496703205376 - and down the rabbit hole...
2535301200456458802993406410752 - and down the rabbit hole...
5070602400912917605986812821504 - and down the rabbit hole...
[...]
162259276829213363391578010288128 - and down the rabbit hole...
324518553658426726783156020576256 - and down the rabbit hole...
[...]
and so on...
```

PS: the "withoutUpdatingChangesFile:" was added to avoid having to cleanup Smalltalk's persistent change-log file afterwards.

PPS: thanks for the challenge: thinking about something new and innovative was fun!

PPPS: I like to note that some Smalltalk dialects/versions copy overflowing stack frames to the heap - so these may run into an out-of-memory situation instead.

Comment: LOL +1 for that black magic in its pure form

Comment: If I find some time, I may "improve" by using an anonymous method of an anonymous class, to make the darkest rabbit hole ever...

Answer (score 12):

### C#

Really big `struct`, no recursion, pure C#, not unsafe code.

```
public struct Wyern
{
    double a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
}
public struct Godzilla
{
    Wyern a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
}
public struct Cyclops
{
    Godzilla a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
}
public struct Titan
{
    Cyclops a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe
        var A=new Titan();
        // 26×26×26×26×8 = 3655808 bytes            
        Console.WriteLine("Size={0}", Marshal.SizeOf(A));
    }
}
```

as a kicker it crashes the debug windows stating that `{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}`

---

And the generic version (thanks for the suggestion NPSF3000)

```
public struct Wyern<T>
    where T: struct
{
    T a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z;        
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe
        var A=new Wyern<Wyern<Wyern<Wyern<int>>>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Needs more Generic code methinks :P

Comment: The it would look like recursion, but it is possible with nested type arguments.

Comment: Didn't see your C# struct answer before I posted mine. I still have a little different approach, so maybe we let them coexist.

Answer (score 11):

## Starting reply using SnakeYAML

```java
class A
{

    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
         new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().dump(new java.awt.Point());
    }
}
```

Edit: ungolfed it

Its up to the reader to find out how that works :P
(tip: stackoverflow.com)

By the way: the recursion is dynamically made by SnakeYAML (you will notice if you know how it detects the fields it serializes and look then in `Point`'s sourcecode)

Edit: telling how that one works:

SnakeYAML looks for a pair of `getXXX` and `setXXX` mthod with same name for `XXX` and return type of the getter is same as parameter of setter; and surprisingly the `Point` class has a `Point getLocation()` and `void setLocation(Point P)` which returns itself; SnakeYAML doesn't notice it and recurses on that quirk and StackOverflows. Discovered that one when working with them inside a `HashMap` and asking on stackoverflow.com on it.

Answer (score 11):

### C#

Faulty implementation of overriden `==` operator:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2)
    {
        if (obj1 == null)
        {
            return obj2 == null;
        }
        else
        {
            return obj1.Equals(obj2);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass obj1, MyClass obj2)
    {
        return !(obj1 == obj2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        MyClass other = obj as MyClass;
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return A == other.A;
        }
    }
}
```

One might say it's obvious that `operator==` calls itself by using the `==` operator, but you usually do not think that way about `==`, so it's easy to fall into that trap.

Answer (score 10):

### C#

wrongly implemented property getter

```
class C
{
   public int P { get { return P; } }
}

static void Main()
{
   int p = new C().P;
}
```

Comment: how does the black magic work?

Comment: The property getter will be compiled in a method (`get_P`), so essentially it is calling the method `get_P` recursively.

Comment: IMHO. This is a classic example for an obvious recursion... (and so not valid)

Comment: Well, it's only obvious once you've done it once and figured out that C# getters don't work the way you may have thought they did. After all, this code is a member variable declaration, so why shouldn't it create an actual member variable?

Comment: This is no more than a convoluted way of doing `static void Main() { Main(); }`

Comment: @Jodrell You wouldn't write recursive `Main()` accidentally. But it's quite simple to write a recursive property accidentally and then be confused by the stack overflow.

Comment: This would be useful for someone picking up C#.

Comment: I have seen so many questions on Stackoverflow about this situation, examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367192/new-to-c-why-does-property-set-throw-stackoverflow-exception), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798697/system-stackoverflowexception-when-get-set-properties-are-used) and lots of others(search on google: stackoverflow exception on setting property in C# site:stackoverflow.com), it may  not be that weird but it is very common and can be really confusing for new developer

Comment: That moment when I did this while I was re-learning C# (learned it in undergraduate, was too much of a Java programmer by graduate school).

Answer (score 7):

## Java

```java
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HiddenStackOverflow extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animate Circle around Mouse Pointer");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new HiddenStackOverflow());
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }
    int x, y;

    public HiddenStackOverflow() {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        x = y = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        mouseMoved(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        x = me.getX();
        y = me.getY();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

This is a mistake that I actually made. Do not get `paint` and `paintComponent` mixed up.

If the `super.paint(g)` in method `paintComponent` were correctly written as `super.paintComponent(g)`, this program will continuously draw a black circle around the mouse pointer.

---

In response to some comments claiming this is obvious recursion, this is why I consider this not obvious:

- I occasionally make this mistake (made it often when I first started coding Swing).
- Rely's on "hidden code" (hidden in Swing and AWT) to create the recursion.
- calls the superclass method, not the "this" class.

Comment: Isn't that an obvious recursion though, if my memory of how AWT works is not altered?

Comment: @ArlaudPierre Not AWT, Swing. You might call it obvious, but I have mistyped that way many times. It is really easy to do so. I would not call it that obvious; for one, it calls the superclass's method, not the class's itself.

Comment: and its relying on the java awt behavior :P
(sometimes APIS have pretty odd behavior; see my YAML one)

Comment: @masterX244 why is everyone calling Swing AWT! They are very different. Swing comes in a completely different project (`javax`, not `java`). Sure, Swing does rely on AWT, but it is quite different in what it can do.

Comment: @Quincunx `paint(java.awt.Graphics)` is in AWT, while `paintComponent` is in swing. By polymorphism, my calling this the work of AWT is true considering Swings JComponent extend AWT Component. I don't know why we're even argueing about this. Anyway, the point is this answer is invalid according to the rules.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre It is not invalid. This is not an obvious recursion. Yes I know Swing is an extension on AWT and I know about all those things that you mentioned. I was just surprised to see that this code is being called AWT when I was coding in Swing. Sorry for seeming argumentative.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre same as Quincunx It isnt that oobvious cause you need to know how the backstage logic of Swing is and if not you may headscratch...

Comment: @masterX244 But it's basically like your second example, except the methodA is "hidden" and you're not the one to have programmed it.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre due to it being hidden outside of your code it isnt obvious anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, ununvoted (is that a word?) :)

Comment: @ArlaudPierre What you are looking for is un-downvoted. :-)

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript - not a single expression

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}`}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

[**Here is why it works**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17306367/1348195)

Comment: Editing it causes my browser to slow down absurdly - so for people not wanting to follow the link - this causes a stack overflow in the JS _parser_ in all modern browsers since they are written in recursive descent.

Comment: The Firefox console returns: `InternalError: too much recursion`

Answer (score 5):

### Java

They always tell you not to reinvent the wheel, so I used collections from `java.util`.

```java
Set<Object> s = new HashSet<>();
s.add(s);
s.add(s);
```

And here's a simple list implementation extending the built-in `java.util.AbstractList`:

```java
public class MyList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private Object[] contents;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList<String> list = new MyList<>( "Roses", "are", "red" );
        System.out.println( list );
    }

    public MyList( E... fill ){
        contents = new Object[fill.length];
        for( int i=0; i<fill.length; i++ )
            contents[i] = fill[i];
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int i) {
        return (E)contents[i];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int i = 0;
        for( E e : this ) ++i;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice way :) funnily how java fails on hashcoding on a hashset with the set added ti itself 2x...

Answer (score 5):

### C#

Value types are created on the stack and stacks are usually 1 MB in size, so a simple struct will do...

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace N
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct A
    {
        [FieldOffset(0xFFFFC)]
        public int a;
    }

    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
             A a= new A();
             Console.WriteLine(a.a);
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's even better if it comes a bit more subtle:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Debug=System.Console;
namespace N
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct Console
    {
        [FieldOffset(0xFFFFC)] public int WriteLine;
    }

    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var console= new Console();
            Debug.WriteLine(console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using an `[FieldOffset]` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

### C + GCC inline assembly

Same idea as [Michael Ehrenreich's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21119/3544).

```
int f() {
        printf("Hello, world\n");
        asm(".section return");
}
asm(".previous");

int main() {
        f();
        return 0;
}
```

The return from `f` is moved to another section, and not executed.

Answer (score 4):

## C, POSIX

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
foo(int sig)
{
        *(int *)sig = sig;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct sigaction sa;

        sa.sa_handler = foo;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER;
        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
        foo(42);

        return 0;
}
```

Should work on all POSIX systems. Only tested on MacOS and Linux. The final crash is because of a stack overflow even though there isn't really a way for the system to tell you it was one. Throw the core dump into a debugger if you don't believe that.

Answer (score 4):

## Android / XML drawable

Save as `drawable/ololo.xml` and open in IntelliJ IDEA editor. It will display `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ololo"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Java

Picked up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1808841/2235132), it causes an `StackOverflowError` in the compiler:

```
class T { }
class N<Z> { }
class C<X> extends N<N<? super C<C<X>>>> {
  N<? super C<T>> cast(C<T> c) { return c; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome in the club :) second one to stackoverflow javac :)
i got it to stakoverflow by spamming it with variables; using the way to compile code you ahve as string inside another program to generate the millions of variables needed to get javac to reject

Comment: See this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/FOOL2007.pdf

Answer (score 4):

## EcmaScript 6 (only 19 bytes!):

```
atob(...Array(9e5))
```

It uses absolutely **no** recursion, and it's a fully-valid program!

Answer (score 4):

## Python

This is one I've seen in practice, by accident:

```py
class test(object):
    mainvalue=1
    def __getattribute__(self,attrname):
        return self.mainvalue


print test().blah
```

The catch is that, if you define `__getattr__` instead of `__getattribute__`, it works exactly as expected (it prints 1)

Answer (score 4):

**C#**

```
var x = "Joel Spolsky";
var y = "Jeff Atwood";

var stackOverflow = x + y;
```

(Actual program output may vary)

Comment: how does it work?

Comment: @masterX244: StackOverflow.com is created by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood.

Comment: ahhh :) nifty way to reinterpret the question :P +1 for thinking outside the box

Answer (score 4):

## C (via ATL)

```
#include <AtlBase.h>
int main() {
     for(;;) 
         printf("%s\n", W2CA("STACKOVERFLOW"));
     return 0;
}
```

Even for people who do code C, this looks like it simply loops forever printing "STACKOVERFLOW" to the screen. Turns out the W2CA is a macro that behind-the-scenes allocates stack memory which isn't released until the function returns. If you use it in a loop, a stack-overflow is a common (usually highly unexpected) result. Microsoft eventually deprecated this macro for this problem. This is effectively the same as Ruslan's answer, except less obvious what's going on.

Comment: What exactly does this do (for us who don't code in C)?

Comment: Even for people who do code C, this looks like it simply loops forever printing "STACKOVERFLOW" to the screen.  Turns out the W2CA is a macro that behind-the-scenes allocates stack memory which isn't released until the function returns.  If you use it in a loop, a stack-overflow is a common (usually highly unexpected) result.  Microsoft eventually deprecated this macro for this problem.  This is effectively the same as Ruslan's answer, except less obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

## dc

With [dc(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dc&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html) in OpenBSD 5.5, adding a *comment* or *whitespace* to a program may overflow the stack.

Both of these programs have obvious recursion. They are infinite loops, and all loops in dc are tail-recursive. The **surprise** is that the first program *never* overflows:

```
[lwx]dswx
```

The second program *does* overflow:

```
[
 lw x   # loop forever
] d sw x
```

The *only* difference is that the second program has extra comments and whitespace. OpenBSD dc optimizes tail recursion only when the tail call, such as `x`, is immediately before the end bracket `]`. So, the first program loops forever. In the second program, dc wants to return and run the commands between the `x` and the `]`, so dc overflows the call stack.

```
dc: recursion too deep: Cannot allocate memory
```

To prevent overflow, I must play *code golf* and delete all comments and whitespace between the `x` and the `]`.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch

```
@call me Al
    ~ Paul Simon
```

Save to a file called `me.bat`. Or add the label `:me` at the start of this batch file and change `@call me Al` to `@call :me Al`.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch

```
call _
```

Save it to a file `_.bat` and execute it!

The code, *per se*, doesn't make the recursion obvious.  Upon executing, you'd see:

```
....
....
******  B A T C H   R E C U R S I O N  exceeds STACK limits ******
Recursion Count=1240, Stack Usage=90 percent
******       B A T C H   PROCESSING IS   A B O R T E D      ******
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21114/weirdest-way-to-produce-a-stack-overflow/21127#21127). But I feel like there must be a more clever way to produce this error with Batch.

Comment: It's funny how stupid the error message looks, like a 90's computer movie error with big letters and spaces and stars.

Answer (score 3):

### Python

`fork`ing isn't recursion, right?

```
import os
while 1: os.fork()
```

Comment: the fork bong according to python :)

Comment: [fork bong](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fork+bong)?

Comment: A fork *bomb* perhaps??

Comment: these days, you have to be careful with such words (bb is listening) [sorry, couldn't resist commenting)

Answer (score 3):

## bash

```
#!/bin/bash

touch $'\x3b'
bash -c "echo $(ls ./*)"
```

#### Usage

Save as `ls` (any other filename works as well), make executable and call as `./ls`.

#### What it does

- `touch $'\x3b'` creates a file called `;`.
- `$(ls ./*)` gets replaced by contents of the current directory.

  Example:

  ```
  ./; ./ls
  ```
- `bash -c "echo ./; ./ls"` executes the following in a subshell:

  ```
  echo ./
  ./ls
  ```

Answer (score 3):

### Common Lisp (GNU CLISP)

```
[1]> (lambda () (funcall *))
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (FUNCALL *)>
[2]> (funcall *)

*** - Program stack overflow. RESET
```

#### Explanation (see if you can figure it out first):

> The value of the variable variable [`*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v__stst_.htm) is the result of the last form evaluated at the prompt.  Thus, `(funcall *)` says "call the last REPL result," and that happens to be `(lambda () (funcall *))` which is a function that calls the last REPL result, which *at that point* is itself.

There are lots of variations on this theme:

```
[7]> (setf (symbol-function '*) (lambda () (funcall *)))
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (FUNCALL *)>
[8]> (*)

*** - Program stack overflow. RESET
```

A particularly devious one would be a function that "works" (does something that's not a stack overflow) at first, and then *later* overflows the stack.  E.g., using `**` (which is the second to last REPL result):

```
[14]> (defun hello-world () (print 'hello-world))
HELLO-WORLD
[15]> (defun uh-oh () (funcall **))
UH-OH
[16]> (uh-oh)

HELLO-WORLD 
HELLO-WORLD
[17]> (uh-oh)

*** - Program stack overflow. RESET
```

Answer (score 3):

C#, no recursion. Requires unsafe code. Attempt to allocate an array that wont fit on the stack.

```
class Program {
    static unsafe void Main() {
        var b = stackalloc byte[0x100000];
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it D:

Answer (score 3):

### J

As J is generally a weird language, probably one of the shortest:

```
    $:''
| stack error
|       $: ''
```

An even weirder one, using every printable, non-white-space ASCII character exactly once:

```
!"#%&()*+,-/:;<=>?@ACDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~&$:0123456789 NB.'
|stack error
|   !"#%&()*+,-/:;<=>?@ACDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{    |}~&$:123456789
```

Answer (score 3):

### Lua

Using metatables frequently results in stack overflows :

```
a=setmetatable({},{__index=function(t,k)return t[k]end})
print(a[1]) -- index this table.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby

```
evil = "eval evil"
eval evil
```

This will cause `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

```
1.9.3p448 :006 >   
1.9.3p448 :007 >   evil = " eval evil"
 => " eval evil" 
1.9.3p448 :008 >   eval evil
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!
1.9.3p448 :009 >
```

Comment: This recursion is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

### C

A simple recursion. But where's the recursive call?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void f(int errno) {
        if (errno==EINVAL) puts("EINVAL");
}

int *main() {
        f(main);
        return 0;
}
```

Solution:

> `errno.h` defines: `#define errno *(__errno_location())`
>  When this is expanded in the parameter list, `f` is defined to get a function pointer parameter, named `__errno_location`.
>  When this is expanded in the body, this function is called.
>  Calling `f` with `main` as a parameter leads to endless recursion.

**EDIT**: The previous version crashed, but not because of a stack overflow. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Java

More API vodoo. This time, the stack trace doesn't hint where the overflow line is actually.

```java
class SO extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[]a)
    {
        new SO().setVisible(true);

    }
    public SO()
    {
        setSize(100,100);
        DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
        JList l = new JList(m);
        m.addElement(m);
        add(l);
    }
}
```

That derp happened to me once while programming some GUI stuff and I didn't knew where it was from

Comment: This is unobvious recursion? Okay.... I thought that adding a list to itself is obvious, but apparently it is not.

Comment: run it and see what the trace tells you as source of overflow

Comment: Lol; recursive stack trace!

Comment: However, I couldn't help but notice that it tells you that the error is from `DefaultListModel`. Also, I use two main steps for debugging: 1. read stack trace to see if there is a hint. 2. either apply the hint or, if there is none, debug by examining code.

Comment: but not the line where you add the model :P so if you have some more code between the setVisible it can confuzzle

Comment: Of course not. Most of those calls are from the `DefaultListModel`. My hypothesis is that the stack trace has a smaller stack than the call stack, so it automatically removes elements to keep its size within the correct amount.

Comment: btw, you can add java syntax coloring by adding this before the code block: `<!-- language: lang-java -->`

Answer (score 2):

## C#

Using fixed arrays and loading `struct` into the stack for an operation.

```cs
public unsafe struct Godzilla
{
    public const int Size = 40900;
    fixed double data[Size];
    public Godzilla(double init)
    {
        fixed(double* ptr=data)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
            {
                ptr[i]= init;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(Godzilla other)
    {
        fixed(double* ptr=data)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
            {
                ptr[i]+=other.data[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Godzilla A=new Godzilla(1.0);
        Godzilla B=new Godzilla(2.0);
        A.Add(B);
    }
}
```

It tries to load all the values on the stack and fails. Each struct is 8×40900 = 327,200 bytes long and when two of them get loaded into the stack it pukes.

[image: SO]

Answer (score 2):

## Java and no!!! recursion anywhere :P

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.SimpleJavaFileObject;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
public class E
{
    public static void main(String[]a)  //run with -Xmx=4G on a 64bit-OS with enough ram...
    {
        //Method m = new E().getClass().getMethod(null, parameterTypes);
        StringBuffer params = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer paramdef = new StringBuffer();
        int i=0;
        for (i=0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
             params.append(i+",\n");   
             paramdef.append("int param"+i+",\n");
        }
        params.append(i);
        paramdef.append("int param"+i);
        String classheader= "class E2{public static void lickme("+paramdef.toString()+"){} static{lickme("+params.toString()+");}}";
        //dump the string to a file to see what happens internally :P
        EU c2 = new EU("stackoverflow.com", classheader);
        JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        c.getTask(null, null, null, null, null,Arrays.asList(new EU[]{c2})).call();
    }
    public static void nop(int... Overflower)
    {
        
    }
    public static class EU extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
           final String code;
           EU(String name, String code) {
               super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension),
                     Kind.SOURCE);
               this.code = code;
           }

           @Override
           public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
               return code;
           }
       }
}
```

If you wonder what happens dump the string before it get compiled;
java-eval ftw :P

If you swap that line `for (i=0; i < 1000000; i++)` to `for (i=0; i < 100 00000; i++)`
it stackoverflows even with `-Xmx10G -Xss100M` as JVM parameters and peaks at just over 9GB RAM usage.

Trick used is sme weird handling f too many Method parameters inside the Compiler

Comment: Oh I like this one!

Comment: @Jason C: if you dump that source file generated and run it through javac manually it still stackoverflows :P

Answer (score 2):

**C# .NET** mishandling unhanded exceptions:

The idea can happen in many places, such as in ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF, well everywhere where you try to handle an unhanded exception and raise another error as a result. To me, this happened in a project where the error log was written in the database, but the database connection would fail, which in turn would raise another error.

Here is a simple windows forms application to illustrate the idea:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Application.ThreadException += (sender, args) => WriteError("Unhandled Exception");
        }

        private void WriteError(string msg)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't write!");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Overflow it!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how some of these answers are *obvious* it was discovered once as a bug. +1 Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

## TeX

```
\def~{\if~}~
```

At least the original TeX code crashes with a stack overflow here.  Several (mostly newer) implementations take measures to avoid it, though, and bomb out with a nicer error message than "Segmentation Fault".

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved using a regex pattern like this in Java. Note that the required data length to reproduce this error may change depending on your architecture.

Replacing the pattern with a better `^([a-fA-F]|\\d)++$` successfully executes the code.

## Java

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class aRegexStackOverflow {
    public static void main(String [] whatIsThis) {
        try {
            String boom = "";
            for (int i=0; i<1292; i++)
                boom+=Integer.toHexString(0);
            System.out.println("Length: " + boom.length());
            if (Pattern.matches("^([a-fA-F]|\\d)+$", boom.trim()))
                System.out.println("This is working!");
            boom+=Integer.toHexString(0);
            System.out.println("Length: " + boom.length());
            if (Pattern.matches("^([a-fA-F]|\\d)+$", boom.trim()))
                System.out.println("This will never be printed...");
        }
        catch(StackOverflowError soe) {
            soe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
Length: 1292
This is working!
Length: 1293
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3692)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4502)
at ... //Goes on for a while tbh
```

---

**Explanation as stated in the comments by nhahtdh (thank you!)**

*Oracle's implementation of Pattern class uses recursion for matching greedy/lazy repetition of a non-trivial pattern. This explains the behavior. Some other JVM which reimplements the Pattern class (such as GNU classpath) and use data structure to simulate the recursion will not have this behavior.*

---

**Inspiration:** [Oracle Bug Database (even if this is not an actual bug)](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5050507)

Comment: I was going to post something similar. Oracle's implementation of Pattern class uses recursion for matching greedy/lazy repetition of a non-trivial pattern. This explains the behavior. Some other JVM which reimplements the Pattern class (such as GNU classpath) and use data structure to simulate the recursion will not have this behavior.

Comment: @nhahtdh Brilliant! I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

### Java:

The idea is to fill the stack with one huge stack frame, containning multiple local variables, rather then with multiple stack frames:

```
public class LocalVarOverFlow {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long
                l1 = 0, l2 = 0, l3 = 0, l4 = 0, l5 = 0,
                l6 = 0, l7 = 0, l8 = 0, l9 = 0, l10 = 0,
                l11 = 0, l12 = 0, l13 = 0, l14 = 0, l15 = 0,
                l16 = 0, l17 = 0, l18 = 0, l19 = 0, l20 = 0,

                ... ;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah thats what generated code helps :P; see my examples on code that generates the overflow code :P and as it is generated it is postable complete :P and if done far enough it may even stackoverflow the compiler :P)

Answer (score 2):

## Java (Regex Compile)

The other Java regex answer (+1'd) SOEs on matching.  Here's one that SOEs on compiling:

```
public class PatternSOE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rep = new String(new char[9999]);
        Pattern.compile(rep.replace("\0", "(") + "a" + rep.replace("\0", ")"));
    }
}
```

Basically builds and attempts to compile up a huge regex in the form:

```
 "((( ... (a) ... )))"
```

The regex parser recurses on each sub-group.

Comment: +1 for something new. But I really doubt anyone would run into this in actual usage.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳  With the amount of reflection addicts around, I wouldn't be surprised if there are people who do run into this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

### Java

Recursive reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] _) throws Exception {
        Method m = Method.class.getMethod("invoke", Object.class, Object[].class);
        Object[] args = { m, null };
        args[1] = args;
        m.invoke(m, args);
    }
}
```

I'd like to think that this code doesn't obviously cause a stack overflow, and I'd hope the 1.8MiB of stacktrace it generates counts as 'clearly visible'.

Idea shamelessly lifted from http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4185411.

Answer (score 2):

**C Buffer Overflow**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   char buff[20];
   sprintf(buff, "Value of Pi = %f", M_PI);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `<string.h>` isn't used, so you may want to remove it. Also, while being syntactically valid, why did you put the bracket around the `0` in the `return` statement?

Comment: Good Point @ace i have removed `<string.h>` .Was trying to get buf overflow using string functions.Finally found this to be more simple.Brackets are habit :)

Answer (score 2):

**PHP**

```
<?php
header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
```

Navigating to this page produces this result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Apache mod_rewrite done wrong**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

The rule, which is supposed to map URLs such as `/about-us` to `/about-us.php`, ends up producing this error in Apache logs (the `L` flag does not help):

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a real stack overflow but effects are pretty much the same.

```
int main()
{
    asm("movl $0, %esp");
}
```

C++ (since there is no return from main) and i386-like cpus.

ESP is the stack pointer in i386 processor, by doing that, we're pointing the stack out of the memory reserved for it, something similar happens when recursion is involved - just without actually writing to it.

Notice that SIGSEGV is generated not when ESP is changed but when the the program uses the stack, so if we modify the code like this

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "hello";
}

int main()
{
    asm("movl $0, %esp");
    foo();
}
```

we will get the crash at:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
main () at stack.cpp:11
11        foo();
```

The interesting thing about SO is that you cannot catch SIGSEGV signal by using signal() function since there no stack to call it, but you can provide alternate stack (eg heap allocated) to the sigaction function.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell

A joke I thought of a couple of years back:

```haskell
import Control.Monad.Fix

main = print(fix error)
```

gives

```
"*** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: *** Exception: ... etc.
```

I'm not getting a stack overflow error, but maybe that is because the Glasgow Haskell Compiler uses lazy evaluation.

The function `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` gives the first fix point of the function error - `fix` applies a function to itself. In that sense it is plain and simple recursion. The function `error :: [Char] -> a` requires a string argument and returns something of any type. That is why it can serve as the argument to another error function.

Answer (score 2):

## Python and the Y combinator

before someone else does it:

```
(lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda : y(y)())))(lambda f: f)()
```

Please, if you don't know much about lambda calculus, don't downvote this solution because you believe that the recursive call is obvious; it isn't obvious at all. More precisely, `lambda x: x(x)` or `lambda : y(y)` or `lambda f: f` ARE NOT recursive calls but mere functions applying to functions.

Comment: In Ruby, `ruby -e '->(f){->(x){x[x]}[->(y){f[->{y[y][]}]}]}[->(f){f}][]'`

Answer (score 2):

## C with GCC extensions

```
int main() {
  goto *(void*)main;
  return 0;
}
```

This will compile without errors and without using any compiler flags when using GCC. GCC allows "computed gotos", where you can jump directly to a pointer. It doesn't look like the goto would cause a stack overflow, but GCC puts a preamble in the main() function that pushes one register to the stack, as can be seen in the produced assembler:

```
main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
  movl  $main, %eax
  jmp   *%rax
```

Answer (score 1):

### AppleSoft BASIC

```
0 GOSUB 0
```

Not so weird but worth mentioning...

Comment: This looks like a direct recursion.

Comment: A agree, very obvious recursion. Don't meet objective nr. 2 of the OP.

Comment: The only way to blow the stack in old BASIC is GOSUB or FOR without next.

Answer (score 1):

## Java again :) Serializing FTW :P

```java
public class C {
    public static class Ci implements Serializable {
        public Object o;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List l = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new OutputStream(){
            public void write(int b) {/*DEVNULL*/}
        });

        Ci c = new Ci();
        Ci c2 = null;
        int i = 0;
        for (;;) {
            i++;
            if (i % 100000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Serializing...");
                o.writeObject(c);
                o = new ObjectOutputStream(new OutputStream(){
                    public void write(int b) {/*DEVNULL*/}
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            if (false) 
                break;

            c2 = c;
            c = new Ci();
            c.o = c2;
        }
    }
}
```

Googling a bit around should tell how this one works :P

The modulo operator is to reduce workload and speed the thing up.

Answer (score 1):

## Go

I challenge anybody to see the bug, who doesn't already know where it is. I added a few (truthful) comments to explain the code to non-Goers.

Try to find it yourself, if you're so inclined, before reading the comment section below (where somebody will surely spoil it.)

Here is a link to the playground: http://play.golang.org/p/UwunxiXKP7

```go
package main

import "fmt"

// Aim: to define an integer type that by default is printed in hex notation (0xab..)
type hexInt int

// Implementation of the Stringer interface, used by Println for conversion to string.
func (h hexInt) String() string {
    // "%#x" is the alternate form of "%x", which uses lowercase a-f and adds 0x in front.
    return fmt.Sprintf("%#x", h)
}

func main() {
    // Create a variable of type hexInt with the value 42 and print it.
    var h hexInt = 42
    fmt.Println(h)
}
```

Comment: print feedback loop?

Comment: "print feedback"? no, not quite.

Comment: meant that it gets stuck in the stringification process :P

Comment: well, it kind of does ;)

Comment: Clever. You can add a link to go playground so that people can test it: http://play.golang.org/p/UwunxiXKP7

Answer (score 1):

### Python:

Using anonymous recursion.  I'm not sure if this is too straight-forward or not, but there are no declared functions, so it seems potentially interesting.

```
(lambda f:f(f))(lambda f:f(f))
```

Comment: A lambda calling itself seems to violate part of the rules though (i.e. "Not allowed to use an obvious recursion.")

Answer (score 1):

## C#

```cs
  public static int i
  {
      set { i = value; }
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      i = 0;
  }
```

Comment: obvious recursion. Same as `int i() { return i(); }`

Answer (score 1):

**Common problem in a Rails model**

```ruby
after_save :bump_version

# a lot of code....

private

def bump_version
  create_new_version_record
  update_attribute(:version, version+1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Flash AS3

```
public class Work extends Sprite
{
    public function Work()
    {
        doIt();
    }

    private function doIt():void
    {
        noYouDoIt();
    }

    private function noYouDoIt():void
    {
        arguments.callee();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Netware:

```
echo hello > file
cat file >> file
```

I discovered this (but did not use it) many decades ago. I mentioned it to someone, who did it on a Netware share. The share had no limits, and was also used for scratch space by the netware server itself.

The server filled with this one file end-to-end-to-end, crashed (due to running out of diskspace), and couldn't be brought back up until the file was removed. The file, of course, couldn't be removed until the server was running.

Comment: what happened to your friend and how was the issue bypassed then?

Comment: It happened at a polytech. They admins called me on the carpet, and I said I discovered the flaw, and (truthfully) that I didn't do it, and that I didn't know who did (also truthfully - we were in a class, many people overheard it; I don't think my friend did it). It took the admins several hours to fix the problems. I was not asked to help, of course.

Comment: @masterX244: obvious bypass is to boot from another media, then access this disk and delete the file.

Comment: Netware used their own proprietary filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript

Tested in Chrome:

```
var a = Array(10000000);
(function(){}).apply(this, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

```
public abstract class A
{
  public int X {get { return -1; }}      
  public virtual string Value(){ return "A"; }
}

public class B : A
{
  public new int X {get{ return 42; }}
  public override string Value() { return "B"; }
}

public class C : B
{
  // no recursion; returns -1      
  public int XFromA {get { return ((A)this).X; }}

  // no recursion; returns 42  
  public int XFromB {get { return ((B)this).X; }}

  // no recursion; returns "B"
  public override string Value() { return base.Value(); }

  // StackOverflowException
  public override string Value() { return ((A)this).Value(); }
}
```

Comment: Technically it's still quite obvious because it is technically calling itself, just with an added bit of anonymity.

Comment: Just for clarification, the extra level of inheritance is the point of this example. Any class can "cast" itself to its base parent by using the `base` keyword. But what if it needs to cast itself to its grandparent? Its also possible to use the `this` keyword in a cast to an interface. So, perhaps I am not a sharp as others reading this, but the syntax seemed quite natural to me, and I had to write several experimental tests to pinpoint the source of the Stackoverflow that caught me by surprise. If it was that obvious, I would have expected the compiler to have caught it.

Comment: I've also added additional code to show that casting the `this` keyword to a parent or grandparent is not in and of itself the cause of the recursion...when I originally used this code, it was this fact that caused me to think: "that's wierd..."

Answer (score 1):

**C**

```
void main()
{
    while(1)
        *(char*)alloca(1000)=0;
}
```

Funnily, without `=0` it will rotate indefinitely because it'll just subtract stack pointer without causing any stack accesses.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

```
import Control.DeepSeq
makeFunc n = \input -> (newfunc input) `deepseq`
    unlines [ "Function number "++(show n)++"was called with "++input
            , "Now calling the next function."
            , newfunc input]
            where
                newfunc=makeFunc (n+1)

main=putStrLn ((  makeFunc (0::Double)  ) "Input")
```

In this, each function creates a new one, and calls it. Note that this is no recursion, in that no function call itself.

Comment: what language?;

Comment: Sorry, I changed it, and accidentially deleted the header.

Comment: derps happen sometimes, no issue; thats why i just asked and didnt said something not so friendly

Answer (score 1):

### excel vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
[a1] = 1
End Sub
```

place code into any worksheet

stack will overflow (in vba, displayed as an out of memory error) as each change to the worksheet triggers another change.

Answer (score 1):

Well just since I'm bored.

```
int main()
{
   char *ptr;
   ptr = &ptr - sizeof(ptr);
   while(1)
      *--ptr = 0;
}
```

Invokes undefined behavior that trips the guard page the same way a stack overflow does.

Answer (score 1):

## Vim

```
:se maxf<tab>=0<CR>
:help<CR>
```

Produces `E132: Function call depth is higher than 'maxfuncdepth'`, vim's equivalent of a stack overflow.  (Several times, actually)

Comment: This works by reducing VimL's stack size and then invoking a simple command.  It'd also be possible to achieve similar errors using any standard recursion approach.

Answer (score 1):

ANS Forth:

```
0 >in 2dup ! !
```

which leads to:

```
$ gforth
Gforth 0.7.0, Copyright (C) 1995-2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Gforth comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `license'
Type `bye' to exit
0 >in 2dup ! !                                          
:1: Stack overflow
0 >in 2dup >>>!<<< !
Backtrace:
$B71DF6EC r> 
$B71D34A4 perform 
$B71DD654 (search-wordlist) 
$3 
$0 
$B71DD734 (vocfind) 
$B71D34A4 perform 
$B71D351C (search-wordlist) 
$B71D3FF4 find-name
```

In fact, the 2nd `!` is never executed.

`>in` is an integer variable that contains the current position within the input line, the program attempts to write zero to `>in` two times, but after the first write (`!`) the input pointer is reset to the start of input line, and the 2nd pair of values is left on the stack...

Comment: whats the black magic? cant get behind it somehow

Comment: the 1st `!` (store) sets the input pointer `>in` to the beginning of the line. After executing `!`, the interpreter begins to interpret the line from the very beginning. So anything ending with `0 >in !` is an endless loop. To get a stack overflow, we need to leave something on the stack. I did `2dup`, it leaves an extra copy of 0 and the address of `>in`. And the 2nd `!` is never executed because `>in` gets reset before the interpreter can reach it.

Comment: Note that after declaring `variable x` the code `2 x 2dup ! !` (in C it would be `x = x = 2;`) is absolutely valid, although stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Another one!

**Ruby**

```ruby
class Foo
  def method_missing *args, &block
    foo
  end
end

Foo.new.stack_overflow!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!
```

Comment: nice one :) especially when the error is spitted in IRB :)

Answer (score 1):

## C#

This will stack overflow the CLR I think, and report that type could not be loaded.

```
public struct Titan 
{
    public Pluto Data { get; set; }
}

public struct Pluto 
{
    public Titan Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
        //Message="Could not load type 'ConsoleApplication1.Titan' from assembly 'ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."
        //Source="ConsoleApplication1"
        //TypeName="ConsoleApplication1.Titan"
        //StackTrace:
        //     at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
        //     at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
        //     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
        //     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        //     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
        Titan t;
    }
}
```

Comment: The JIT might optimize the statement away if it is not used. That is what I had a `WriteLine()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

### C: "Hello World" format

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    (*printf+285)("Hello World\n");
}
```

This is actually a recursive call that fails when the stack get too big, but it is definitely not an *obvious* one.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP

```
$a = array('call_user_func_array', &$a);
$a[0]($a[0], $a);

Process exited with code 139.
```

Compatible from 4.3 to 5.6

Answer (score 1):

**(C)Python**

```
eval("f("*99+")"*99)
```

Produces:

```
s_push: parser stack overflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    eval("f("*99+")"*99)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

```
>>> class C:
...     def __setattr__(self, k, v):
...             self.k = v
...
>>> C().x = 10
...
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __setattr__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

`__getattribute__` will also do this in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

**Haskell**

I'm surprised nobody posted this already... Maybe it's too obvious?

```
data Foo = Bar

instance Eq Foo where

main = print (Bar == Bar)
```

Naturally, `Bar == Bar` *should* evaluate to `True`. So this program *should* just print "True" and then exit. However, that's not what the empty `instance Eq Foo` declaration does. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Java

StackOverflowError before main is even executed. No recursive functions required, good old initializers. Also one of the shortest Java programs:

```
public class _ { static { new _(); } { new _(); } public static void main(String[] _) {}}
```

Make sure this class isn't referenced anywhere in the codebase or you will get a StackOverflowError on load. Which also makes this really easy to hide anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**JAVA**

"B" overrides "foo()", but invokes "super.foo()". Because the overridden "foo()" in "A" is invoked by an instance of "B", the "this" reference is pointing to "B", not "A". Therefore, when I create another instance of "this", another "B" object is created.

```
public class Main {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
  }

   static class A {       
        void foo() { 
            try {
                this.getClass().newInstance();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    static class B extends A {
        B() { foo(); }

        void foo() { super.foo(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to explain (in your answer) how your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme

```lisp
((lambda (x) (x x)) (lambda (x) (+ 1 (x x))))
```

I claim this is not an obvious *recursion*.

Comment: after some university stuf that one is now obvious as hell for me

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I ran into this stack overflow in C#, which took me a significant amount of time to track and figure out what was going on. Assuming you have a C# application with Aspose PDF installed:

```
Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharSet = "UTF-8";
pdf.BindHTML("<div><img src=\"myImage.jpg\" alt=\"broken!\" /></div>");
pdf.HtmlInfo.ImgUrl = @"C:\users\me\pictures";
pdf.Save(@"c:\output.pdf");
```

If "myImage.jpg" is more than about twice as tall as it is wide, the image will overflow the generated PDF page, and somewhere in obfuscated code this results in a stack overflow.

Comment: bugs outside the own code are the weirdest to locate :P; but nice find

Answer (score 1):

## Java

This code causes `StackOverflowError` on Oracle's JRE/JDK and OpenJDK. Basically, any JVM that uses the reference implementation for the class library.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;

class G21114 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT; i < Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; i++) {
            if (Character.isDefined(i) && Character.getType(i) != Character.SURROGATE) {
                int codePoint[] = {i};
                String s = new String(codePoint, 0, codePoint.length);

                if (!Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).equals(s)) {
                    buf.append(s); buf.append(s); buf.append(s);
                    buf.append('a');
                    buf.append(s); buf.append(s);
                    c++;

                    if (c >= 300) break; // Don't need too many
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(buf.length());

        // try-catch to clearly show what is thrown
        try {
            Pattern.compile(buf.toString(), Pattern.CANON_EQ);
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

This is based on the fact that the reference implementation implements the `Pattern.CANON_EQ` (canonical equivalence) mode by modifying the input string to create alternation between all the possible decompositions. The string is then compiled as per normal.

The construction works well on a single character, but if there are multiple decomposable character in a row, the construction goes amok and doesn't close non-capturing groups `(?:regex)` properly. Look at this [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7080302) for the test case.

However, to cause `StackOverflowError`, the parentheses don't need to be balanced. The combination of letters I chose above happen to produce a series of many opening parentheses, which cause the recursive descent parser in Pattern class to exhaust the stack. The underlying cause is similar to [ɲeuroburɳ's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21114/weirdest-way-to-produce-a-stack-overflow/21450#21450). However, the code above is more discrete in causing the `StackOverflowError` and depends on internal implementation of `Pattern` class.

Answer (score 1):

### Java

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Temp.class.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, new Object[]{null});
    }
}
```

Gives a bunch of weird stack traces and exceptions

- `InvocationTargetException` once with a gazillion times 'caused by `InvocationTargetException`'
- `InvocationTargetException` another gazillion times without stack trace, only `... 1024 more`
- finally ending in `StackOverflowError`

Also posted in [Call a method without calling it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22469/call-a-method-without-calling-it/22526#22526)

Answer (score 1):

Lua:

```lua
setmetatable(_ENV, {__newindex = function(x, y) z = y; end});

test="Hello world!"
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @user2509848 it adds a metatable on the global environment. When `test=...` is executed, the `__newindex` method is called, since there's no `test` in the environment. Then the method does `z=...`, and since `z` isn't in the environment too, the recursion happens. Another thing to note, is that the `__newindex` is executed in a synthesized stack frame (unlike a usual frame which is created upon a regular funicton call), and when those are abused, a `C stack overflow` occurs.

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl

```
interp r {} 1
a
```

Uses the same trick that python uses (recursionlimit).
Calling a will result in a call to `unknown` which executes a lot of other stuff (which will fail)

And here an other one:

```
proc unknown {args} a
a
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rant

```
[?[src]]
```

Allow me to explain.

`[src]` is a function that returns the source code of the current state object. Metapatterns (`[?...]`) generate their own source code, so the return value is different when `[src]` is called inside as opposed to outside. This is where things get rather weird...

When the code is executed, the metapattern generates a source. It calls `[src]`, which returns the metapattern's source code, which is just `[src]`. It jumps back to the original scope with this new code on the stack, and runs it again. This calls `[src]`, which returns `[?[src]]`. When this is executed, another metapattern is created. It generates the same code, until the entire allotted stack space is used up and all hell breaks loose.

Basically, the flow of the program looks like this:

- `[?[src]]`

  - `[src]`

    - `[?[src]]`

      - `[src]`

        - `[?[src]]`

          - ...

... where indent depth represents stack size.

[Try it online!](http://berkin.me/rantbox#287E54369DC8D1E4C769F3B7FE5A2AD15BE613F3)

Answer (score 1):

**Shell and HQ9+**

Assumes that there is an HQ9+ interpreter called hq9

crash_things.sh:

```
hq9 $1 | crash_things
```

runs recursively, exits when the output is not a valid HQ9+ program.

evil_code.sh:

```
hq9 QQ | crash_things
```

messes it up because the code doubles in length every time.

Answer (score 0):

## Frege

Type this in the REPL at try.frege-lang.org

```
> foldr (+) 0 [1..]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Delphi / Object Pascal

Not exactly weird, but technically deprecated and certainly without recursion.

```
  raise EStackOverflow.Create('Without recursion'); // deprecated warning
```

This raises the same stack overflow exception that would be raised by an actual stack overflow. Compiling the code results in `[dcc32 Warning]: W1000 Symbol 'EStackOverflow' is deprecated` warning because the `EStackOverflow` class is defined in `System.SysUtils` as deprecated presumably with the intention that it never be actually raised, but it is defined to make it easier to trap and handle a Stack Overflow (despite the fact you really can't do much to recover from a stack overflow).

You could suppress the warning by wrapping it in a compiler directive.

Comment: "I.e, avoid boring obvious answers like this:

throw new StackOverflowError(); // Valid, but very boring and downvote-deserving."

Answer (score 0):

### Python

```py
class I:
    def __init__(self, kids=[]):
        self.kids=kids
    def allkids(self):
        for ii in self.kids:
            ii.allkids()
jj = I()
jj.kids.append(I())
jj.allkids()
```

It dumps when you run it because of a [mutable default argument](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

```
  ... more here ...
  File "foo.py", line 6, in allkids
    ii.allkids()
  File "foo.py", line 6, in allkids
    ii.allkids()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
[mpenning@tsunanmi]$
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java again.

Using too many parameters this time

```java
public class M
{
    
    public static final int maxmethods=1024;
    public static void main(String[]a) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        StringBuffer paramvals = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer paramdecls = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer paramusages = new StringBuffer();
        String[] methodnames = new String[maxmethods];
        String[] methods = new String[maxmethods];
        int i=0;
        for (; i < maxmethods-1; i++)
        {
            methodnames[i] = "method"+i+"(";
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i<253){
            paramvals.append(i+",");
            paramusages.append("param"+i+",");
            paramdecls.append("int param"+i+",");}
        }
        i=maxmethods-1;
        methodnames[i] = "method"+i+"(";
        paramvals.append(255+"");
        paramusages.append("param"+255);
        paramdecls.append("int param"+255);
        for (int j = 0; j < methodnames.length-1; j++)
        {
            methods[j] = "public static void "+methodnames[j]+paramdecls+")\n{\n"+methodnames[j+1]+paramusages+");\n}";
        }
        methods[maxmethods-1] = "public static void "+methodnames[maxmethods-1]+paramdecls+")\n{\nSystem.out.println(\"This shouldnt be reached\");\n}";
        //fuckyou java
        StringBuilder finaL = new StringBuilder();
        finaL.append("public class F{\npublic static void main(String[]a){System.out.println(\"NOPPE\");}\n\nstatic{helper();}\n"+
                "public static void helper(){method0("+paramvals+");\n}\n//#######################################################+\n");
        for (String method : methods)
        {
            finaL.append(method);
        }
        finaL.append("}");
        new FileWriter(new File("F.java")).write((finaL+"").toCharArray());//Dump of srcfile generated
        EU c2 = new EU("F", finaL+"");
        JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager f = c.getStandardFileManager(null,null,null);
        c.getTask(null, f, null, null, null,Arrays.asList(new EU[]{c2})).call();
        //System.out.print(new File("").toURI().toURL());
        URLClassLoader u = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("").toURI().toURL()});
        Class fc = u.loadClass("F");
        fc.getMethod("helper", null).invoke(null, null);    
    }
        public static class EU extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
           final String code;

           EU(String name, String code) {
               super(URI.create("string:///" + name.replace('.','/') + JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE.extension),
                     JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE);
               this.code = code;
           }
           @Override
           public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
               return code;
           }
       }
}
```

generated file is dumped in workdirecotry used while running; no endless recursion inside :P
runtime compilation ftw :)

Edit: moved the method count to a constant

Answer (score 0):

### Python

```
>>> def foo( N ):
    root = list()
    nest = root
    for i in range(N):
        nest.append( list() )
        nest = nest[0]
    return root

>>> nested(999)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#184>", line 1, in <module>
    nested(999)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the repr of a list
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby**

```
class Fixnum
  def +(arg)
    self-arg
  end
  def -(arg)
    self+arg
  end
end
```

reopens the `Fixnum` class, defines addition as substraction and substraction as addition, then simply do:

```
3+2
```

and voila :)

Comment: Obvious recursion but still funny.

Comment: Code that redefines numeric operators to return the wrong answer is always suspicious. Your recursive calls to Fixnum#+ and Fixnum#- look obvious to me.

Comment: I did this to a friend, it didn't look obvious to him when he opened up a new feature branch and got stack overflow on an addition ^_^

Answer (score 0):

## Batch

```
START http://stackoverflow.com
ECHO STACKOVERFLOW!
PAUSE > NUL
```

Sorry, I coudln't resist!

It fulfills rule 1 and 2 ;o

Comment: LOL :) nice bending of the rules :)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy

```
def getProperty(String p){ p2 }; p
```

Due to an undefined property, Groovy calls `getProperty` again.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2

Stack overflow caused by printing. Yes, the standard usual printing operation. It's SIGSEGV, not standard RuntimeError in CPython.

```
print reduce(lambda*s:s,range(100000))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with the worlds most convoluted javascript! I think it's a cheat since it is really just "obvious" recursion.

```js
(function(f){
    return new function () {
        for(var i= 1; i<3;i++) {
        (function(i){this[i] =  this[f(i)] || function (arg) {
            return !arg || (this[f(i)] || this[i + 1]).apply(this, [f(arg)]);
    }}.bind(this))(f(i));
        }       
}
})(function(i){return i === 1 ? i : i - 1;})[1](1);
```

Answer (score 0):

## VB.NET

I found this when I did your basic merge sort when I came across a StackOverFlowError. I was so confuzzled I asked a SO question about it. Without going to the link, can you find the cause? [The link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508346/vb-net-doesnt-round-numbers-correctly) Obviously this sorting algorithm uses recursion, but that is not the *cause* of the error being thrown.

**Runner Class:**

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        dim array = new integer(100){}
        dim random = new Random()
        for i=0 to 100
            array(i) = random.next()
        next
        dim sorter = new MergeSort()
        sorter.sort(array)
    End Sub
End Module
```

**MergeSort Class:**

```
public class MergeSort

    private numbers() as integer
    private helper() as integer

    private number as integer

    public sub sort(values as integer())
        me.numbers = values
        number = values.length
        me.helper = new integer(number) {}
        mergesort(0, number - 1)
    end sub

    private sub mergesort(low as integer, high as integer)
' check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high)
  ' Get the index of the element which is in the middle
          dim middle as integer = low + (high - low) / 2
  ' Sort the left side of the array
          mergesort(low, middle)
  ' Sort the right side of the array
          mergesort(middle + 1, high)
  ' Combine them both
          merge(low, middle, high)
        end if
    end sub

    private sub merge(low as integer,middle as integer,high as integer)
    ' Copy both parts into the helper array
        for l = low to high 
          helper(l) = numbers(l)
        next

        dim i as integer = low
        dim j as integer = middle + 1
        dim k as integer = low
    ' Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
    ' to the original array
        while (i <= middle andalso j <= high) 
          if (helper(i) <= helper(j)) 
            numbers(k) = helper(i)
            i+=1
          else 
            numbers(k) = helper(j)
            j+=1
          end if
          k+=1
        end while

    ' Copy the rest of the left side of the array integero the target array
        while (i <= middle) 
          numbers(k) = helper(i)
          k+=1
          i+=1
        end while
    end sub
end class
```

Answer (score -1):

**Ruby**

```
puts Time.now
```

Presumably, someday many millions of years into the future, the current time will become so large that the computer will run out of memory.

Comment: Surely time grows linearly while memory grows exponentially according to More's law...?

Comment: Won't the time just wrap round since technically most time structures are actually integers internally anyway?

Answer (score -3):

The Ackermann function!

## Java

```java
public class Ackermann {

   public static long ackermann(long m, long n) {
      if (m == 0) return n + 1;
      if (n == 0) return ackermann(m - 1, 1);
      return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      long M = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
      long N = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
      System.out.println(ackermann(M, N));
   }
}
```

(Shamelessly copied from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/75universality/Ackermann.java.html)

```
 % java Ackermann 3 8
 2045
 % java Ackermann 3 9
 StackOverflowError
```

Comment: This is obvious recursion, so I think this is not acceptable according to the rules.

Answer (score -3):

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   main();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is about "weird". Your answer doesn't seem very interesting and is not likely to give you upvotes.

Comment: please add title of the programming language (in this case `c`)

Comment: You can optimize by `return main();`