# Tell me the moves

Tags: code-golf, chess

Jack and Jane decided to play a game of chess to while away time.  Unfortunately, Jack is rather bad at visualizing.  He finds it tough to figure the moves possible for a given piece other than a pawn, of course!

Your challenge is to help find Jack the possible options for a given piece (other than a pawn).

In case one has forgotten, the various pieces are denoted by:

- K: King
- Q: Queen
- N: Knight
- B: Bishop
- R: Rook

As an example, in the following image the Knight is located at `d4` and can move to `c2`, `b3`, `b5`, `c6`, `e6`, `f5`, `f3`, `e2`.  For a given input:

```
Nd4
```

you would produce:

```
Nc2 Nb3 Nb5 Nc6 Ne6 Nf5 Nf3 Ne2
```

[image]

Rules:

- The order of the output doesn't matter as long as all the possible moves are listed
- The possible moves can be separated by whitespaces, newlines or any other delimiter
- The input can be passed to the program as a parameter or via `STDIN`
- Whitespace in the program shall be counted, so make optimum use of it

This is code golf.  (Please avoid making use of any tools/utilities specifically designed for the purpose.)  The shortest answer wins!

Comment: I believe this would work just fine as a code golf

Comment: @JanDvorak I was bit confused about that.  Agree with you.

Comment: Code golf is the better choice. The obvious is always forgotten: I understand that we can submit either a function or a program, and that input/output can be either stdin/stout or parameters/return value. I'm thinking recursion might be useful here for the queen: `f(x)... case "Q": {f("B");f("R")}` If the function requires any #includes these should be part of the byte count.

Comment: The font in that graphic. xD

Comment: Do the possible moves have to be separated by spaces or are newlines OK as well?

Comment: the legal moves for a pawn are more convoluted than any other piece (en passant, diagonal capturing, and the 2-square initial move). so i assume jack also has the castling rules memorized?

Comment: @ardnew The complexity involved with pawn movements was the precise reason for excluding that.  Moreover, keeping that would have implied keeping track of color and direction too.  (What's Jack?  You mean rook, don't you?)

Comment: jack is the chap with poor visualization skills! and you're right- it wouldn't be possible to identify all valid moves without a full board and some limited move history either. so we should ignore all special moves, correct?

Comment: @ardnew You are right.  Making the problem overly complicated doesn't seem like a good code-golf problem.  Feeding a chess board as input wouldn't have made much sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## GolfScript, <s>94</s> 93 characters

My first ever GolfScript program! This took me many an hour of fumbling around not really knowing what I was doing, but I persisted and I think I managed to learn the language basics and golf it fairly well.

[Fully golfed](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Ik5kNCIKCnt9Lzgsezk3Ky4zJC0uKjo%2BOCx7NDkrLjQkLS4qOl4yJCsuWzM8Pl4qND0%2BXj0%2BXiohLjIkfF0iS05CUlEiOCQ%2FPSp7WzUkMyRAXSIiK3B9ezt9aWZ9Lzs7fS9dOw%3D%3D):

```
{}/8,{97+.3$-.*:>8,{49+.4$-.*:^2$+.[3<>^*4=>^=>^*!.2$|]"KNBRQ"8$?=*{[5$3$@]""+p}{;}if}/;;}/];
```

[Commented and nicer source](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Iy0xIC0xIC0xIC0xIC0xIC0xIC0xIC0xCiMjU1RBQ0sgRFVNUDogWzckNyQ3JDckNyQ3JDckNyRdcAoKIk5kNCIKCnt9LyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIyB0SW4gZkluIHJJbgo4LHs5NysgICAgICAgICAgICMgICAgICAgICAgICAgZlRzdAogIC4zJC0uKjo%2BICAgICAgICMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBmRGlmXjIgOiA%2BCiAgOCx7NDkrICAgICAgICAgIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICByVHN0IAogICAgLjQkLS4qOl4gICAgICMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICByRGlmXjIgOiBeCiAgICAyJCsuICAgICAgICAgIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBePisKICAgIFszPCAgICAgICAgICAjIFRoZXNlICAgICMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBbdmFsaWRLCiAgICAgPl4qND0gICAgICAgIyBjaGVja3MgICAjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB2YWxpZE4KICAgICA%2BXj0gICAgICAgICAjIGRvIG5vdCAgICMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB2YWxpZEIKICAgICA%2BXiohICAgICAgICAjIGFjY291bnQgICMgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgdmFsaWRSCiAgICAgLjIkfF0gICAgICAgIyBmb3IgbnVsbCAjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB2YWxpZFFdCiAgICAiS05CUlEiOCQ%2FPSAgIyBtb3ZlOyAgICAjICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB2YWxpZAogICAgKiAgICAgICAgICAgICMgKiBkb2VzLiAgIyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgdmFsaWROb3ROdWxsCiAgICB7WzUkMyRAXSIiK3B9ezt9aWYgICMgcHJpbnQ%2FICMgIGZEaWZeMgogIH0vOzsgICAgICAgICAgICMgICAgICAgIHJJbgp9L107):

```
{}/              # tIn fIn rIn
8,{97+           #             fTst
  .3$-.*:>       #                  fDif^2 : >
  8,{49+         #                         rTst 
    .4$-.*:^     #                              rDif^2 : ^
    2$+.         #                                     ^>+
    [3<          # These    #                              [validK
     >^*4=       # checks   #                                      validN
     >^=         # do not   #                                             validB
     >^*!        # account  #                                                    validR
     .2$|]       # for null #                                                           validQ]
    "KNBRQ"8$?=  # move;    #                          valid
    *            # * does.  #                          validNotNull
    {[5$3$@]""+p}{;}if  # print? #  fDif^2
  }/;;           #        rIn
}/];
```

It may look like Claudiu's answer, which is because I referenced his answer, as well as my (unsubmitted) C solution, while making mine. He provided a good specimen of a (relatively) complex, working GolfScript program, and it helped me learn a lot about the language. So thanks, Claudiu!

Being new to GolfScript still, if you guys have any feedback, I'd appreciate hearing it!

Comment: Awesome! Nice work =). I'll have to look at it more closely later to see how you got 40 chars shorter than mine. Isn't Golfscript fun?

Answer (score 12):

## Python, <s>217</s> <s>212</s> <s>220</s> <s>217</s> 213 characters

Tied the 213-byte Mathematica solution

```
R=range(8)
def f((p,x,y)):
 for a in R:
    for b in R:
     A,B=abs(a-ord(x)+97),abs(b-ord(y)+49);C=max(A,B);r=(A+B==3and C<3,C<2,A*B<1,A==B,0)
     if(r['NKRBQ'.index(p)],any(r[1:]))[p=='Q']*C:print p+chr(a+97)+chr(b+49)
```

I started off by generating all valid moves but that grew too large so the approach is quite similar to the Mathematica one.

```
>>> f("Nd4")
Nb3
Nb5
Nc2
Nc6
Ne2
Ne6
Nf3
Nf5
>>> f("Qa1")
Qa2
Qa3
Qa4
Qa5
Qa6
Qa7
Qa8
Qb1
Qb2
Qc1
Qc3
Qd1
Qd4
Qe1
Qe5
Qf1
Qf6
Qg1
Qg7
Qh1
Qh8
```

Comment: Nice extracting of string chars with this argument tuple. Too bad it doesn't work anymore in Python 3.

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, <s>278</s> <s>272</s> <s>264</s> <s>260</s> <s>215</s> 213 characters

```
f=(FromCharacterCode@Flatten[Table[c=Abs[#2-x];d=Abs[#3-y];b=c==d;r=#2==x||#3==y;If[Switch[#-75,0,c~Max~d<2,-9,b,7,r,6,b||r,3,!r&&c+d==3],{p,x,y},##&[]],{x,97,104},{y,49,56}]&@@ToCharacterCode@#,1]~DeleteCases~#)&
```

Ungolfed version:

```
f[pos_] := (
  {piece, u, v} = ToCharacterCode@pos;
  board = Flatten[Table[{piece, i + 96, j + 48}, {i, 8}, {j, 8}], 1];
  DeleteCases[
    FromCharacterCode[
      Cases[board, {_, x_, y_} /; Switch[p,
        75, (* K *)
        ChessboardDistance[{x, y}, {u, v}] < 2,
        66, (* B *)
        Abs[u - x] == Abs[v - y],
        82, (* R *)
        u == x || v == y,
        81, (* Q *)
        Abs[u - x] == Abs[v - y] || u == x || v == y,
        78, (* N *)
        u != x && v != y && ManhattanDistance[{x, y}, {u, v}] == 3
        ]
      ]
    ], 
    pos (* remove the input position *)
  ]
)&
```

Example usage:

```
f["Nd4"]
> {"Nb3", "Nb5", "Nc2", "Nc6", "Ne2", "Ne6", "Nf3", "Nf5"}
```

The ungolfed version creates a full board, and then selects correct positions with `Cases`, whereas the golfed version drops invalid moves immediately in the `Table` command by issuing `##&[]`, which simply vanishes.

Comment: Just curious about the input, is it `N4d`?  Shouldn't it be `Nd4` instead?

Comment: @devnull sure, that's a typo. should be `Nd4`.

Comment: Learned a knew function today `ChessboardDistance`

Comment: Per the Mathematica/Wolfram Language documentation, "ChessboardDistance[u,v] is equivalent to Max[Abs[u-v]]." Perhaps you can save characters by using the latter form, especially if you replace Abs[u-v] with |u-v|.

Comment: @MichaelStern that's exactly what I'm doing in the golfed version ;). And unfortunately vertical bars don't work for `Abs` in Mathematica, because they denote alternatives in a pattern.

Answer (score 10):

## Haskell <s>225 220 208 205 200</s> 182

```
f=fromEnum
m[p,a,b]=[[p,c,r]|c<-"abcdefgh",r<-"12345678",let{s=abs$f a-f c;t=abs$f b-f r;g"K"=s<2&&t<2;g"Q"=g"B"||g"R";g"N"=s+t==3&&(s-t)^2<2;g"B"=s==t;g"R"=s<1||t<1}in s+t>0&&g[p]]
```

<s>It's going to be difficult to touch Mathematica when that has chess moves built in :rollseyes: (well played m.buettner)</s> I take it all back. Beating Mathematica by 31!

Latest edit: replaced case with a function, inlined filter into comprehension, to beat the entry in R ;)

usage:

```
ghci> m "Nd4"
["Nb3","Nb5","Nc2","Nc6","Ne2","Ne6","Nf3","Nf5"]
```

Ungolfed (corresponds to 208 char version before 'u' was inlined):

```
f=fromEnum -- fromEnum is 'ord' but for all enum types,
           -- and it's in the prelude, so you don't need an extra import.
u piece dx dy= -- piece is the character eg 'K', dx/dy are absolute so >=0.
  dx+dy > 0 && -- the piece must move.
  case piece of
    'K'->dx<2&&dy<2         -- '<2' works because we already checked dx+dy>0
    'Q'->dx<1||dy<1||dx==dy -- rook or bishop move. see below.
    'N'->dx+dy == 3 &&      -- either 2+1 or 3+0. Exclude the other...
         (dx-dy)^2 < 2      -- 1^2 or 3^2, so valid move is '<2', ie '==1'
    'B'->dx==dy             -- if dx==dy, dx/=0 - we checked that. 
                            -- other moves with dx==dy are along diagonal
    _->dx<1||dy<1           -- use _ not 'R' to save space, default case is
                            -- the rook. '<1' saves chars over '==0'.
                            -- Again, dx==dy==0 edge case is excluded.
m[piece,file,rank]=       -- the move for a piece. 'parse' by pattern match.
 filter(                    -- filter...
  \[_,newfile,newrank]->    -- ...each possible move...
    u piece                 -- ...by, as everyone noticed, converting char..
      (abs$f file-f newfile) -- differences to absolute dx, dy differences,..
      (abs$f rank-f newrank)) -- and then using special routines per piece.
    [[piece,newfile, newrank] -- the output format requires these 3 things.
      |newfile<-"abcdefgh",newrank<-"12345678"] -- and this just generates moves.
```

Comment: Can you post an ungolfed version too? (if you have one of course)

Comment: @swish I don't but I don't mind writing that up.

Comment: @swish done. Hope that makes more sense. Ask away if you need something clarified.

Comment: Great job! Why do you need add `piece` to the list `[piece,newfile, newrank]` if you don't use it in pattern matching, can save you some characters?

Comment: It's there for output. You'll see I don't pattern match on it in '...each possible move...'. Originally I didn't have this - chess moves don't require it - but then I noticed the question wanted it, and everyone else did it, so it's only fair.

Comment: Another suggestion: why `m(p:[a,b])` and not just `m[p,a,b]`?

Comment: @swish oh, good point. I'd previously had m(p:x) there and only started matching a,b in that function when I got down to 212. I'll fix it now, thanks!

Comment: I actually didn't even use `ChessboardDistance` in the golfed version... the name is just too bulky. ^^

Answer (score 8):

## Bash, 238

```
B={19..133..19}\ {21..147..21};K=1\ {19..21};N='18 22 39 41';R={1..7}\ {2..14..2}0;Q=$B\ $R
a=${1%??};b=$[20#${1:1}-200];c=`eval{,} echo '$'$a`;d=({a..h})
for i in $c -${c// / -};do echo $a${d[$[(i+=b)/20]]}$[i%20];done|grep '[a-h][1-8]$'
```

## How it works

- The idea is to represent every field on the board by a numeric value, taking its coordinates as a base-20 number and subtracting 200. This way, `a1` becomes `20 * 10 + 1 - 200 = 1`, `h8` becomes `20 * 17 + 8 - 200 = 148`, etc.

  Now, the possible moves of the Bishop can be represented by (positive or negative) multiples of 19 – same amount of steps up (+20) and to the left (-1) – or 21 – same amount of steps up (+20) and to the right (+1).

  The figure's placement after the move is simply the sum of its original position and the movement. After adding those numbers, we have to check if their sum corresponds to a valid field on the board.

  Since the base (20) is more than twice as big as the highest possible number (8), the sum cannot wrap around the board, e.g., moving *Bh1* seven steps to the right and up will result in an invalid board position.
- The line

  ```
  B={19..133..19}\ {21..147..21};K=1\ {19..21};N='18 22 39 41';R={1..7}\ {2..14..2}0;Q=$B\ $R
  ```

  enumerates all possible moves of the pieces that are represented by positive numbers.
- The commands

  ```
  a=${1%??};b=$[20#${1:1}-200];c=`eval{,} echo '$'$a`;d=({a..h})
  ```

  stores the piece's identifier in variable *a*, the original position's numeric representation in *b* and the letters *a* to *h* in the array *d*.

  After brace expansion, `eval{,} echo '$'$a` becomes `eval eval echo '$'$a` (doubly evil), which evaluates to, e.g., `eval echo $K`, which evaluates to `echo 1 19 20 21`.
- `for i in $c -${c// / -};do …; done` loops over all possible movements and their negative counterparts.
- `echo $a${d[$[(i+=b)/20]]}$[i%20]` gives the final position after the movement.
- `grep '[a-h][1-8]$'` makes sure that we have a valid board position.

Answer (score 7):

### C <s>634</s> <s>632</s> <s>629</s> <s>625</s> 600 chars

```c
#define F for(;i<4;i++){
#define B ;}break;
#define O x=X,y=Y,
P,X,Y,c,r,x,y,i=0, N[8][2]={{-2,1},{-1,2},{1,2},{2,1},{-2,-1},{-1,-2},{1,-2},{2,-1}},S[4][2]={{1,0},{0,1},{-1,0},{0,-1}},D[4][2]={{-1,1},{-1,-1},{1,1},{1,-1}};
C(){return((0<=c)&(c<8)&(0<r)&(r<9))?printf("%c%c%d ",P,c+'a',r):0;}
M(int*m){c=m[0]+x,r=m[1]+y;C()?x=c,y=r,M(m):0;}
main(int a,char**v){char*p=v[1];P=*p,X=p[1]-97,Y=p[2]-48; switch(P){case 75:F c=S[i][1]+X,r=S[i][0]+Y,C(),c=D[i][1]+X,r=D[i][0]+Y,C()B case 81:F O M(D[i]),O M(S[i])B case 78:for(;i<8;i++){c=N[i][1]+X,r=N[i][0]+Y,C()B case 66:F O M(D[i])B case 82:F O M(S[i])B}}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this? This is my first time submitting an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!  To begin with, you could strip the whitespace in your code.  Remember this is code golf, which implies that the shortest code wins.  So attempt to reduce the size of your program.

Comment: Remember to update the character count too!

Comment: @devnull are necessary spaces counted?

Comment: Yes, the necessary spaces are counted.

Comment: In C if no type is specified, `int` is implied, so you may want to get rid of the `int`s in your `int C(P,c,r)` and `M(int P,int x,int y,int m[2])` and use a global variable, e.g. `z`, to replace the `c` in your `M` function so you don't need `int` there as well.

Comment: Also, instead of `main(int argc,char*argv[])`, you can do `main(int a,char**v)`

Comment: @ace how do I get rid of the `int`s in M()? mingw is complaining about `m[2]` needing the int in front of it.

Comment: @calccrypto Oops, sorry, I thought you can. My fault. By the way, can you use `int*m` instead of `int m[2]`?

Comment: One more thing: `C` can be simplified greatly using the ternary operator `?:` and by using the return value of `printf`. (`printf` returns the number of characters written, so in this case it is always non-zero.) `C(P,c,r){return(0<=c)&(c<8)&(0<r)&(r<9)?printf("%c%c%d ",P,c+'a',r):0;}`. A minor edit: there is an extra space in `M` after the `if` that you can remove.

Comment: i forgot about that. thanks!

Comment: Right now, you seem not to be counting any newlines. While *some* of them can be removed, others cannot. Required newlines should definitely contribute to the byte count.

Comment: For this specific puzzle, the table of moves you have isn't the shortest solution. Take a look at the other solutions - they mostly use absolute dx and dy differences, and 'min(dx,dy)' and 'max(dx,dy)' can be useful too. We also went for generating all positions on the board *once* and then per-piece testing if the move was valid, not per-piece generate&test functions.

Comment: i know, i know. im just doing using naive method

Comment: There's still a whole bunch of whitespace that can be removed: there are unnecessary spaces after open braces and semicolons.

Comment: You may benefit from defining something shorter for `case`.

Answer (score 7):

## Golfscript, <s>144</s> 135 characters

Instead of continuing to try golfing my [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25057/4800), I translated it into Golfscript:

```
{}/49-:y;97-:x;:N;8,{.x-abs:A
8,{.y-abs:B@[\]$1=:C[B
A+3=\3<&2C>B
A*1<B
A=]81N={(;{|}*}{"NKRB"N?=}if
C*{[N
2$97+@49+]''+p}{;}if
A}/;;}/
```

Straightforward translation without much golfing so it can most likely be whittled away further. Takes input from stdin without a newline, [try it here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJOZDQiCgp7fS80OS06eTs5Ny06eDs6TjsKOCx7CiM1IAogICNhCiAgLngtYWJzOkEKICAjYSBBCjgsewojMyAKICAjYSBBIGIgCiAgLnktYWJzOkIKICAjYSBBIGIgQgogIEBbXF0kMT06QwogICNhIGIgQwogIFtCIEErMz1cMzwmCiAgIDJDPgogICBCIEEqMTwKICAgQiBBPV0KICA4MU49CiAgeyg7e3x9Kn0KICB7Ik5LUkIiTj89fWlmCiAgQyp7W04gMiQ5NytANDkrXScnK3B9ezt9aWYgQQp9Lwo7Owp9Lw%3D%3D) (1st two lines are to mimic stdin).

Comment: Seems to work well!  I hope that someone comes up with a brainf*ck solution too.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>300</s> 269 chars

Thanks to bazzargh for help with losing 31 characters...

```
import Data.Char
f x=filter(x#)[x!!0:y|y<-[v:[w]|v<-"abcdefgh",w<-"12345678"],y/=tail x]
a%b=abs(ord a-ord b)
x#y=let{h=(x!!1)%(y!!1);v=(x!!2)%(y!!2);m=max h v;n=min h v}in case(x!!0)of{'N'->m==2&&n==1;'K'->m==1;'B'->h==v;'R'->n==0;'Q'->('R':tail x)#y||('B':tail x)#y}
```

Same algorithm as the Mathematica version.  Sample output from ghci:

```
*Main> f "Nd4"
["Nb3","Nb5","Nc2","Nc6","Ne2","Ne6","Nf3","Nf5"]
*Main> f "Ni9"
["Ng8","Nh7"]
```

(You didn't ask for sanity checking!)

Comment: You can get rid of syntactic whitespace. See my answer here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell (to be more specific, you want let{h=d(x!!1)(y!!1);...})

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell , 446 chars

```
import Data.Char
a=[-2,-1,1,2]
b=[-1,1]
d=[1..8]
e=[-8..8]
g=[-1..1]
h 'N' c r=[(c+x,r+y)|x<-a,y<-a,3==(sum$map abs[x, y])]
h 'B' c r=[(c+x*z,r+y*z)|x<-b,y<-b,z<-d]
h 'R' c r=[(c+x,r)|x<-e]++[(c,r+y)|y<-e]
h 'Q' c r=h 'B' c r++h 'R' c r
h 'K' c r=[(c+x,r+y)|x<-g,y<-g]
l s=ord s-96
m n=chr$n+96
k ch (c,r)=ch:m c:[intToDigit r]
f (x,y)=all(`elem`[1..8])[x, y]
i n c r=map(k n).filter(/=(c,r)).filter f$h n c r
j s=i(s!!0)(l$s!!1)(digitToInt$s!!2)
```

Called using the `j` function

```
j "Nd4"
```

I haven't worked with Haskell in a few months, so it didn't end up being as short as most of the other solutions, but I'm sure there are some optimizations to made, mainly with `h`. I might shorten it in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## q & k [<strike>311</strike> 262 chars]

There is a potential of reducing some more characters. I will be reducing it in next iteration.

```
k)o:{n:#m:&(#x)##y;((),x)[m],'n#y}

k)a:`$"c"$(o/)c:+(97;49)+/:!8

k)r:{{|x@<x}'?,/{o[x]y}'[x](|"c"$c)}
k)k:{"c"$(6h$x)+/:(o/)2 3#-1 0 1}
k)n:{"c"$(6h$x)+/:(|:'t),t:o[-1 1;2 2]}
k)b:{"c"$(6h$x)+/:(n,'n),n,'|n:-8+!17}
k)q:{,/(r;b)@\:x}

d:{(`$("rknbq"!(r;k;n;b;q))[x]y)except`$y}
g:{a inter d[x 0]@1_x}
```

#### Usage

Rook

```
g"ra1"
`a2`a3`a4`a5`a6`a7`a8`b1`c1`d1`e1`f1`g1`h1
```

King

```
g"ka1"
`a2`b1`b2
```

Knight

```
g"na1"
`b3`c2
```

Bishop

```
g"ba1"
`b2`c3`d4`e5`f6`g7`h8
```

Queen

```
g"qa1"
`a2`a3`a4`a5`a6`a7`a8`b1`b2`c1`c3`d1`d4`e1`e5`f1`f6`g1`g7`h1`h8
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell (hypothetical), 248 chars

```
import Data.Char
f x=filter(o x)[x!!0:y|y<-[v:[w]|v<-"abcdefgh",w<-"12345678"],y/=tail x]
d a b=abs(ord a-ord b)
h x y=(c*(d(x!!1)(y!!1))-(d(x!!2)(y!!2)))+200*c
 where c=d (x!!0)'A'
o x y=elem(chr(h x y))"ਲ਼ੁߏߚߙÈേെ൅ൄൃ൙൪ൻඌඝථ඿౿౾౽౼౻౺౹ಐಏಠಞರಭೀ಼೐ೋೠ೚೰೩"
```

Unfortunately, every Haskell compiler I can get my hands on right now has problems with Unicode string literals.  Here's the (longer) version that actually works:

```
import Data.Char
f x=filter(o x)[x!!0:y|y<-[v:[w]|v<-"abcdefgh",w<-"12345678"],y/=tail x]
d a b=abs(ord a-ord b)
h x y=(c*(d(x!!1)(y!!1))-(d(x!!2)(y!!2)))+200*c
 where c=d (x!!0)'A'
o x y=elem(chr(h x y))"\2611\2625\1999\2010\2009\200\3399\3398\3397\3396\3395\3394\3393\3417\3434\3451\3468\3485\3502\3519\3199\3198\3197\3196\3195\3194\3193\3216\3215\3232\3230\3248\3245\3264\3260\3280\3275\3296\3290\3312\3305"
```

The definition `h x y=...` is a hash function; valid moves will hash to character numbers that are in the 41-character string.  This gets rid of the need for a "case" statement or equivalent.

I'm not planning to work further on this right now.  It would be fun to see if someone can use a hash function in a more concise language to make a shorter solution.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 203 chars

```R
f=function(p,x,y){x=which((l=letters)==x);X=rep(1:8,8);Y=rep(1:8,rep(8,8));A=abs(X-x);L=abs(Y-y);B=A==L;R=!A|!L;i=switch(p,N=A+L==3&A&L,R=R,B=B,Q=R|B,K=(R|B)&A<2&L<2)&A+L>0;paste(p,l[X[i]],Y[i],sep="")}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
f = function(p,x,y) {
  x = which(letters == x)  # Gives index between 1 and 8.
  X = rep(1:8, 8)          # 1,2,...,7,8,1,2,.... (8x8).
  Y = rep(1:8, rep(8,8))   # 1,1,...2,2,.....,8,8 (8x8).
  dx = abs(X-x)
  dy = abs(Y-y)
  B = (dx == dy)           # Bishop solutions
  R = (!dx | !dy)          # Rock solutions
  i = switch(p,
             N=dx+dy==3 & dx & dx,  # Sum of dist. is 3, dx and dy must be <> 0.
             R=R, 
             B=B, 
             Q=R|B,                 # Queen is merge of rock and bishop.
             K=(R|B) & dx<2 & dy<2  # King's distance is < 2.
             ) & (dx+dy > 0)        # Exclude start field.

  paste(p, letters[X[i]], Y[i], sep="")
}
```

Usage:

```R
> f('N', 'a', 3)
[1] "Nb1" "Nc2" "Nc4" "Nb5"
```

The solution is even good readable. However I added some parentheses and comments for readers unfamiliar with R code (on the ungolfed version).