# Quine of orders

Tags: code-challenge, quine, polyglot

Write a program that, when run in different languages, outputs a different byte permutation of the code in each language. The exact source code is counted as one permutation.

Here "different language" can be different version(Py 2 and Py 3) or different standard flags. It's different output that forces different version.

Proper quine rules apply for the program in each language. Your score is calculated as `(Language count)^6/(Code length in bytes)`, with a higher score being better.

**Sample:**

If your code is `AAB` and running in three different languages returns `ABA`, `AAB` and `AAB`, then its score is `2^6/3`(only one of the two `AAB` count). It's fine if `ABA` is meaningless.

Comment: What counts as a different language?

Comment: Which definition of a proper quine applies? ([Martin's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878), or [ais523's](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12358/3852), or maybe some other definition in these meta threads?) Do the proper quine rules apply only to interpretations of the program that _are_ actually quines? (For what it's worth, I don't think this challenge is improved much by enforcing proper quine rules.)

Comment: To clarify, working on your example — if my code `AAB` prints `AAB` in language-1 and `ABA` in language-2, I assume that it must be a proper quine when viewed as a language-1 program, and there are no further restrictions involving its interpretation as a language-2 program. Is that right?

Comment: @Laikoni assume that, if it prints a different permutation then it is a different language

Comment: Is code length counted in characters or bytes? What should we do with different character encodings?

Comment: None of the programs are required to be a quine, right?

Comment: @dylnan True. Program `123` outputting `321` and `132` is allowed

Comment: What about bytes vs. characters?

Comment: Proper quine rule is to avoid some code like `if(language1)output thiscode().permutation(5);else if(language2)output thiscode().permutation(6);else ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Befunge-98](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), [Wumpus](https://github.com/m-ender/wumpus), [Cardinal](https://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Cardinal), [Beeswax](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl) and [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice) Score: 8<sup>6</sup>/88 = 2978.909

```
"65*4+059*$!#.39*0jp2+'Wk,@ ''5&.'\d&o@o&88#+\@ol?!,'.'0.6'!+Ox,++tttt=++%-$#}.6~.F4*`*R
```

[Try it in Befunge!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XMjPVMtE2MLXUUlFU1jO21DLIKjDSVg/P1nFQUFc3VdNTj0lRy3fIV7OwUNaOccjPsVfUUddTN9AzU1fU9q/Q0dYuAQJbbW1VXRXlWj2zOj03E60EraD//wE)
[Try it in ><>!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8nMVMtE28DUUktFUVnP2FLLIKvASFs9PFvHQUFd3VRNTz0mRS3fIV/NwkJZO8YhP8deUUddT91Az0xdUdu/QkdbuwQIbLW1VXVVlGv1zOr03Ey0ErSC/v8HAA)
[Try it in Gol><>!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X8nMVMtE28DUUktFUVnP2FLLIKvASFs9PFvHQUFd3VRNTz0mRS3fIV/NwkJZO8YhP8deUUddT91Az0xdUdu/QkdbuwQIbLW1VXVVlGv1zOr03Ey0ErSC/v8HAA)
[Try it in Fission!](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7Mz/v/X8nMVMtE28DUUktFUVnP2FLLIKvASFs9PFvHQUFd3VRNTz0mRS3fIV/NwkJZO8YhP8deUUddT91Az0xdUdu/QkdbuwQIbLW1VXVVlGv1zOr03Ey0ErSC/v8HAA)
[Try it in Wumpus!](https://tio.run/##Ky/NLSgt/v9fycxUy0TbwNRSS0VRWc/YUssgq8BIWz08W8dBQV3dVE1PPSZFLd8hX83CQlk7xiE/x15RR11P3UDPTF1R279CR1u7BAhstbVVdVWUa/XM6vTcTLQStIL@/wcA)
[Try it in Cardinal!](https://tio.run/##S04sSsnMS8z5/1/JzFTLRNvA1FJLRVFZz9hSyyCrwEhbPTxbx0FBXd1UTU89JkUt3yFfzcJCWTvGIT/HXlFHXU/dQM9MXVHbv0JHW7sECGy1tVV1VZRr9czq9NxMtBK0gv7/BwA)
[Try it in Beeswax!](https://tio.run/##S0pNLS5PrPj/X8nMVMtE28DUUktFUVnP2FLLIKvASFs9PFvHQUFd3VRNTz0mRS3fIV/NwkJZO8YhP8deUUddT91Az0xdUdu/QkdbuwQIbLW1VXVVlGv1zOr03Ey0ErSC/v8HAA)
[Try it in Alice!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/JzFTLRNvA1FJLRVFZz9hSyyCrwEhbPTxbx0FBXd1UTU89JkUt3yFfzcJCWTvGIT/HXlFHXU/dQM9MXVHbv0JHW7sECGy1tVV1VZRr9czq9NxMtBK0gv7/BwA)

[Verification!](https://tio.run/##fVLLbtswEDxHX7G2U1MSZdpIYsMOYNSnXAP00kNTtJRFyUxokuADig7tr7vUKwhgoDyQs7M75HJI3biTkveXCz9rZRwoGw3INjaKjqpgsG8xsa7gkhhGiziJooKVYLz8pY2qDD3HgsrK04olj9FNzd0JlGYyRq0eZYBqlAC1UD5CSWrDHYvbTHJVS/Lyv@WGOW9k6JLoTjQeixF0RyUfDUZUiGfvQvOCWxefqY4/9ZvBj6luSi8rBotFuNp@tw0gZx01zSBkO2NgqbRbltyeuono5ipZKdHlrTmOeCgbtZYrOa4tb3ze9Nran7W3w0JMfrX5kZpgOxUf4PPWr15wusy57FGvyBmzNX3v6AFPfybBkVnamqANly7rzUmyKOriWAQvBw72wbIQWuZGKjyGLCAEsQ0/gxX9a7SFQ0wTKJUBClzCqLlcppt1@oBX6116O5mR@126etV3GH1/yw6A0HpO0EsxVwc1325n@OWgxNdJhghakQ2a4Of3DGMXxh7jL4vb2R@y@UueHtLf6bd/)

Lots of 2D languages, all abusing wrapping string literals. The difference in outputs are thus:

><>, Gol><> and Befunge-98 all print the code backwards (except for the `"`), with the last three characters in different positions, `R*"`, `O"*` and `"R*` respectively. Beeswax also has the code backwards, but the last three characters are interspersed in the first section of the output. Alice is mostly backwards, except for all the escaped characters (`'`,`\` and `"`) moved to the front instead.

Wumpus is the only actual quine, Fission puts the `"` at the end of the code instead of the beginning, and Cardinal puts the `"` between the `0` and the `5` near the start.

[Proof of different permutations](https://tio.run/##tZTBbqMwEIbP5SmMSWPwuBZqACUHVE69VuKSQ4hUGpyU1osRkG16aF89xQ5IXWnVU/HNY898mvl/u37vnlW1OJ93qhAovrpqCCE4CmkAfriiM9vhixX1X@pbIOtXliBCwjknWTFXiZovlw5kiZJ3NiOc@DwiNjycGEDXrxjg@mbmfPDok98H9JGmfWnLehL7Y3XQLINK@4Pgnn9G/MOZ3VwDxDoXgJ0ewCYR9/vCzL6TKsnAWS4NtsgIn4eEoIS9rgnc1i8@XS24Y8/oKvQhoGGkUfuyfR5bSimejHNQckBpEsXplB21paoG0kQqYU16O/6pj@0o0oR@2OVNUVa5/KcnPAnqSYj2LT@NOtEg1So9/q5MZnq5LHeX14QxzohZPzu95/EL7RtMswzq/ySMLUv8Fc07itFmeFYMaSsyNHjSbLVlGLooytA4cIaGeWwtq27KqnNzKd2NFJXbis41hT0PxTHSoct2C5tWNZ0oXJlXh2N@EObCENNfiIf2qkHjKSorZDK3nnc@fwE)

### Explanations:

#### Befunge-98:

```
"  Wrapping string literal pushes all other characters + a space to the stack
 65*4+  Push " to the stack
      059*$!#.39*0j   Push 1,27 to the stack
                   p  Pops the top three values of the stack (27,1,34)
                    2+  Adds 2 to the space to make "
                      'Wk,@  Prints the top 88 characters of the stack and terminates
```

#### ><> and Gol><>:

To be honest, I didn't do much here. The only difference between the execution of these two languages is the `@` command, which rotates the top three values of the stack in different ways for each language.

```
"  Wrapping string literal pushes all other characters to the stack
 65*4+  Push 34 (") to the stack
      059*$!#.  Jump to cell 45,0
                                   \@  Rotate the top three values of the stack 
                                     ol?!,'.'0.  Output the whole stack, ending in a divide by 0/stack underflow error
```

#### Fission:

```
 "............R  Spawn a pointer going right

 "  Switch to printing mode and print every other character
 "  Switch off printing mode
  6  Teleport to other 6
 "........6'!+O   Print the "
```

#### Wumpus:

```
"  Bouncing string literal
 65*4+  Push a (")
      059*$!#.   Push 0 and jump to cell 0,45
                                        \  Reflect off mirror
                                       +   Add 0 to top of stack
                                 @o&88#    Print the top 88 characters of the stack
```

#### Cardinal:

```
                                 %   Spawn two pointer going left/right (up/down despawn immediately)
                                  -$  Right pointer jumps to cell -1,0
                      x,++tttt=++     Left pointer prints "
"  While right pointer switches to print mode and prints the code
```

#### Beeswax:

```
 "................*`*   Spawn pointers going in every direction
                        Every other * also spawns pointers, but they do nothing
                   `    Turn on print mode for two of the pointers going in different directions
                        This prints everything but the `
          #}.6~.F4*     Print a `
```

#### Alice:

```
"  Wrapping string literal pushes all other characters to the stack
   Except 's and mirrors
 65*4+  Push " to the stack
      059*$!#.  Does nothing
              39*0j  Jumps to cell 39,0
                         ''5&.    Push ' and duplicate it 5 times
                              '\  Push \
                                d&o@  Print the whole stack
```

Answer (score 6):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), JavaScript (Chrome), [PHP](https://php.net/), [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1206 bytes, score 6<sup>6</sup>/1206 = 38.6865671641791

```
q=1//2;s=+0;s|0;"/.__id__;#";_="""q=1//2;s=+0;s|0;"/.__id__;#";_={0}{1}{0};R=chr((39,34)[1/2>0])*12;Q=chr((39,34)[1/2==0])*3;q={0}{2}{0};print(_.format(Q,_,q[0:-12]+R,"%"))""";R=chr((39,34)[1/2>0])*12;Q=chr((39,34)[1/2==0])*3;q="""|;#<?ob_end_clean();
eval($_='"$t"?0?[$q=37 .chr+113 .chr+38 .chr,$p=(96 .chr+39 .chr)*4,$n=10 .chr,$s=39 .chr*12,$S=34 .chr*3]:eval("printf=console.log;c=String.fromCharCode;$q=c(96);$p=c(37,113,38,39).repeat(4);$n=c(10);$s=c(39).repeat(12);$S=c(34,34,34)"):[]?[$q=q(!g)^PA,$p=HARHARHARHAR^od2od2od2od2,$n=R^X,$s=bbbbbbbbbbbb^EEEEEEEEEEEE,$S=hhh^JJJ]:[$q=O^h,$p=str_repeat(RHa3^w9GS,4),$n=R^X,$s=str_repeat(b^E,12),$S=HHH^jjj];//#');printf($x='q=1//2;s=+0;s|0;"/.__id__;#";_=%7$sq=1//2;s=+0;s|0;"/.__id__;#";_={0}{1}{0};R=chr((39,34)[1/2>0])*12;Q=chr((39,34)[1/2==0])*3;q={0}{2}{0};print(_.format(Q,_,q[0:-12]+R,"%8$s"))%7$s;R=chr((39,34)[1/2>0])*12;Q=chr((39,34)[1/2==0])*3;q=%7$s|;#<?ob_end_clean();%5$seval($_=%3$s%1$s%3$s);printf($x=%3$s%2$s%3$s,$_,$x,$q,$p,$n,$s,$S,"%8$s",![]||([]+[])?$n:"");//#%4$s%6$s%7$s;print(_.format(Q,_,q[0:-12]+R,"%8$s"))%9$s',$_,$x,$q,$p,$n,$s,$S,"%",![]||([]+[])?$n:"");//#`q&%`q&%`q&%`q&%''''''''''''""";print(_.format(Q,_,q[0:-12]+R,"%"))
```

[Validate Perl, Ruby, PHP, Python 2 and Python 3 online!](https://tio.run/##7VRbU@JIFH7nV/S0HUlrTAhhRqGNljW1NZQPsw5UbW0VQgwhkDgxCekwSgm/3T2dgBNu6@iTD6Zyge9cvq9Pnz59m3tPT7GbBEj1w3iSqqkfoTMUR8F0FESpGgeslEz60x3mpM9KeyiMBu4Oh1vOSq7jRQgTHa8bYi9GRwPEvShJrSh2Qyu1R2YUCjCapJDO6k@GQzfxwwzeIdGLIdU09XZ7TJcOxk4Pg5VK9w46cgoeuXS2wFdqsgaJOqxBYoHrgULpOjbdAgkxOfWieO1okjhuA7OSY6dbFN4NPqPTVYUr8Veww8voLV47whH@HqXIRuOJH7oKsgcDLl4@EId2gMrjMsdrRC3olQ0iUZ2tREvDS0TSFqZL@5fddhI/TpH8HRoQCk43mJftt8EsDIvGLWBolkMzBO7rJWxebVZQbOj2EmZN@cr@LkaDhteGb1Wdn4vqpvTpLuXPh6WICTk5@D8sxhYWYyeN8ftQFtFnJmONCvZrD2Wj6qgSuqhMLPM28kOMFQ4F0lRtxLgmq/RaP9Bg2jSwGrjhKPVksk9VfB1ibeSyGIqVYnLR@vbPdUis6xDwcnEoPEs5AMoi28MG273nB658ekYfifdIrLlqZnnnwyiRf7pTLnn0MeMb4twB@RxJ/Jcd@AOgVfwQPcjkAYWuvJaa0rn74KfbhcVB8QCttO9KAxV3b7XsT09jU9e0KuPmYYXxWYVhTbUsf2BZbA8zy8QYv@DxWJk/6nN4s5bpeIksG3XFqNGOrlXPKl16oFfZj3WDaQqLwcZZdDWLzuojWyrU7M5O5R@KpYw7lcaRXu0ethQsYUpBzJtIIG7G9k7Po77lhgPLCVw7lCm0E2yADM1TxiTF55XzDhmbxjFSIdGhrhv5D@Mk@yokNuX6lwVWz770oKaQ0NQrCw9uLgygRyFt06jl/4xuI6PCeQ@YThTyKHDVIBoxx2yn4tiqwyS6@@rZyVcYOwyEOMBGGbA6snGsgBzFOFGMOlUTN3ahQDUwhmDUK/CDC6/fNr0KWFtgNSW7KaaNTjdb4Fj@NKK9qwuxoOZF6/nuRYPq8y2W1er9K5bUL1y9vwqXWKHneb3Ly8tuQ2T@u@eJpDxNrIWOVtM2evf1b22lRgspCx6QUgG1Ilez2ezd3t52mabtlWneD0M4FWb5hQ6Ujgl/J016Qjj0qRD0JiIRuK1Tpc@EL5tVMgiXdHjgW6xShldzXCGWQh4UMob9gLorAmkv5CmfOt3ZTO50Dztdek7CBsZUlFyqQewXeIT4P1xnnfDyLq6dRDfjfan4lAuXOOF/MAhKH2MLOuHmY2y9s7F1UzyQNx9j6/2OrZtXjy1pvF8uPm8YW/8B)

**Note**: running the above program in the Inspector console in Chrome (which appears to support positional arguments to `console.log`) returns the correct program.

#### Explanation

This turned out a lot longer than I'd hoped and I made my life a little harder too, so I'm likely to keep tinkering with it. I'd like to add in more languages too, but I need to find something that doesn't mind a `$` sigil...

This is pretty much a standard quine format where the calculation of the quote to use is a little different for each language: in Ruby `%q&` is used, PHP uses `'`, JavaScript (Node.js) makes use of `` ` `` and Perl 5 utilises `q(`...`)`. Because only the quotes change, the rest of the program is still executable and valid syntax in each language. Python 2 and 3 are wrapped around the previous program using `"""` for Python 2 and  `'''` for Python 3.

The resultant Perl and Ruby programs aren't standard quines, additional `q`/`%q`s are added each iteration, but the first program returns correctly.

The results are:

- Perl 5:
  `eval($_=q&`...`q&);printf($x=q&`...`q&,`...`` );//#'%`'%`'%`'%`''''''''''''""" `` ...
- Ruby:
  `eval($_=%q&`...`%q&);printf($x=%q&`...`%q&,`...`` );//#`'`'`'`'''''''''''''""" `` ...
- JavaScript (Chrome):
  `` eval($_=` `` ...`` `);printf($x=` ``... `` `, ``...`);//#%q&'%q&'%q&'%q&'''''''''''''"""` ...
- PHP:
  `eval($_='`...`');printf($x='`...`',`...`` );//#`q&%`q&%`q&%`q&%''''''''''''""" `` ...
- Python 2:
  ...`_="""`...`""";`...`q="""`...`''''''''''''""";print(_.format(Q,_,q[0:-12]+R,"%"))`
- Python 3:
  ...`_='''`...`''';`...`q='''`...`""""""""""""''';print(_.format(Q,_,q[0:-12]+R,"%"))`

I've re-worked this a lot, I hope I haven't missed anything key here. I still have quite a way to go to be anywhere near [Jo King's score](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162022/9365)...

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), and [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 2<sup>6</sup>/14 = 4.57

```
1Ɗṙ@“1Ɗṙ@ȮṾ”ȮṾ
```

[Try it in Jelly!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wWNfDnTMdHjXMgbJOrHu4c9@jhrlg@v9/AA)

[Try it in M!](https://tio.run/##y/3/3/BY18OdMx0eNcyBsk6se7hz36OGuWD6/38A)

`Ɗṙ@ȮṾ1“Ɗṙ@ȮṾ1”` in Jelly

`1Ɗṙ@ȮṾ“1Ɗṙ@ȮṾ”` in M

Comment: I'm not sure that the Charcoal one counts as a proper quine

Comment: @H.PWiz I was about to add a comment saying that. I'll ask OP

Comment: @l4m2 do you consider the Charcoal program a proper quine? I will delete if not.

Comment: I guess it's like `Quine` in PHP?

Comment: @l4m2 Not sure, I don't know PHP. [It works for most ASCII text I think](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788I7EktSy1qCS1ouT/fwA)

Comment: @dylnan Yeah, that's how it works. As far as I remember, commands in charcoal are only unicode characters, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @JoKing I've asked OP about Charcoal which is similar and they didn't really say whether it was valid. I'll just remove PHP.

Comment: Printable ASCII text is treated as a string literal, and the default command is Print if no other command or function wants the string.

Comment: @Neil Thanks. I guess that means it's not a quine, right?

Comment: There's no code, only data, so no, I don't think it does count as a quine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 2<sup>6</sup>/61 =1.05

```python
s='s=%r;print(s%%s[::(1/2>0)*2-1])';print(s%s[::(1/2>0)*2-1])
```

[Try it in Python 2!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWvdhWtci6oCgzr0SjWFW1ONrKSsNQ38jOQFPLSNcwVlMdLoch9f8/AA)

[Try it in Python 3!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9hWvdhWtci6oCgzr0SjWFW1ONrKSsNQ38jOQFPLSNcwVlMdLoch9f8/AA)

Saved 12 bytes thanks to Jo King.

**Python 2 prints**

```python
s=')]1-2*)0>2/1(::[s%%s(tnirp;r%=s';print(s%s[::(1/2>0)*2-1])
```

**Python 3 prints**

```python
s='s=%r;print(s%%s[::(1/2>0)*2-1])';print(s%s[::(1/2>0)*2-1])
```

This uses the fact that `1/2` is `.5` in Python 3 and `0` in Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash/GolfScript, 72 bytes, score 2<sup>6</sup>/72 = 8/9 (~0.888...)

```
.~0 () 
{ 
    declare "-f" @* ".~0" " ()
 "+@n.;
    echo '.~0;'
}
.~0;
```

Contains a single trailing space on the first two lines.

[Try it online in Bash.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/X6/OQEFDU4GrWoFLAQhSUpNzEotSFZR005QUHLQUlIDySgpKQCVcCkraDnl61mBlqckZ@QrqQDlrda5aLhD9/z8A)
[Try it online in GolfScript.](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X6/OQEFDU4GrWoFLAQhSUpNzEotSFZR005QUHLQUlIDySgpKQCVcCkraDnl61mBlqckZ@QrqQDlrda5aLhD9/z8A)

Simply modification of [*@jimmy23013*'s answer for the "*Write a Polyquine*" challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37857/52210). The modification that was done was removing the trailing space after the third line, and changing `\n"+@n.;` to `\n "+@n;`.

Bash will print lines 1 and 2 like this:

```
.~0 ()    <- Trailing space
{         <- Trailing space
```

And GolfScript will print lines 1 and 2 like this:

```
.~0 ()   <- No trailing space
 {       <- Both leading and trailing space
```

Here the base program, Bash output, and GolfScript outputs respectively with the new-lines replaced with `\n`:

```
.~0 () \n{ \n    declare "-f" @* ".~0" " ()\n "+@n.;\n    echo '.~0;'\n}\n.~0;
.~0 () \n{ \n    declare "-f" @* ".~0" " ()\n "+@n.;\n    echo '.~0;'\n}\n.~0;
.~0 ()\n { \n    declare "-f" @* ".~0" " ()\n "+@n.;\n    echo '.~0;'\n}\n.~0;

      ^^^ Note the difference here
```