# Tips for making a golfing language

Tags: code-golf, tips, language-design

I am currently working on a golfing language. Do you have any suggestions for this language? What are some helpful features of a good golfing language? What features do you find useful? Do you suggest a language based on variables, stack(s), tapes, registers, etc?

As usual, please post separate tips in separate answers.

Comment: Would [tag:code-golf] be relevant in this question?

Comment: @KritixiLithos yes, added.

Comment: I think this is too broad. We used to have [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/16954/8478) which was more specific and [we decided](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6905/8478) that this kind of question is not a good fit for the SE platform. Specific questions about the design of golfing languages could potentially be on-topic and well scoped, but I don't think this is.

Comment: @MartinEnder If tips for golfing in <all langauges> on-topic than why isn't this?

Comment: @programmer5000 That's a narrower question, since the tips there should pertain to the majority of languages, specific to shortening them. This one is completely open-ended, and answers could encompass the entirety of language design.

Comment: Maybe if you center the question around _Do you suggest variables, stack(s), tapes, registers, etc?_. I think that is one of the main foundations when making a language and doesn't seem too broad.

Comment: @Geobits This is pertaining to shortening, too, it is tagges [tag:code-golf]

Comment: @tkellehe [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118111/tips-for-storage-in-a-golfing-language)

Comment: This question is now a duplicate of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118111/34718). @programmer5000, why didn't you just edit this question instead of posting a new one?

Comment: @mbomb007 I think this could be modified to be a question for _general_ tips for making a golfing language.

Comment: I don't feel like this question is useful in any way. The fact that the OP is asking for *feature suggestions* shows that the OP is missing the point of making a language. That's the sort of question that will make "cookie cutter" languages that are all the same. If you're going to make a language, make it unique, make it well, and make it complete. A better question to ask would be how to implement certain features.