# The Staircase Challenge

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

Your work is to recreate this piece of art:

```
                        _____
                       |
                       |
                       |
                       |
                  _____| 
                 |
                 |
                 |
                 |
            _____|
           |
           |
           |
           |
      _____|
     |
     |
     |
     |
_____|
```

The answer must recreate this and print this as a result. All languages allowed, no direct printing of art, ofc, some level of manipulation is required. The answer with the least bytes wins.

*Closes on Thursday 6:30 AM UTC or so.*

The original thing was shown to me by my friend who did this with Java, he refused to show me the source code and now I'll dazzle him with the brilliance of other languages possibly. :D

**You cannot use any alternative character** *(makes it easier?).*

---

**Current leader board**

1. *Pyth* - 28 bytes - isaacg
2. *CJam* - 30 bytes - Runer112
3. *CJam* - 32 bytes - Martin Büttner

**Highest votes:** *C* - 73 bytes - Paul R

---

isaacg takes the crown for passing the Staircase Challenge with Pyth. Watch out for more challenges like these on PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange! All challenges here require an objective winning criterion, to indisputably decide which solution should win. This looks like a [tag:code-golf] question, i.e. shortest code wins, but I'll let you edit it in yourself in case you want to make it something different. Thanks!

Comment: I did mention that the one with the least bytes wins.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. I've edited the proper tag into your question, then.

Comment: @Doorknob This is interesting. We ec-ed twice apparently, explains the loss the information which I had to readd.

Comment: Do we have to print that 1 weird trailing space on the 6th line ?

Comment: More generally, is trailing space allowed? Can I pad this to a rectangle of the width of the first line?

Comment: Can we have a trailing newline?

Comment: @Optimizer Nope, not necessary. Anything that looks necessarily similar is permitted in accordance to what I stated above.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Well, since a trailing newline would reduce the bytes, everyone can do it. No probs. I'm looking for the most optimized code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>29</s> 28

```
V21++**6/-20N5d*5?d%N5\_<\|N
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

A pretty straightforward solution, with the "append five spaces or five underscores" trick from @xnor's solution, but with the loop from 0 to 20, not 20 to 0.

Comment: I dub you thee, Sir isaacg for passing the Staircase Challenge.

Comment: ...and now you can enter the staircase

Answer (score 22):

## C, <s>86</s> <s>80</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 73 bytes

```c
c;main(i){for(i=21;i--;c='|')printf("%*s%c\n",i/5*6+5,i%5?"":"_____",c);}
```

Comment: There always has to be that guy who will post a C solution. Upvote for you.

Comment: You could get it even shorter by changing the loop to `for(i=25;i--;)`

Comment: @FelixBytow It should be `i=26`. Besides this, the `' '` could be changed to `32` for an extra character. My solution is 2 characters longer after these optimizations :(

Comment: You seem to have an extra step. there are 21 rows in the required output, not 26. Some more optimizations: `main(i){for(i=21;i--;)printf("%*s%c\n",i/5*6+5,i%5?"":"_____",i<20?'|':0);}` 1. Simplify the formula for length 2. As @Allbeert says, you can use the ascii code for `' '` but why stop at ASCII 32 when ASCII 0 will do. Also it runs fine for me with `""` instead of `" "`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions guys, and for noticing that I had one stair too many!

Comment: For `i<20?'|':0` substitute `i<20||'|'` for one character.

Comment: @FUZxxl: nice idea but it doesn't seem to work - I haven't quite worked out whether it's a problem with operator precedence or something else.

Comment: Sorry. It should have been `i<20&&'|'`. Does that work?

Comment: Still not quite there unfortunately - since `&&` is a logical operator I guess the result of the expression is either `1` or `0`, not `'|'` or `0` as we would like it to be ? You can play with it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79d9e9ebfb821907) if you like...

Comment: How about this to save two bytes in `'|'` printing? `c;main(i){for(i=21;i--;c='|')printf("%*s%c\n",i/5*6+5,i%5?"":"_____",c);}`

Comment: @Runer112: very devious - I like it - thanks !

Answer (score 11):

## Java, <s>198</s> <s>158</s> <s>156</s> 146 bytes

This can probably be shortened a lot. As usual, suggestions are welcome.

```java
void a(){String a="",b="_____",c=b;for(int i=-1;i<20;b=i%5<1?b.replace(c,"     "):i%5>3?b+" "+c:b)a=b+(++i>19?"":"|")+"\n"+a;System.out.print(a);}
```

Indented (kinda):

```java
void a(){
    String a="",b="_____",c=b;
    for(int i=-1;i<20;b=i%5<1?b.replace(c,"     "):i%5>3?b+" "+c:b)
        a=b+(++i>19?"":"|")+"\n"+a;
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

Thanks Martin Büttner, Rainbolt, and Geobits.

Comment: Honestly, since you did it with Java, I'm impressed.

Answer (score 9):

**Brainfuck (1065 Bytes)**

It's not pretty, it's not short...but i'll optimize later on!

```
++++[->++++++++<]>........................
[->+++<]>-.....>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++....
...................-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++
.[->+++<]>++.......................-[->+++
+<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++..............
.........-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>
++.......................-[->++++<]>.>++++
++++++.[->+++<]>++..................[->+++
<]>-.....[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>+
+.................-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.
[->+++<]>++.................-[->++++<]>.>+
+++++++++.[->+++<]>++.................-[->
++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++...........
......-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++.
...........[->+++<]>-.....[->++++<]>.>++++
++++++.[->+++<]>++...........-[->++++<]>.>
++++++++++.[->+++<]>++...........-[->++++<
]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++...........-[->+
+++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++...........-
[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++......[-
>+++<]>-.....[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++
<]>++.....-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]
>++.....-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>+
+.....-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[->+++<]>++.
....-[->++++<]>.>++++++++++.[--->++<]>+++.
....[->++++<]>.
```

Comment: brainfuck is never pretty :) upvote just for making it work

Comment: I disagree: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output/34699#34699

Comment: http://ideone.com/ICtrhv *Time limit exceeded* I mean, what....

Comment: Bizzare...try it here: http://esoteric.sange.fi/brainfuck/impl/interp/i.html

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>36</s> 30 bytes

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=L%7B%7BS5*%5C%2B%7D%2FS'%7C5*%2B%5D'_5*%2B%7D5*1%3EzN*)

```
L{{S5*\+}/S'|5*+]'_5*+}5*1>zN*
```

My initial 36-byte solution generated the result in the output orientation. Despite my attempts to squeeze more bytes out of the algorithm, I couldn't. Then I saw [Martin's brilliant strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47245/18144) of generating *columns* instead of rows and transposing the result. I realized that was probably a better approach, so I set off to create a transposition-based solution.

However, my approach to implementing that strategy varies quite a bit. Instead of generating full columns, I use an iterative solution that indents any already-generated "steps" and adds adds a new step at each iteration. So the first iteration of the main loop generates this:

```
 |||||
_
_
_
_
_
```

The second iteration of the main loop indents the existing step and adds a new one after it:

```
      |||||
     _
     _
     _
     _
     _
 |||||
_
_
_
_
_
```

And the full five iterations of the main loop generate this:

```
                     |||||
                    _
                    _
                    _
                    _
                    _
                |||||
               _
               _
               _
               _
               _
           |||||
          _
          _
          _
          _
          _
      |||||
     _
     _
     _
     _
     _
 |||||
_
_
_
_
_
```

After this, all that needs to be done is eliminate the first line, which would otherwise become the unwanted riser for the bottom step, and transpose.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>80</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```py
n=24;exec"print' '*n+'_'*5+'|'*(n<24)+('\\n'+~-n*' '+'|')*4*(n>0);n-=6;"*5
```

Got rid of the double `exec` and fit everything into the one `print`!

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
{5*S*'_+a5*~_W<S+5'|*+}5/;]W%zN*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B5*S*'_%2Ba5*~_W%3CS%2B5'%7C*%2B%7D5%2F%3B%5DW%25zN*)

I also tried using an explicit formula, but it's longer in CJam... maybe it helps someone else:

```
21,29,ff{_2$5/)6*(=@@6/5*=_++" |_|"=}W%N*
```

### Explanation

I found that the staircase can be built much more easily if you a) transpose the grid and b) reverse the lines:

```
_
_
_
_
_
 |||||
     _
     _
     _
     _
     _
      |||||
          _
          _
          _
          _
          _
           |||||
               _
               _
               _
               _
               _
                |||||
                    _
                    _
                    _
                    _
                    _
```

So first I'm building that, then reverse, then transpose.

```
{                     }5/        "For i in [0 .. 4].";
 5*S*'_+                         "Get a string of 5*i spaces and append _.";
        a5*~                     "Get five such lines.";
            _W<S+                "Duplicate the last, remove the _, add a space.";
                 5'|*+           "Add 5 copies of |.";
                         ;       "The above creates a row too many, so discard the last one.";
                          ]W%zN* "Wrap everything in an array, reverse, transpose, riffle
                                  with newlines.";
```

Comment: Okay, someone's did it with 30 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Clip, 46](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip)

```
{:24S:5'_m[z{*4,:+5*6zS"|
":*6zS:5'_"|
"`}vR4`
```

### Explanation

```
{               .- Put everything in a list -.
 :24S           .- 24 spaces                -.
 :5'_           .- 5 underscores            -.
 m[z            .- Map...                   -.
    {           .- A list                   -.
     *4         .- 4 of the following       -.
       ,        .- Append                   -.
        :+5*6zS .- 5 + 6 * the iteration of spaces  -.
        "|      .- A pipe and newline       -.
"
     :*6zS      .- 6 * the iteration of spaces      -.
     :5'_       .- 5 underscores            -.
     "|         .- A pipe and newline       -.
"
    `           .- End list (per iteration  -.
   }vR4         .- The mapping is onto {3,2,1,0}    -.
```

Comment: Clip doesn't even have a Wikipedia page. I mean, what....

Comment: @therewillbecoffee Many languages on this site don't have a Wikipedia page. That's the fun ;)

Comment: @Ypnypn Did you design it? It looks really interesting! Although I'd be interested in a *true* quine. ;) (That one on the examples page is a bit cheaty.)

Answer (score 6):

## ECMAScript 6, <s>142</s> <s>138</s> <s>129</s> 91 bytes

Special thanks to @edc65 for really reworking this.

```
a=o='',[for(x of!0+o)(o=(a+'     |\n').repeat(4)+a+'_____|\n'+o,a+='      ')],a+'_____\n'+o
```

```js
out.value=(a=o='',[for(x of!0+o)(o=(a+'     |\n').repeat(4)+a+'_____|\n'+o,a+='      ')],a+'_____\n'+o)
```

```css
textarea{
  width:300px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="out";></textarea>
```

The logic of the original version check @edc65 comment for how it morphed.

```
((f,l,p)=>                  //variables
f(24)+l+p[1]+               //add the non pattern line
[0,1,2,3].map(b=>f(18-6*b)) //add the right number of spaces in front of the 4 steps
.map((a,b)=>f(4,a+f(5)+p)   //the four repeating lines of the step 
+a+l)                       //the landing line
.join(p)+p)                 //put it all together
((n,s=' ')=>s.repeat(n)     //create an variable array of some character
,'_____','|\n')             //string literals
```

Comment: You can safely remove the `new` constructor before `Array` to save a few bytes.

Comment: @hsl thanks for some reason I thought the `new` was necessary.

Comment: Array(n).join(s) is so ES5! did you try `repeat`

Comment: `[1,2,3,4].map((a,b)` and using just b => `[0,1,2,3].map(b` (-4)

Comment: I run Firefox and it works, pretty nicely!

Comment: @edc65 I'll have to remember the repeat function I hadn't seen it yet.

Comment: Just for fun, some golfing advice - http://jsfiddle.net/90zp3729/1/ - score 95

Comment: @edc65 I added one really dirty hack to your for of loop. `!0+o` convert a number to a boolean then to a string.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 59

```python
n=21
exec"n-=1;print n/5*6*' '+' _'[n%5<1]*5+'|'*(n<20);"*n
```

The 21 lines are indexed by `n` in `[20,19,...,1,0]`. First prints 6 spaces for each "step" we're up (minus 1), computed as `n/5*6`. Then, prints five spaces, except these are instead underscores for multiples of five. Finally, prints a vertical line, except for the top line `n=20`.

Comment: Nice and straightforward. I like it!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, <s>115</s> <s>107</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 83 bytes

This is too long to win, but it's the first time I've come up with an answer on PCG.SE, and I'm kind of proud to have made something postable.

With some helpful syntactical advice I shortened the code significantly - even below the scrollbar threshold!

```js
for(s='',y=22;--y;s+='\n')for(x=0;++x<29;)s+=6*~(~-y/5)-~x?4+5*~(x/6)+y?' ':'_':'|'
```

Comment: Nice answer, several things you could do to shorten it are take out the `alert`. If you run it in the console it works just fine without it. Also, the semicolon inside the last curly brace isn't necessary. You can save 1 byte by using `(y/5-.2)` instead of `((y-1)/5)`

Comment: @qw3n thanks for those suggestions; I wasn't sure if the alert was required by the rules.

Comment: You could also move the `s+='\n'` after the `y--` and get rid of the curly braces so it looks like `for(s='',y=21;y>0;y--,s+='\n')`. I also initialized the s inside the for loop so your code is all one statement

Comment: Sorry, one last thing you can do is move the the counting up and down of x and y into the conditional part of the loop it would look like this `for(s='',y=22;--y;s+='\n')for(x=0;++x<29;)s+=x==6*~~(y/5-.2)+5?'|':y==5*~~(x/6)+1?'_':' '`

Comment: @qw3n I was just about to change `y>0` to `y`, but your solution goes even further. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I thought that was my last one but this should be it for me `for(s='',y=22;--y;s+='\n')for(x=0;++x<29;)s+=6*~~(y/5-.2)+5-x?5*~~(x/6)+1-y?' ':'_':'|'` if you flip your ternary expression you can test for `number - x` which is 0 if both terms are equal saving you 2 more bytes.

Comment: Tilde games: ~n == -n-1, -~n == n+1, ~-n == n-1, `for(s='',y=22;--y;s+='\n')for(x=0;++x<29;)s+=6*~(~-y/5)-~x?4+5*~(x/6)+y?' ':'_':'|'` is 83

Comment: You guys are amazing.

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, 68 bytes

I have the strong feeling MATLAB should be able to do better, but I can't think of a way.

```
p(1:5,6)='|';p(1,1:5)=95;w=blkdiag(p,p,p,p);w(21,25:29)=95;flipud(w)
```

Creates the stairs upside-down and flips it. My thaumometer broke because of all the magic constants around.

`'|'` is intentionally left as-is (instead of ascii codepoint) to initialize `p` and `w` as a char array.

Comment: `'|' = 124` anyway, so that doesn't cost any extra chars.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 48

```
25.times{|i|puts" "*(4-i/6)*5+(i%6==0??_*5:?|)}
```

### Old approach, 68

```
4.times{|i|(?_*5+"
|"*5).each_line{|l|puts" "*(4-i)*5+l}}
puts"_"*5
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A couple of Ruby golfing tips: 1. there's some unnecessary whitespace in there. 2. Single character strings like `'_'` can be written as `?_`. 3. Newlines can be embedded directly in strings (so you can actually do `"<linebreakhere>|"`). 4. The parentheses around that aren't necessary. The final `puts` can be replaced with `$><<` (which allows you to get rid of the space, even after using `?_`). Keep it up! :)

Comment: Yeah, I just got rid of some whitespace. Thanks! I didn't know about the single character strings.

Comment: You can probably also replace `(1..4).map` by `4.times` and then use `4-i` instead of `5-i`.

Comment: Ooh, good call. Done.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 83 bytes

```lua
for n=24:-6:0 print(" "^n*"_"^5*"|"^(n<24)*"\n"*(" "^(n>0?n-1:0)*"|\n"^(n>0))^4)end
```

In Julia, string concatenation is performed using the `*` operator and string repetition is performed using `^`.

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>108</s> <s>104</s> 100 bytes

```
cc+::?v~'_____'o\/' 'o  \
?:o'|'\' 'o1-30.o\v!?:-1<}:{oav!?:<4;!
-20.12^?(+cc:ooo/ \~1-'!|'o1. \~ao6
```

A simple ><> solution, using the same strategy as my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47254/21487). The main difference is that ><> doesn't have string multiplication (or even strings), so all of that is done with loops.

### Explanation

```
cc+                  Push 24 (call this "n")

[outer loop]
[loop 1, print n spaces]

:                    Copy n (call this "i")
:?                   If i is not zero...
' 'o1-30.                Print space, decrement i and go to start of loop 1

~'_____'ooooo        Pop i and print five underscores
:cc+(?               If n < 24...
'|'o                     Print a pipe
21.                  Otherwise skip pipe printing

[loop 2: print vertical parts of stairs]

?!;                  If n is zero, halt
4                    Push 4 (call this "j")
?!                   If j is zero...
~ao6-20.                 Pop j, print a newline, minus 6 from n and go to start of outer loop
ao                   Print a newline
}:{                  Copy n (call this "k")

[loop 3: print n-1 spaces]

1-                   Decrement k
:?!                  If k is zero...
    ~1-'!|'o1.           Pop k, decrement j, print a pipe and go to start of loop 2
' 'o                 Otherwise print a space and go to start of loop 3
```

Comment: I feel like I will always upvote a ><> answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 50

```
#!perl -l
print$"x6x(-$_/5),($_%5?$":_)x5,"|"x$|++for-20..0
```

Try [me](http://ideone.com/61qMXw).

Answer (score 2):

## Visual FoxPro 9.0, 261 bytes

#### n = Number of Steps

total of 175 characters, but had to output to file to display correctly - so minus 43 chars for file operations = 132 chars.

```
n=10
c=CHR(13)
f="st.t"
ERAS (f)    
FOR i=n TO 1 STEP -1
    p=(i-1)*6
    =STRTO(PADL("_____",p+5)+IIF(i<n,"|","")+c+IIF(i>1,REPLI(PADL("|"+c,p+1),4),""),f,.t.)
    ?PADL("_____",p+5)+IIF(i<n,"|","")+c+IIF(i>1,REPLI(PADL("|"+c,p+1),4),"")
ENDFOR
MODI COMM (f)
```

**Note to answerer:** Byte count is for the absolute working source code, and the byte counter says that it's 261 bytes, so it is.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 276 bytes

```
declare @x int declare @y int declare @w varchar(30) declare @l char(5) set @l='_____' set @x=23 while @x > 4 begin set @w=replicate(' ',@x) set @y=0 if @x=23 print @w+' '+@l else print @w+' '+@l+'|' while @y < 4 begin set @y=1+@y print @w+'|' end set @x=@x-6 end print @l+'|'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash (+tac from coreutils): 110 bytes

This can be pasted directly into the terminal.

```
(n=;set {1..4};for i do echo "${n}_____|";n+='     ';for i do echo "$n|";done;n+=\ ;done;echo "${n}_____")|tac
```

Comment: Without `|tac`, it doesn't quite work. And I ran this on Git Bash, so I should kill myself.