# What is the shortest infinite loop statement in Java?

Tags: code-golf, tips, java

I'm working on a golf for Java and I need an infinite loop. Obviously, I don't want to spend any more bytes than I have to, especially in such an expressive language.

Assuming I have some code I want to run, obviously the baseline is set at `while(1>0)/*stmt*/` or 10 additional characters for a single line and `while(1>0){/*stmt1*//*stmt2*/}` or 12 additional characters for multiple lines. I say additional because the code I want to loop forever (well, forever-ish... I may or may not want to break out of or return from the loop) will have a certain length, and then I must tack on additional characters to make it actually loop.

At first I thought this was the best I'd get, but I figured I'd throw it out to the experts to see if they can find a better one.

Comment: Or something like `main();`?

Comment: @jimmy23013 No, but you can do `main(null)`.

Comment: @Ypnypn Or `main(a)` if `main` is declared as `public static void main(String[]a)`.

Comment: Out of interest do Java compilers or JITs typically optimize tail-call recursion, or are these recursions limited by stack size?

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/shortest-code-to-produce-infinite-output?rq=1

Comment: @SteveJessop I imagine a lot of loops are unrolled, tail-recursion optimized, or many other tricks. I believe sometimes they will unroll the loop for part of the loop, but not for others - like `for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) { /* stmts */ }` will maybe unroll ten statements, and make the for loop execute ten times. Irrelevant from the source code perspective, but still super cool!

Comment: @jimmy23013 You may have provided me a way to do my the shortcut that prompted this question using recursion actually. It might not answer this particular question, but it might have made the underlying code I was making a bit shorter. It's not like I care how big my stack gets as long as it doesn't overflow!

Comment: A little off topic, I'm surprised we see more Java than Groovy here. If you like Java you should give Groovy a try for code golfing, It's Java with a lot of shortcuts : implicit main(), some of python syntax, a lot of overriden operators, truthy / falsey values, etc. ; In Groovy, while (1) would work.

Comment: Java very explicitly does not perform tail-call elimination. It's not actually an optimization because it modifies the semantics of programs. It obviously makes the difference between programs which crash on a stack overflow versus loop forever. It also impacts any code which inspects and manipulates stack traces.

Comment: @JohnE holy shit... I have only one word: `CogParticle`

Comment: @corsiKa: I'm not proud of all my past code. As Rufus says in Bill and Ted's Excellent Adventure, "they _do_ get better..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
for(;;){}
```

It works cause no condition evaluates to always true.
Insert the code between the braces.

If you only got a few statements you can place them inside the head (the (;;) part. That the loop still runs is caused by when the condition statement is not a boolean it counts as always true. 
Thanx to @Ypnypn for the reminder

Comment: If you have multiple statements, try to put all but one in the for loop itself. e.g., `for(;;foo(),bar(),baz())quux();`

Comment: you can exchange the empty braces for a semicolon `for(;;);`

Comment: @ratchetfreak Only if you don't intend to break the loop, but the OP that they do want the ability to break.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes I'm looking for both single and multi-line, although it's debatable whether Ypnypn's suggestion might actually be smaller. Either way, I should edit my post to make my objective more clear.

Comment: @Ypnypn I don't think that's legal syntax. There's no comma operator in Java (though it can be used in variable declarations).

Comment: Are we really allowed to post answers that aren't a function or a complete program?

Answer (score 2):

## 50 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(;;);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 60 bytes (complete code)

I'm probably not interpreting the question correctly, but this code when compiled and run results in an infinite-ish loop, in that technically it should run forever, but usually it will exhaust the stack memory.

```
public class X{public static void main(String[]a){main(a);}}
```

On Coding Ground it ends quite quickly, on my Windows 7 laptop with advanced virtual memory management, it runs a long time, just making the system slower and slower.

Comment: problem with your solution is, it will give you quite quickly StackOverflowError so it hard to call it infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

```java
for(/*init*/;;/*stmt*/){/*stmt*/}
```

To save characters, you can use the init and increment parts of the loop to save a few bytes by using the semicolons.

Comment: How is this different than the accepted answer?

Comment: I'm just trying to make it more clear where the statements should go. One more thing: If you do need to use break, you can put it in the condition.