# Dump core on Linux

Tags: code-golf

Write the shortest program which, when run with no arguments, stdin, or user input, triggers a core dump.

Your code must behave this way when run on some common out-of-the-box Linux distribution. Other than installing support for your target language, you may not reconfigure the system to make it more fragile than it is as provided.

25-byte C example: `int main(){*((int*)0)=0;}` on my Ubuntu outputs

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-returns-sigsegv)

Comment: I'm posting here since I'm not sure if this is right, but is `perl -ue ''` a valid solution? (question intended for people knowing perl)

Comment: @Dada, when running that I get `Aborted (core dumped)` instead of `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: @redstarcoder It doesn't have to be a segfault, so that would work.

Comment: We already have questions for the fastest way to create a SIGSEGV and the fastest way to create a SIGILL. Dumping core on Linux without a signal is likely to be very verbose compared to crashing in a way that creates a core file, so this question is basically "shortest way to cause a SIGQUIT, SIGILL, SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGSYS, SIGTRAP, SIGXCPU, or SIGXFSZ". I think we'd be better off with those as separate questions, rather than having a combined question for any (especially as some of the existing SIGSEGV/SIGILL are very short).

Answer (score 7):

## C, 5 bytes

```
main;
```

[Try it online!](https://goo.gl/r5RTnz)

### Slightly longer, 7 bytes

```
main=0;
```

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? This is my first post ever.

Comment: I can't guarantee this is what happened, but it's possible that your post was flagged as low-quality because it was short, and then the system itself casted a downvote because you edited. We really dislike this behavior, but it's something the system does that we can't change.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! The downvote was cast automatically by the Community user when you edited your answer. [I consider this a bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/170332).

Comment: The "maximum golfed" answer counts as 9 bytes; it's 2 in the file itself, but has 7 bytes of penalties (`Dm=main`) because it requires an unusual compiler configuration (you'd write it as "2+7 = 9 bytes"). In general, trying to hide code in the compiler configuration or the program's filename is a cheap tactic, and the penalties are intended to prevent it improving your score except in cases where it's interesting.

Comment: Well said! I will remove it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
×ß
```

**[TryItOnline!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5fDnw&input=&debug=on)**

A dyadic atom (here `×`, but there are swathes of others) followed by the quick `ß` which instructs to call the same link (the whole line of code) with the same arity - calling it once more with any arity would also work, so, since it is the only line of code, `ß` could be replaced by any of `¢ÇçÑñ` (last link as a nilad, last link as a monad, last link as a dyad, next link as a monad, or next link as a dyad).

Answer (score 3):

### NASM, 3 bytes

```
ret
```

I guess it tries to jump to whatever is on the default stack and immediately segfaults :).

Built with: `nasm -f elf64 golf.asm && ld golf.o -o golf`

Answer (score 2):

### BASH, 10 bytes

```
kill -6 $$
```

kill -6 precisely does this

Answer (score 0):

## C, 14 bytes

```
main(c){c/=0;}
```

It's that simple 8-)